# Burninate the [run] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

How do we feel about eliminating the [run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/run) tag?  As far as I can tell, this tag is used when

- [someone wants to run something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23355889/run-execute-a-file-upon-creation-of-a-specific-file)
- [when they have a method named run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320680/run-method-not-running)
- [not sure about this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488675/getting-first-run-status-of-test-scripts-in-qc-through-ota) :-)

And none of those scenarios are really helped by the [run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/run) tag.  So we either need a tag cleanup if we decide to keep it, which I'm happy to help with, or a quick death for this tag.

Comment: Can we keep it for when a question gives you the runs?

Comment: Maybe it's for questions that you should run from.

Comment: @jemminger It should have a lot more questions then.

Comment: It's really only for questions about eliminating the `run` tag ;)

Comment: I would like to give an answer, but I have to run.

Comment: Trying to think of a reason it was used in the first place, but I've run out of ideas.

Comment: Looking at the comments here I get the feeling this tag is actually a running gag.

Comment: So do the mods still nuke it from orbit, or do we get to go through and make it disappear?  Also, why couldn't I have posted this on the old MSO, where I would have gotten mega rep for this? #stackoverflowproblems

Comment: @dsolimano According to the [tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) manual editing is required. I've been cleaning up a bunch

Comment: I thought this tag looked familiar - [older burninate request for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193371/should-we-burninate-the-running-tag) [tag:running].

Comment: There are a number of questions tagged `execute` with the same issue.

Comment: @HarryJohnston `[tag:execute]` gives [tag:execute]

Comment: Looks like run and running are both done.  Execute, we're coming for you!

Comment: When you make these requests please remind people to not just blindly accept/make the edits without making other improvements to the question.

Comment: Excellent point @MarkHall, it's a great opportunity to fix all sorts of formatting and phrasing issues.  Remember folks, we're trying to make the Internet a better place!

Comment: @Mark Hall: I disagree with the philosophy of not allowing minor edits. It just means I'm unlikely to contribute to cleaning up issues that span multiple posts. I'm more willing to contribute to Wikipedia, even though I generally just chip away at minor issues such as spelling. I very much dislike how SE happily turns down edits even if they are an improvement. If rep-farming is the issue that people are concerned about, then users should be allowed to give-up the +2 rep and mark it as minor if they are not bothered about silly points but just want to make our shared knowledge better.

Comment: @JamesHaigh I do agree with you, my earlier comment was made because of seeing some higher rep users with a Review ban, as a way of reminding people of what needs to be done.

Comment: @Mark Hall: Well I'm ranting at the wrong person. ;-) I was reading this post because it was linked in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253293/review-ban-because-of-approving-burninate-tag-edits), which I guess is what you're talking about when you say “seeing some higher rep users with a Review ban”, because it was in the community bulletin. Even the banners are being banned for helping out. I don't like how bureaucratic this network is. :-(

Answer (score 81, accepted):

As no one will ever be an expert in questions tagged "run", I don't see the point in keeping it.

Tags are for letting people find questions they can answer.

Comment: I AM AN EXPERT IN RUNNING FROM PROBLEMS!!!1!

Comment: What about Forest Gump?

Comment: Tags are also useful for searching.

Comment: Usain Bolt will be sad

Comment: @gitsitgo He can always be an expert at [running](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/running).

Comment: or an expert at running his [mouth](http://cdn.someecards.com/someecards/usercards/MjAxMy1kZGQzZjBlMDA4ZTU1MjM2.png)

Comment: What about Trump running for President and winning?