# Should [footer] be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags

[footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/footer) has 1535 questions. It's usually used with [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) or [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios). It doesn't seem to add any information to existing tags. So should it be burninated?

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252954/2888561

Comment: No it shouldn't.  If nothing else, it helps users find the right questions and answers.  [Searching for `footer`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=footer) results in a useless mountain of junk results. [Searching for `[footer]` (the tag)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/footer) gives a much more likely set of results. Notice that a great many of these are **not** tagged neither `html` nor `ios`.

Answer (score 4):

I distinguish two types of tags: tags that are specific, and tags that clarify.

For instance: you could have the specific tag [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and then add the clarifying tag [footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/footer). That's better than having something such as [html-footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-footer) because many people will follow the tag [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), but (almost?) nobody will follow the tag [html-footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-footer).

Adding a clarifying tag such as [footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/footer) to a specific tag such as [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) helps people understand what the question will be about, even before opening the question.

If it would come to a vote, I'd vote against removing tags such as [footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/footer), because such a tags serves a purpose.

**Extra example in answer to an extra comment:**

> Footer contains no information. What do you want to do with the
>   footer? A footer is just like any other element, it doesn't help
>   clarify the question.

I'm the original developer of [itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext), a Java PDF library, with a C# port [itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itextsharp). I follow those two tags, and whenever I have the time, I try answering these questions. However, when I don't have much time, I look at the overview of [itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext)[itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itextsharp) questions, and I pick those that spark my interest because I can usually answer them in only a handful of minutes. This is the case when people tag their question as [itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext)[footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/footer) or [itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext)[header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/header) (you could ask the same question about [header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/header) and many other tags, once you start thinking about the implications of your question). This is *not* the case when I see the tags [itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext)[flying-saucer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flying-saucer) or [itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itextsharp)[browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser) (I skip all those questions).

The tags are the first piece of information I look at, even before I look at the question or the first line of the question. That's what I mean when I say that *clarifying tags* are important.

**Extra remark in answer to extra comment:**

> How is [html-footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-footer) any worse than [footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/footer)?

People follow tags. For instance: I follow the 10 tags [itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext), [itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itextsharp), [itextpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itextpdf), [itextg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itextg), [pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf), [pdf-generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf-generation), [digital-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digital-signature), [android-droidtext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-droidtext), [livecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/livecycle), [xfa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xfa).

Every day, I look at the questions of at least [itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext) and [itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itextsharp). If I have more time, I also look at the other 8 tags.

I would find it extremely inconvenient, if I had to add more tags such as [pdf-header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf-header) and [pdf-footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf-footer). Already I'm annoyed about the distinction between the tags [pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf) and [pdf-generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf-generation) because people often tag questions using [pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf)[pdf-generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf-generation) in which case I see the same question twice. I prefer [pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf)[generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generation) above [pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf)[pdf-generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf-generation) for reasons of convenience: I have less tags to follow (I could remove [pdf-generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf-generation) from my list of followed tags) without losing information that shows me what the question is about in only one glance.

You have to look at your question form a practical point of view. The user experience is worse when using [html-footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-footer) when compared to using [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)[footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/footer).

Comment: Footer contains no information. What do you want to do with the footer? A footer is just like any other element, it doesn't help clarify the question.

Comment: Yes, it does. I'll add another example.

Comment: How is `html-footer` any worse than `footer`?

Comment: My answer doesn't fit in the comment box, I'll update my answer.

Comment: [Meta-tags are actually a subset of a larger problem that I usually call dependent tags. These are tags that don’t say anything by themselves – you can’t tell what the question is about unless they’re paired with some other tag (or several of them). These tags are a problem because people don’t realize this and will often use that as the question’s only tag.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: [tag:footer] tells you more about the question than a meta-tag such as [tag:beginner], [tag:subjective],... would do. If you see [tag:footer], you know that the question will be about a document (HTML, PDF,...) whereas [tag:beginner] doesn't tell you anything about the nature of the question. Please don't compare apples with oranges.

Comment: [Ok…](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=apples+vs+oranges) but it wasn't just talking about meta tags. "Meta-tags are a subset of…" Yes, it tells you a lot more than `beginner`, but still not enough to properly classify a question without a language tag.

Comment: Isn't the same true for a tag such as [tag:pdf]? Without a tag such as [tag:Java] or [tag:iText] or [tag:printing] or [tag:file-upload], the question can be about *any* aspect of PDF, just like the tag [tag:footer] can be about *any* document-type. Following your reasoning, tags such as [tag:pdf] should also be banned because they're not specific enough. I don't agree. A single tag can cover a huge field of expertise, but one should be able to clearly categorize a question using 3 to 5 tags.

Comment: Javascript: The question is about javascript. PDF: The question is about PDFs. Footer: The question is about… something? Homework: I have no clue.

Comment: That question is answered here [tag:footer]: *In programming, a page footer (or simply footer) is part of page that is separated from the main body and appears at the bottom of a page.* The question is about footers in a document (HTML, PDF,...). See also: [tag:header] (I assume you want to have [tag:header] removed too?)

Comment: I know what a footer is, just not what a question involving it will be about.

Comment: Well, if a tag is [tag:Javascript], *I* don't know what the question will be about! Will it be about validating form fields? Will it be about drawing a graph? Will it be about Math operation? Will it be about positioning content (maybe even animation)? Let's *burninate* [tag:Javascript] because it doesn't tell me what the question will be about!

Comment: You can be a JavaScript expert. You can't be a footer expert.

Comment: That's true, but do you know anyone who would take pride in being an [tag:html-footer] expert? How would you tag a question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918382/how-to-make-a-footer-in-generating-a-pdf-file-using-an-itextpdf The three tags [tag:java], [tag:footer], [tag:itextpdf] qualify the question. Removing [tag:footer] broadens the scope (and makes it worse). With [tag:footer], the question fits into a very specific category (which is really helpful).

Comment: If you can't be an expert in the tag, the tag cannot be alone on a question. If a tag requires other tags to work, it is *too broad*. Footer should be `concept-footer`, where concept makes footer be specific enough to work on its own.

Comment: That's a very academic approach. Having worked for a university for over 10 years, I know that such an approach is often dead letter because it's not the pragmatic approach people use in the real world.

Comment: a little-known feature of SE is an ability to track [tag:html-footer] and similar tags with [tag:*html*] ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*html*))

Comment: I didn't know that. I'll start using it immediately!