# Should we get rid of the [div] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/div) tag currently has [6,675 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/div).

It is, in my opinion, absolutely useless. When you search using this tag, 99% of the time what you get is questions like

> Why isn't my Javascipt/CSS working on this div

The problem is adding a tag like this does nothing to enhance the question. The CSS/JS problem have to occur on *some element*, so why give it the specific [div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/div) tag? It could be any other block level element, or it could very well be that the HTML (and hence the `div`) was never involved in the problem itself, so this tag is usually meaningless, and hence useless.

---

Some background on this for those who don't know HTML. The `<div>` tag is a generic block level element - that is, on its own it has no **meaning**. Its **purpose** (there is a distinction here) is to separate content (or rather, divide, hence the name) into meaningful and distinct blocks.

> The `div` is a generic block-level element. It doesn’t convey any meaning about its contents (unlike a `p` element that signifies a paragraph, or an `h1` or `h2` element that would indicate a level 1 or level 2 heading, respectively); as such, it’s easy to customize it to your needs. The div element is currently the most common method for identifying the structural sections of a document and for laying out a web page using CSS.
>
> —[Source](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/div)

The problem here is that since its generic, the problem could very well occur to any other block level HTML element, but since `div`s are most commonly used, this tag is frequently applied to questions on CSS layout and DOM manipulation and event handling problems.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree, I can't think of one single question that benefits from having this tag. At this point, this useless tag has grown to a size of 6,600 questions...

Comment: Yeah, it's completely useless. [The silliest badge I own...](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1256/div?userid=405015)

Comment: Isn't the solution to this problem to go and remove [div] from questions where it doesn't belong? What's wrong with treating this as a shallow problem to be fixed by many hands?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: The problem is it *doesn't* belong on *any* of the 6,600 questions tagged with it.

Comment: @animuson If you've really looked through all of those, then I'll have to accept that and I'd withdraw the objection. But, isn't SO for *experts*? There are wacky things that *expert* webdevs do with divs, or bugs with divs, that they should be able to ask about regardless of clueless users abusing the tag. They can't use the tag with all the noise in it, yeah. It seems like a self-defeating argument though: if the tag weren't neglected and saw some cleanup, maybe it'd be useful. Saying it's not useful without cleaning it up is a bit circular, no?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You can't be an expert on divisions. A division is just a non-semantic box. Any bugs you could encounter with it would not be at all related to the fact that's it's a division. It would have something to do with it being `display: block` or some other properties you are applying to it. A division on its own **does absolutely nothing**. This tag is like mixing in [tag:apples], [tag:oranges], [tag:bananas], and [tag:grapes] and labeling it all [tag:fruit].

Comment: @animuson [Are](http://forums.asp.net/t/1742420.aspx/1?IE7+container+div+expansion+bug) you [sure](http://www.tightcss.com/bugs/empty_div_bug_google.htm)? I'm not claiming to be an webdev expert, but I know enough about programming design and bugs that saying the semantics of the *intended* behaviour means that it is impossible to have bugs doesn't really make sense. There are enough div-only bugs that indicate the engines do in fact special case them, at least sometimes. Besides, all I'm saying is that the assertion "this room is a mess!" isn't reason to flood it with cleansing fire.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Skimming through your first example, the solution didn't have anything to do with the `<div>`... The second example is *most* likely a rendering bug in IE6 related to font sizing, as I remember I used to have to set `font-size: 0` on empty containers in order to actually make them display at the proper height.

Comment: Related… ish? [Should \[footer\] be burninated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252832/should-footer-be-burninated)

Comment: Let's replace it with the table tag!

Answer (score 23):

I'd like to revisit this issue. At the time of writing this, the [div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/div) tag has grown to over 14,000 questions strong, and is still an *incredibly useless* tag.

By HTML's definition, a division has no meaning, whatsoever. It's just an element meant to contain some content. The questions which do use this tag are clearly just using it as a meta-tag. Oftentimes, the mention of the division doesn't really help the question, or it's not even relevant to the actual question.

Many questions using this tag are *actually* about CSS - trying to make an element do something specific stylistically, and the element **just happens to be** a division element. The same exact question could apply to any other element, but this specific question used a division. That doesn't mean the tag is useful at all.

At its base, this tag can **only** be used to say "I'm using a division in my code" - it has no value to the site in helping categorize questions, and certainly is not a topic you can be an "expert" on in any sense. I think it should just be merged and synonymized into [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html).

**Update 05/05/2014:** As an experiment I've gone ahead and transferred all of the synonyms for [div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/div) to [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and made it a synonym itself. If all goes well, I'll go ahead and merge them all in (which will likely just remove the tag from the vast majority of them) at a later date (6 - 8 weeks, maybe).

Comment: I was just about to merge it into [tag:html], until I realized this is apparently actually in question…

Comment: OK, so this is weird. For some reason, after the migration the tag links in this answer are pointing to MSE, while the links in the rest of the question are pointing to SO.

Comment: @BoltClock Probably because I edited it while it was still on MSE? :/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this logic, unless the position is that `div` just cannot be used meaningfully by most folks.  `div` is a frequent target of jQuery, Javascript and CSS.  Other than the fact that it is apparently being interpreted as devoid of semantic meaning, what makes `div` any different from `ul`, `li`, etc.?

Comment: I also think this sort of thing is a slippery slope for requests like [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258265/102937).  Who cares?  Is the tag actively harmful?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Slippery slope?  That other suggestion sounds good to me.

Comment: @Brilliand: It was easy to fix this one, because there was a tag to synonymize it with.  See [my answer there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258274/102937).

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing specific in HTML DIV element. There is a lot specific in HTML **block elements**.

So I would suggest retagging them to [block-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/block-element) and synonymize [div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/div) with it.

Most of the HTML tag shouldn't have special tags, because there's nothing special in them, what couldn't be achieved with CSS. So tags for inputs, forms, iframes - yes, for spans, divs, headers, paragraphs etc. - no.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the people who write HTML/JavaScript/CSS can reasonably be described as not knowing HTML and not understanding the distinction (or lack thereof) between `div` and any other element.

I'm not at all convinced that eliminating the [div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/div) tag would help this situation, nor am I sure it wouldn't cause more problems in the process. The presence of the tag might help somebody who doesn't understand it find a question where it's explained...

Comment: This is a good point. The tag isn't appropriate, but if it does help people than it should stay.

Comment: "The presence of the tag might help somebody who doesn't understand it find a question where it's explained" I think I've stated in the question that the problem *is* the abuse. Look through the list of `div` questions, and see if you could find questions like that. Even the most highly votes ones have titles like `div class vs id`.

Comment: Honestly, we don't keep tags because they *might* help people, it just encourages people to continue miscategorizing things. I don't see *how* this actually helps anything. The word "div" is likely already plastered throughout the question and title, so the search will pick up on it anyways.