# Are we [heading] in the wrong direction?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, tag-disambiguation

The [heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heading) has no usage guidance.  I stumbled on it as an additional tag when reading a question about [bearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bearing), which also has no guidance but is used almost exclusively in navigational/geolocation types of questions.  In navigation, these are related but slightly different concepts.

- *bearing* is the direction you want to go (your target/destination, useful for algorithms to calculate it)
- *heading* is the direction you are pointing (useful for map UI questions)

The vast majority of the 247 questions under the [heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heading) tag, however, apply to HTML/CSS headings.  There is a completely separate [html-heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-heading) tag.

About 20-30 questions, however, refer to the navigational heading.

I propose:

- Review the geographical-related questions with the [heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heading) tag and change it to either [bearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bearing) (if it was used incorrectly) or [direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/direction) (a tag with usage guidance for map UI headings).
- Merge/synonymize the [heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heading) tag to [html-heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-heading) for the remainder of the HTML/CSS-related questions

Comment: I don't think the heading/bearing split is as clear-cut as that. Mapbox GL JS for instance uses `bearing` to describe the current rotation of the map.

Comment: Retagging the HTML/CSS questions to use [tag:html-heading] seems the right thing to do.  For the other uses, I don't have enough grounding in the geographic area to know whether the [tag:direction] and [tag:bearing] are replacements for [tag:heading].  But the tag information for [tag:heading] should be created and should firmly point at the other tags — at least until it is expunged.

Comment: To an observer, the bearing is the angle between North and the (rhumb) line to an object. The heading is indeed the direction the observer is facing relative to North.

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63432563/1997232) question? Retag to [tag:title]?

Comment: Looking at all those bearing, heading, orientation, navigation, position, direction, etc. I think we have a bigger problem here. Someone has decided how to use tag (e.g. [tag:orientation] is about page orientation), but there are 100 other cases. Imho, to disallow misusing  there should be no "heading", but rather "html-heading", "gps-heading", "whatelse-heading", which make mistakes impossible. So yes, "heading" should go.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler are you sure we need a tag for h[1-6] tags? Other elements tags, like a, href, etc. were burninated because people were... um... misusing them the same way this tag is.

Comment: @Braiam there already is an existing `html-heading` tag (230 questions). If you want it gone, that'd be a separate request to this one.

Comment: @Braiam — I have no strong views on [tag:html-heading].  There are no tags for [tag:h1] through [tag:h6] — and I certainly wasn't suggesting adding them.  As Daniel said, as the [tag:html-heading] tag exists and some of the questions currently tagged [tag:heading] would be more appropriately tagged [tag:html-heading], then it seems sensible to retag them.  If it makes more sense to expunge [tag:html-heading] instead, that's fine with me too.  I have no attachment to (or, AFAIK, involvement with) any of the tags mentioned here — they can live or die and I won't be concerned either way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler drats, [I guess animuson missed those](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253557/792066)