# Re-tag [header]

Tags: feature-request, retag-request

[header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/header) has the following wiki:

> The portion of a data block, cell, frame, or packet that precedes the text field or payload and provides information such as the source address and destination address. The header often includes synchronization bits that serve to synchronize the operations of the transmit and receive devices across the link.
>
> Please do not use this tag to categorise questions around user-interface and/or UX related issues. Within such a context it is ambiguous and has no specific taxonomic meaning on a programming site.

Reasonable, right?

There are 6,642 questions with that tag.

By votes:

#2 [HTML5 best practices; section/header/aside/article elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781077/html5-best-practices-section-header-aside-article-tags)

#3 [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer)

#4 [What is the common header format of Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523427/python-what-is-the-common-header-format)

#6 [In Node.js, how do I "include" functions from my other files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files)

#7 [Should Jquery code go in header or footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105327/should-jquery-code-go-in-header-or-footer)

#8 [Xcode 4 can't locate public header files from static library dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543854/xcode-4-cant-locate-public-header-files-from-static-library-dependency)

#9 [Where does gcc look for C and C++ header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344317/where-does-gcc-look-for-c-and-c-header-files)

#10 [Tool to track #include dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308/tool-to-track-include-dependencies)

#11 [How should I detect unnecessary #include files in a large C++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74326/how-should-i-detect-unnecessary-include-files-in-a-large-c-project)

#12 [Why has it failed to load main-class manifest attribute from a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591516/why-has-it-failed-to-load-main-class-manifest-attribute-from-a-jar-file)

#13 [C++ Redefinition Header Files (winsock2.h)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372480/c-redefinition-header-files)

#14 [Javascript Include Tag Best Practice in a Rails Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390164/javascript-include-tag-best-practice-in-a-rails-application)

#15 [Tool for adding license headers to source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151677/tool-for-adding-license-headers-to-source-files)

...and so on. Not even close to the wiki description.

The problem is that "header" is vague, and has many possible meanings.

The incorrect uses of [header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/header) should have had [header-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/header-files), [html-head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-head), [html-header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-header), [table-header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-header), or no header-like tag at all. (Okay, [html-header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-header) and [table-header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-header) don't exist yet, but they probably would if [header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/header) weren't an option.)

The vast majority of questions are mislabeled. The best thing is to remove the tag and use more specific tags, like [http-headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-headers) or [email-headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email-headers) where [header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/header) could have been (correctly) used.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252832/should-footer-be-burninated

Comment: @bjb568, I have read that. I agree that [tag:footer] should die in favor of [tag:html-footer], [tag:table-footer]. However, [tag:header] has even *more* possible uses than [tag:footer].

Comment: Do you think all tags that you can't be an expert in should be burninated?

Comment: @bjb568, no...I think that all tags that are overly vague or that have multiple unrelated uses should be burninated.

Comment: So should the excerpt be changed to something that warns users to not the tag anymore?

Comment: @Sam, looks like you or someone else just did that. "This tag is deprecated because it lacks discriminating power. Please use a more specific tag instead, e.g.: html-header, email-header etc."

Comment: This is not a "burnination" request, it is a "retag" or "cleanup" request. Calling it the right thing is important, because otherwise we get people shooting themselves (and all of us) in the foot by single-mindedly trying to obliterate the tag from existence. You do sort of make this point in the question itself, but tagging questions about C headers, HTML headers, email headers, etc. is not only perfectly appropriate, but a very good idea. The problem is not the tag [header], but its vagueness. That's what needs to be solved here, not wiping [header] off the map.

Comment: @CodyGray, done.

Comment: If [header] is deprecated then what about [footer]? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510180/how-to-make-a-sticky-list-item-which-will-float-only-within-the-screen-on-androi for an example where one was removed, the other left.

Comment: @CodyGray, in regards to your objection to Sam's action, how much consensus is needed? It stands at 16 to 3, with no articulated dissenting opinion.

Comment: Currently, this tag has over 12k questions. It should just be removed.