# How to better deal with "questions" that only contain an imperative?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I've recently run across a few questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497709/inputting-grep-with-a-named-class-of-characters) one, which contain nothing but what looks like a problem set problem.  No code, no context, not even an actual *question*.  All it says is "do this!"

Upon perusal of various discussions here on Meta, I flagged this one (and others) as "too broad" for lack of a better flag reason.  And yet, this question is still open, and only 2 downvotes with 11 views (as far as I can see at the time of this writing).  I can only assume that the low views are why it's still around.

What is the best thing to do about questions like this?  Is it just that more people should downvote and flag?  Are we just waiting for the Roomba suck this up?  I would think we would want to eliminate stuff like this pretty quickly, but it doesn't appear to be happening.

Apologies if this is a duplicate of something, I couldn't find other meta posts regarding questions that have zero info from the asker, not even "this is a homework problem"...

Here's the original question for reference:

> ### Inputting grep with a named class of characters
>
> > Write a command to list lines containing a 4-digit year. Use a “named
> >     class of characters” in your solution, rather than a range expression.
>
> [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) [ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) [grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grep)

Comment: I'd say dovnvoting and close voting/flagging for `Unclear what you're asking` should be the right decision (did so)

Comment: It's been DV'd and closed now.

Comment: Wow, the meta effect in action... dang I didn't realize it would be so fast!

Comment: Note that the Roomba will not suck up a question unless its closed.

Comment: I prefer "unclear" as the close reason for "do this for me" questions.  "Write code that does X" "It's unclear what the issue is here.  What have you tried, why didn't it work?"

Comment: Well, it is now deleted.

Comment: @Will I agree this one was particularly unclear so that works also.  I've seen a few though that have the same format ("Do this") that are actually pretty specific (I think they're all deleted now), and in that case both "unclear" and "too broad" both feel not quite right.  Should I be generating a custom mod flag?  Or are these things the community could handle without bothering a mod?

Comment: Closing questions generally happens by the community without bothering a mod (unless it's spam/offensive/otherwise a big problem).  Once you've got 3k rep you can cast close votes for 'other' Off Topic reasons, but I think that's not in the Flagg->Close option set (on purpose).  "Unclear what you're Asking" is probably best for any of these - it's unclear what the question is, since there's not a question.

Comment: Some questions are so bad that just the title scares SO users away.  Yes, hard to get them closed when nobody looks at it.  Not so sure this is a real problem, it can only become one when [somebody answers it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261874/17034).

Comment: It looks like a homework question. I sometimes point them to [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811). Then I move to close.

Comment: Why does this question need to be discussed? At 20% downvote rate the Stack Overflow system has worked. I rarely see such a high rate.

Comment: It would be good to copy the text of such questions, because now it's unavailable for viewing due to moderation.

Comment: @Kev: here you go :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Whether the question actually contains a question in the grammatical sense, or merely a problem statement, isn't really relevant.  Either can make a good or a bad post.  A problem statement in which the problem is reasonably scoped can be a perfectly fine SO question.  It doesn't need to be phrased as a grammatical question by adding something like "How do I do this?" to the end of it.

Of course, if the problem at hand *isn't* reasonably scoped (or isn't clear, or doesn't contain sufficient information, or whatever) then it doesn't matter whether there is an actual grammatical question or not, it should be closed for the corresponding close reason.

Comment: Sensible.  Indeed, these are in the same vein as the 'gimme teh codez' questions, which are the subject of many a meta post, regardless of how they are couched.  I shall continue to downvote away...

Comment: Do you have any example of a good SO question formulated as an imperative?

Comment: @JanDvorak: here's [an example of "imperative" question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/47402/4279). It has >10K views, accepted answer has +20 upvotes. Though I hadn't received an answer that uses a  new (for me) approach (the motivation to ask the question), I used the idea that is implemented in the accepted answer on several occasions in a less trivial context i.e., it has practical value.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thanks for the example. Though the question seems to be useful, I must say I'm not particularly a fan of the way it's formulated. I believe that its score reflects the same feeling in other potential voters. Though adding "how do I" seems to be a cosmetic change, it _might_ push the score up slightly. Also, I'm convinced this question might not go well if asked in this form today.

Comment: @JanDvorak: yes. SO is worse today. [The question is in top ~1% by viewcount and accepted answer score](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/238961/question-percentile-by-view-and-votes-on-its-accepted-answer).

Answer (score 7):

I think the right response is downvote, explain the reasoning, and vote close as too broad. If you're feeling feisty, flag as "not a real question". Then, sit back and let the machinery work.

Other answers here hedge their bet and say " some questions might be ok in that format" but I disagree. If the question starts out as "I need..." or "corite code to... " it cannot be redeemed IMHO, if for no other reason that it shows zero research. If someone wants free professional help, they should be expected to put in a little effort.

Answer (score 6):

Lack of an actual *question* in the title is indeed often an indication of a problem with the post - the OP don't know themselves what they are really asking.

However, this is not a rule. If a post as a whole constitutes a good question, it is usually trivial to reformulate the title into a *question*.

Answer (score 0):

### Downvote. Always.

Tooltip says: "This question does not show any research effort [...]" and imperative-only questions fit the bill.

(I don't think it's technically possible do demonstrate research effort using exclusively the imperative... Except maybe: "Look at what I tried... Tell me what's wrong with it" but I don't think this is what the OP meant by "question that contain only an imperative".)

### Vote to close?

It's a gray area, but I think my ever fluctuating internal heuristics have temporarily settled on the following:

#### Sometimes yes...

Definitely yes if, beyond just zero research effort, there is an *additional* reason to get rid of the question — including but not limited to the strict definitions of the prefab close reasons.

One such valid reason, as far as I'm concerned, is, if I *know* for a fact this is a duplicate of a bunch of other questions I've seen on Stack Overflow. This is true even if I can't afford to spend the 15 minutes of search time necessary to locate the exact duplicate.
When life gets in the way of common sense, "Too broad" is the way to go.

Another such valid reason is when the assignment is just too tall an order for an SO question, and should really have been broken down in multiple questions with narrower scope.

And there are more.

#### Sometimes no...

An "imperative-only" question *can* often be quite clear, and even really, really interesting and fun to answer and potentially useful to future observers.

#### Bottom line

Will this question and its likely answers increase or decrease the quality of the site? Is what I try to ask myself when in doubt.

Comment: How does whether or not the post is phrased as a question or an imperative have anything to do with how well it is researched or whether or not it is too broad?  A post can be in either form and either meet or not meet either of those criteria; it's grammatical phrasing has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Servy: I'd be interested to see an example of how an OP would show their research using exclusively the imperative tense. Seems to me it would be grammatically impossible, but I'm happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: You could take any SO question ever and change the grammatical question to an imperative.  Research is an entirely orthogonal concept.  What makes you thing that how a post is grammatically phrased could even possibly be dependent on how much research is done.  If you want to assert that it's impossible to do research when a post is phrased imperatively then you'll need to demonstrate *that* assertion.

Comment: *Doing* research? Possible. *Showing* research effort? (which is what the tooltip says) I don't really see how, to be quite honest (except in a really contrived way, which I have never seen). And no, I won't attempt to prove a negative. But this is all beside the point; I do not see the OP meaning "all the sentences are tortured into using the imperative tense only". I see it meaning, questions that are exclusively "do this, do that".

Comment: One can state (not asked) what is needed and then follow that up with what they've tried, what research they've found, and explain why it hasn't solved  the problem.  Omitting a superfluous, "How do I do this?" doesn't magically make the question not be well researched.

Comment: I agree with everything you wrote in this last comment. Is it relevant? I don't think so. I don't see how any of this applies to the OP or the examples given therein.

Comment: So you're saying that the grammatical phrasing of the question is irrelevant, contrary to your answer, that your statement that all questions phrased imperatively should be downvoted is incorrect, and that, contrary to your post, one should evaluate whether or not the post actually does its research, and is reasonably scoped without considering the grammatical phrasing of the question?  I mean if you agree that one can phrase a question as an imperative while having it be reasonably scoped and well researched that's pretty much the only conclusion.

Comment: Or are you asserting that because there were a few examples of questions phrased imperatively that weren't reasonably scoped or didn't show sufficient research effort that it's impossible for any other questions to be appropriate that happen to be phrased imperatively?  If so, that's just not true.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand the point you're trying to make. I give up. You win. Have fun with your straw man.

Comment: I thought the point was rather clear.  I demonstrated that a quality, well researched, appropriately scoped question could be asked imperatively, rather than as a question.  You agreed.  Clearly, if that can be done, then the entirety of your answer doesn't apply, as it's based on the assumption that an imperatively phrased question cannot be appropriate.  So your answer is wrong, you know that it's wrong, and you, what, don't care?  If you feel that my points aren't correct then *explain what about them is incorrect* rather than throwing out words like "straw man" that clearly don't apply.