# Which option in the current close-vote menu should be used for questions that merely ask for a direct solution?

Tags: discussion

An example might be:

> Here is a Python list of data: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. How do I get the sum?

Or

> Here is a complicated data structure: `Foo(complicated_values)` (followed by some copy/paste source code). How do I turn `Foo` container into a sorted array of `complicated_values` in faster than quadratic time complexity?

These questions are not asking for a reference of any kind, rather they exhibit the classic "what have you tried" problem of asking directly for the solution. The question is asking for someone to write code directly into the answer box that, when executed, computes the desired effect.

Currently there doesn't seem to be a way to signal this in the close-vote options. There is an option for off-topic questions due to seeking references, but I feel that very much doesn't apply to a question like this.

Comment: 'Too broad' or 'Unclear what you're asking' should work well for such cases.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. The first example question is the total opposite of broad. It asks a highly precise question about exactly the scope of the computation to perform. It's very clear what is being asked. It's not broad or unclear at all, rather just lazy.

Comment: Don't ask, "what reason should I use to close this question I want closed?"  Instead go through each of the close reasons and ask yourself which of them apply to this question.  If none apply, then don't vote to close.

Comment: Regarding the 1st question: Aren't there multiple ways to achieve this in python?

Comment: I was always told to use "too broad", but I don't know if there's an official guideline.

Comment: @Mr.F I don't care so much for a specific close reason in such case (both I proposed would fit well). It's the _laziness_ you mention that makes this question deserved to be closed.

Comment: @Mr.F _"... answering the question would also receive some kind of -50 rep penalty ...."_ LOL! I'd love to see such thrown/slapped  into the face of all those filthy rep-whores lurking and hanging around. That's a terrific proposal!

Comment: first example: downvote and move on, or just move on. doesn't need to be closed. 2nd example, will depend on whether or not the question is clear and not too broad. **We don't have a not enough effort close reason.** You could however close it as a duplicate if you can find one.

Comment: Given the expansion you've made in the comments, [What happened to the "you're just lazy" close vote reason?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216491) is related reading for you.

Comment: See also [How does "proof of effort" make a question better?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179035) and [Close option for questions that can be answered with a simple research](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189345)

Comment: Then don't close it. If it isn't too broad, it isn't too broad.

Comment: Of, course, this is where the guideline you mention gives us enough reason to make exceptions for real copy/paste homework questions that may also be specific enough to be answered.

Comment: @Mr.F too broad may fit more frequently than it seems, if you take into account the way it is laid out in [another answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601) of the same guy who wrote top answer in dupe target: "_... **ME**: Click the right mouse button.
   **NOOB**: What's a mouse?_ How much text do you suppose it will take to explain things now?" -- any time you smell that requirements dump simply doesn't let answerers figure how much they need to explain, recall this "What's a mouse?" example

Comment: Unfortunately i think you would still need to provide examples for that question, and you'll likely just again be told to use too broad. The only guideline that isn't covered by a close vote reason word for word is the homework guideline you are focusing on.

Answer (score 10):

The two examples you gave are two very different situations, so I'll address each separately:

#### Example 1

As much as I hate coming across questions like this, the fact remains that these questions are often very popular and bring in a lot of views for stackoverflow. [Take a look for yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1000&tab=votes&q=how%20do%20i). However, these questions are also very often duplicates of other questions, so see if you can find one to close it with. If it's clear, on topic, not too broad, and not asking for an opinion (or the *"Best"* solution,) leave it open.

#### Example 2

I don't understand the question being asked (maybe that's the point?) but if a question includes current output, code that generates it, and then expected output, i don't see anything wrong with the question. He/she clearly explained what they have and what they want. It is clear what they are asking for, it's specific, isn't asking for an opinion or reference material, and therefore doesn't need to be closed.

---

In both cases, if you feel the user didn't do enough research before asking, **downvote it.** But don't try to shoehorn in a close reason that doesn't fit the question just because you don't like it.

Comment: According to [the guidelines, point 3](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), questions like Example 1 are not on-topic. But there is no way to signal that they are off-topic due to merely asking for someone else to solve the problem for you, lacking effort or evidence of what was tried.

Comment: I don't feel point 3 should even be there anymore. The majority of "homework" questions i've come across can be on topic once slightly edited to not be a homework question. If they can't be, they're likely closeable by the unclear or too broad reasons.

Comment: By that definition everything is homework.

Comment: I don't see what the question being about "homework" has to do with the questions relevance on stackoverflow.

Comment: I still think too broad would be the choice close reason, if it is indeed too broad. but, of course, whether or not it is too broad can be subjective, so you'd need 4 other people to agree with you. A question can be specific enough to side-step the too broad close reason without including attempted solutions.

Comment: There is no indication that the question is a homework question at this point. I'd much rather downvote the user so that rate limiting can do it's job, **even more so if it's a new user.**

Comment: @Mr.F You mean [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362586/sum-a-list-of-numbers-in-python)? Sure it's not exactly an amazing question, but votes indicate it has been well-received by the community. And on top of that, it has 186,107 views! That's a *lot* of people that question has helped, and I don't think it should just be discarded.