# Another way to close a not helpful question than to flag it?

Tags: discussion, flags, edits

### Problem

Because I frequently browse the `[autoit]` tag, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30972117/3750388) question.

It is

- completely misformatted, but there is no point in editing it, because
- a) it was already edited, although I ask myself what improvements
  where made and
- b) it is entirely out of scope of stackoverflow

The question contains way too much typos and too much information:

```
upload document/file using selenium C# webdriver from windows7 OS(moliza Firefox)
```

The first line is just bragging about a suggestions made in a previous question (on which this question depends):

```
I used autoit but autoit is not useful if we are trying run the code in another system.
```

And the second line is just leeching:

```
Plz provide me some useful code to upload a PDF document from system to the mozila broswer
```

Of course I've flagged to close this question, it

- contains no valuable information / research / effort
- asks about ready made code
- comments by the author would be rather considered "spammy" then useful
- the author clearly shows no intent to fix or improve this question

Now two questions:

- Is there another way of suggesting to close this question than flagging (which was already done)?
- How did this version got approval from anyone? Clearly, it has been edited, but it is still a mess. Granted, no edit could really improve this.

### Trivia

There also seems to be an increasing amount of selenium-related not-really-good questions in this tag lately...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a "no comment" close reason for these?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601)

Comment: You only have to earn 26 more rep points and you can give this question what it deserves, a downvote.  Couple of days at the rate you are going.