# Is demonstrative effort strictly needed if a question can be fully understood without it?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've noticed in places that people are keen to encourage and sometimes dismiss questions that lack things like suggested routes to solution, ideas, code, references, data-traces, etc. *I.e. evidence of research*.

There's some conception of minimum due diligence and people seem quick to evaluate on it, possibly judging by it as a guiding criteria. While *certainly in general*, researching any given question as well as routes to solution is a good thing and should be encouraged, is it conceivable that some questions are better, or at least adequately presented, without this demonstrative side?

Arguably I believe we can find samples that are inherently precise

> How to find all M-length sets of integers that sum to N?
>
> How to check if one string contains another substring?

I've frequenatly seen these type of questions, that can quite understood, but at the same time garner comments and votes faulting demonstrative lack.

So I'm wondering if upsides to a clean propositional approach is unfairly biased, possibly overlooked. Centrally, are we being judged by the *demonstrative* ability as a mandatory part of a good question? (As a good question isn't inherently worse just because the originator didn't prove it) And related, is there a tendency to conclude that lack of research *evidence* is the same as lack of research *effected*? (The originator might have spent too long or thought it was not appropriate.)

As a side-effect are we somewhat arrested in providing interfering content, to the degree of staining succinct and good looking questions with extraneous components?
Speaking from a certain transactional ideal even, isn't there a certain aesthetic in having questions without discourse on one side, clearly separated from candidate answers on the other?

Comment: Once I answered a question of this type, OP reaction: "I already tried this"... Oooook, lesson learned.

Comment: @brasofilo: But retort with "Well why didn't you say so?" and someone else flags that as rude/offensive. This is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: Quite a bit of discussion on this topic also here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions

Answer (score 25):

Yes, demonstrative effort is strictly needed. Let me take one of your examples and explain why.

> How to check if one string contains another substring?

Sure, I understand the question, but I don't know why you're asking it. Do you not know about the `contains` function (or equivalent) that's surely built in to your language of choice? Are you a student who has to implement this yourself without using a built-in function? Have you not seen the dozens of other questions dealing with this topic? If you have seen them, what's giving you trouble with the answers on those other questions?

So, even a question that appears to be fairly self-contained will generate several follow-up questions if you don't explain what you've tried so far and where you're stuck. If you just put that information in the question to begin with, we can get started answering the question much more quickly.

As for your other question...

> ...is there a tendency to conclude that lack of research evidence is the same as lack of research effected?

Yes, there is that tendency. I think Occam's razor applies here. If someone posts a question without showing any effort whatsoever, I don't know if they haven't done any research or if they simply haven't shown it, but I have a guess as to which one is more likely. It doesn't really make a difference to me, the question reader, though. Any research effort that you don't *show* is effort that I can't *see*, so it effectively doesn't exist.

Comment: + Another point is: If you see effort/code from OP you can see where exactly he got stuck and maybe explain that bit more than other stuff.

Comment: @area5one The only difference it makes is in how you might answer. It's fine for people to ask questions about school assignments.

Comment: @Bill thanks for you comment, you were quick to answer. Yes I was considering on the side if there is an ethical criteria to posting anwers, and I suppose it makes sense if this criteria is imposed equally regardless of the originator's motivation

Comment: @pnuts you may want to take a look at a similar (but more colorful) explanation given by Robert Harvey in an [answer to similar question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601), "_ME: Click the right mouse button. NOOB: What's a mouse?_ How much text do you suppose it will take to explain things now?"

Answer (score 4):

I do think this unspoken rule is annoying, but it is in place for very good
reason: most of the time **you have tried something**. I would say few have
tried literally nothing before posting on Stack Overflow. What usually happens:

1. User tries 1+ things
2. Said things do not work
3. User posts question
4. User includes 0+ things that they have tried

If you do not include at least some of what you have tried, the conversation
will go like this:

1. "OP, just use tactic X"
2. "I already tried that"

and back and forth until both parties realize what has and has not been tried,
then it is a matter of what is left that could work. This also prevents drive by
answers like this:

1. OP posts question without what they have tried
2. Person post answer of something they already tried
3. OP pleads that this has already been tried, falls on deaf ears and answer
   gets way upvoted
4. No one else posts answer because question has seemingly been solved

So you see in some cases you are just hurting yourself by doing this.