# How should I deal with users that clearly don't understand what they are talking about?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I was on SO looking for questions I could answer when I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37436206/3484498). The user is asking for help with his database, but it seems he doesn't even know how to interact with it, which makes it really hard to provide a helpful answer.

I went on the profile to triple check before I post here and I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25808038/3484498). (I let it up to you to understand what you can understand.)

This question is not about bashing this particular user, but more about **how to deal with such users.**

I ask this, because even with a lot of patience, I'm not sure if I could help him...

---

About possible duplicates:

I don't think my question is a duplicate of [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a "no comment" close reason for these?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261858/reviewing-some-awful-questions-is-just-a-waste-of-time-can-we-have-a-no-commen) because:

- that question was about "op showing no effort" (I would blame OP), mine is more about lack of knowledge (I wouldn't blame OP)
- I don't ask for a new close reason but for feedback about your reactions when confronted to such users

Comment: Close vote, down vote and forget them.   The question/code is probably not even theirs - they may have copied/stolen it, or perhaps they do others' homework for money.  There are a huge number of abusers on SO who will drain you of every drop of O-negative they can get out of you:(

Comment: Not sure but I think I remember of a flag on Super User which was pretty much like this : "OP lacks of knowledge and wouldn't understand answer". This is a bit rude but sometimes it makes sense

Comment: Point them to basic resources to help them learn the basics of what they are talking about. There's no need to be rude or abrupt, we were all beginners once.

Comment: We used to have a "Lacks Minimal Understanding" close reason on SO, but people used it differently from what was intended. It was eventually removed. You can find back some of the (heated) discussions about it on MSE and MSO, if you search for the phrase "Lacks Minimal Understanding".

Comment: that question was about "op showing no effort" (I would blame OP), mine is more about lack of knowledge (I wouldn't blame OP)

Comment: @Bulrush when you are going to play someone, it's always easier if you know the marks's name.  Just don't engage, it's safer.  You give these people an inch, and they will flag you as hostile and rude for not giving them a mile:(

Comment: If (note the "if") you want to take the high road, you can always add a comment with a link to information on how to ask a good Stack Overflow question BEFORE you downvote / close the question.  Like this:  http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. down vote
2. comment with 1 basic fault in logic OP has (only 1 !!)
3. see OP reaction. if reaction shows effort and some understanding, consider providing another hint
4. if reaction is not productive or non-existent - live long, prosper and forget it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I would try to link them some useful material that could get them from where they are to a place where they can ask for more specific help, and understand the responses given. If they read it or not, not my problem. I usually dont mind doing a simple google search for someone, if they have not shown any outright laziness so far that is. I figure some people are just so new that they feel lost when trying to look for answers and material on their own.

Comment: 'OK, i need some info.  I could seach for it, but those drones on SO can do it quicker - they did last time.  I'll just post it and go down the bar - some sucker wil have done my work for me when I get back'.

Comment: Like I said, I would only do this for people who have not shown any outright laziness so far. It takes me 3 minutes to find something the the questioner can use to get to where he/she needs to be to understand the help being given. I dont think everyone who asks a question and appears to be totally missing any understanding of what they need are bad people exploiting us for easy google searches. I mean how hard is it to share learning material anyway?