# Is beginner questions=too broad?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I understand this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291214/how-to-print-all-combination-of-two-digit-sum-xy-num

Is not well received because it contains at least 2 unwelcome elements:do my work and beginner level. But now this question is closed as too broad, which I'm not quite understand the reason.

As in my view, the solution can be just a for loop with few lines of codes, and the logic is simple and straightforward that there are only few reasonable ways to complete the requirement (I think the only reasonable way is looping y=9-x), so I'm not quite understand why this question is too broad.

Comment: It's more of a math question than anything. It is technically a programming question, and I can see how someone might think that it is too broad of a code request, but it doesn't really seem that unreasonable to me. Though I am a lowly JavaScript developer and am probably unaware of something that would make this question overly broad in the Java language.

Comment: _the solution can be just a for loop..._ ---> ["what's a for loop?" How much text do you suppose it will take to explain things now?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601)

Comment: "I need a optimize code".  Really??  "Too broad" is a standard reason that SO users pick when they actually mean "Not good enough to belong on SO".  Which you are forbidden from saying so you have to find a workaround.  It is the recommendation provided by moderators back when free speech was suppressed (summer 2003) and users could no longer find a reasonable way to get rid of junk.  When you carry out the garbage then the color of the bag doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would close this particular question as "unclear what you're asking" because it's asking for an "optimize" code.

Wait, *what*?

Here's what we *don't* know that would easily narrow the scope down:

- if the OP's code works at all
- if the OP's code works but performs slowly per *their* benchmarking efforts
- what is really meant by the OP when they claim they're looking for an optimized solution

It's not that beginner questions are bad.  They're on topic.  If you see anyone saying otherwise, point 'em here and let 'em have a bit of a talk on Meta about it.  (Or point them to as many discussions on "homework" questions as exist here; it has been discussed to death.)  But, we should be able to disambiguate between a *beginner* question and an *unclear* question.

Comment: @PaulCrovella:  Good.  That should give the OP a chance to clarify what it is they're asking.