# How is this too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173378/solve-ballistic-velocity-for-a-given-time

In my opinion it is extremely clear what needs to be achieved, it states clearly what information is available, and yet it is closed for being "too broad". According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) "too broad" means that answers would need to be too long to satisfy the question.

Although someone did provide a very lengthy answer (which was very good of them to explain their answer), the actual answer to the question was exactly 8 lines of code so clearly did not *necessitate* a large answer and therefore cannot logically be defined as "too broad".

This is clearly not a case of the questioner being unable to understand any answer given, as was proven by the fact that the questioner understood the answer that was accepted and (before edit) later edited the question to reflect information given in the answer. So this is not a duplicate of [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261858/reviewing-some-awful-questions-is-just-a-waste-of-time-can-we-have-a-no-commen).

Comment: The initial revision was just text, so that left us doing all the work. And that solution shouldn't have been edited into the question IMO.

Comment: @rene The first question was clear enough to start with. Given two positions what is the calculation required for angle + force. The answer to that question was exactly the same as the answer to the revised text. In addition to this, the question was closed long after the text of the question was revised to its current form.

Comment: Unrelated to the closure reason, but: don't add answers inside a question, and don't rant about close votes inside a question.

Comment: @rene Also I don't think it is appropriate to down-vote questions on here that criticise your decisions elsewhere, you should remain impartial.

Comment: Yes, I have closed it after it was edited. It probably sat in the CVQ when I handled it

Comment: @Stijn - Don't bring up the fact that questions have been invalidly closed? You must be joking?

Comment: I'm free to use my down votes.

Comment: @rene Yes you are free to do what you want, I am just suggesting you should use that freedom to act impartially.

Comment: @PeterMorris I'm talking about your question on SO, not the one here on MSO, if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @Pekka웃 The question asks how to calculate an initial vector.

Comment: Seems a common no-effort question that is usually downvoted (so expect more of that). Doesn't seem like it should be closed though.

Comment: @Stijn Ah, my mistake, sorry.

Comment: Whether the close reason was perfectly accurate is secondary. SO has a massive aversion against "I need code for this" questions because they come in by the thousands every day, and they tend to be toxic to fostering a community of professionals. Now, they rarely are as specific as this one, and they rarely come from a 3k rep user who has contributed to the place and asks intelligent questions, so I personally would have considered not downvoting and not voting to close. But the fact remains that it's basically a coding request and the longstanding consensus here is that we don't do those.

Comment: @RobertLongson It might look that way, but I always put effort into solving my problems before asking for help, and most of the time I end up coming back to StackOverflow to answer my own questions for others to benefit from in the future. But yes, it should not have been closed. It's just an unfortunate example of psychological group-think.

Comment: @PeterMorris you are expected to show that effort in the question. In this case you have not done so.

Comment: @Pekka웃 The question doesn't request code, it asks how a vector is calculated.

Comment: @RobertLongson That's because I got nowhere, there was nothing to show.

Comment: I rolled back your "edit". Please don't insult other members. Instead, edit to focus your question.

Comment: It's very hard to see how that's any different from a coding request. As said, I personally would probably not have voted to close/downvoted, but different people interpret the rules with differing strictness (and calling people names isn't going to help either way).

Comment: @Pekka웃 It's different because it is a request for an algorithm, not an implementation of the algorithm in C#.

Comment: @Tunaki Don't roll it back, edit it. The part of the question you rolled back contained a more concise version of the answer. This allowed me to give a clear & concise resolution whilst still giving credit (by accepting an answer) to the person who led me to derive the code given.

Comment: Answers should not be in the question. Your work so far to solve the question should be there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a "no comment" close reason for these?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261858/reviewing-some-awful-questions-is-just-a-waste-of-time-can-we-have-a-no-commen)

Comment: It's very hard to see the difference between a code request and an algorithm request. As said, morally, in an ideal world, I feel anyone with a healthy SO track record should get to ask this kind of question in an area they don't happen to be experienced in every now and then. I know I have my fair share of questions that don't fit the SO rules and I'd like to ask about. But it's not a sustainable model for a massive community with millions of users and an overwhelming majority of really bad questions. You gotta have rules... I don't know whether GameDevelopment.SE has any different rules

Comment: Re: "The question doesn't request code" And your SO question state: "Does anyone have a C# method that calculates the angle and force required to hit the target after the exact given duration" How asking explicitly for a method is not asking for code ? I had voted to close with "Off-Topic -> Why isn't this code working ?" reason, show an attempt even if it's blatantly wrong.

Comment: @Tensibai I forgot the part where I asked for a C# implementation. I was specifically after C# because all of the physics solutions I found were solving different parts of the same phenomenon (calculating speed at a specific point, calculating height after a specific time, etc). A solution that would make sense to a coder rather than a physicist would have sufficed.

Comment: @PeterMorris As SO is for programming problems, we do expect it for a code solution. But solving a physic problem with code still need a minimal amount of physic before translating it into code. All in all, that sounds to be "too broad" or "why isn't this code working" :) Don't take me wrong, that's perfectly fine to ask about it here to have a better idea on how SO community get things. I'm just trying to point out what I think is the reasoning behind the closure.

Comment: @Tensibai I understand your position, I just disagree. It's not just a physics problem, in game programming trajectories are pretty standard bread and butter coding so I don't think it was unreasonable to ask in the way I did.

Comment: @PeterMorris It would be reasonable on any discussion forum about game programming, not for SO Q/A format. We're back on the same thread as under Maroun answer.

Comment: @Tensibai It wasn't a discussion, it was a very specific coding question that happens to be useful in games.

Comment: @PeterMorris You already have 2 answers, you can disagree as long as you think SO is an exchange place. That doesn't change the overall consensus that the question without details on what you found and why it didn't help is not a good fit for SO. I can't really believe you didn't find anything searching for "C sharp balistic" to start from...

Comment: @Tensibai I found information on ballstics but, as I said, they were all related to solving different ballistic problems.

Comment: And you didn't learn anything from them ? Nevermind, we'll be starting an infinite loop here as it has already been  said above.

Comment: @Tensibai I learned how do to things other than what I wanted, yes.

Answer (score 14):

I close voted your question when it was presented to me in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/14610061).

Your question was tagged with c# and physics and at the time I saw it you edited in the answer.

As I focused on what was being asked, all I could distill from it was a request to come up with a formula or algorithm to calculate an outcome.
If you had included one attempt for a velocity calculation I would have had not much reason to close vote the well worded question.

But the lack of that bit of code, that result of the research you did for this algorithm made me to chose too broad as the close reason. I still feel my decision I made back then was correct. I often use the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to verify if questions are up to the standards.

I only failed doing one thing: I should have rolled back the edit that you made to include the answer. That is something I shouldn't have left for others to fix.

Here are some tips that might have helped the question:

- provide the method signature
- provide the results of your research
- make sure visitors will understand the context (Unity3D with its own Physics Engine expects maybe a different approach then a plain C# calculation)
- Tag correctly: Unity3d seems relevant for your question. Make sure it is there from the start.

Comment: I added the Unity3D tag today because I initially added Unity3D code in the solution. Now that this has been removed the Unity3D is actually superfluous as it is a standard algorithm question.

Answer (score 11):

Your question:

> Does anyone have a C# method that calculates the angle and force required to hit the target after the exact given duration?

We don't encourage "does anyone have a code for me" questions, and your question is explicitly requests code from us, and it doesn't really demonstrate efforts rather than describing your actual problem.

I doubt that "too broad" is the most accurate reason for closure, but the question should be definitely closed (and maybe downvoted too).

Comment: In game programming this kind of thing is extremely common. The solution will undoubtedly exist somewhere. Besides, it's a question in a C# forum, answers very often involve C#, that's the point.

Comment: ["Too Broad is absolutely the correct close reason..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601)

Comment: @gnat I really miss the "lacks a minimal understanding of the problem" reason, it's very descriptive and helpful, and it actually prevents "how my question is too broad" questions.

Comment: @PeterMorris Regardless of how common the problem is, we do expect to see minimal efforts.

Comment: @MarounMaroun and what do you expect to see when absolutely no progress was made? A signed statement that I made an effort but have nothing to show, hence I am asking in public for help? There isn't always something to show.

Comment: The problem is described very well. _"I know these variables, I just need the velocity"_. What's missing, and what makes it too broad, is an _attempt_ to get the missing variable. Or some indication of research like _"I've got this formula `<formula>` to calculate distance, but I don't know how to get the velocity out of that"_

Comment: @PeterMorris I think that you should specify that in your question, that you have actually looked and didn't find a solution that meets your problem. Describing your attempts, if there are any, would be great.

Comment: Note: _"I did some reaseach, but didn't find anything"_ isn't sufficient.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I am a 3K reputation user who has answered many questions - of course I attempted to solve the problem I am paid to solve before asking for help on a public forum. Why would I need to state "I promise I tried to solve this" in order for a question to be valid?

Comment: @Cerbrus then what should I have written? I didn't even have an algorithm to attempt to implement, so what example should I have given for what I had tried to implement?

Comment: @PeterMorris Well, it's not sufficient to add only "*I tried this and it didn't work*", there is no general rule - it's really specific for each case.

Comment: @PeterMorris: If all you have are those variables, you should probably have searched a bit before asking the question. A Google search for _"calculate required velocity and angle throw"_ returns [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17467/calculating-velocity-needed-to-hit-target-in-parabolic-arc) as first seach result. You could've gotten your answer from that.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I agree, and in *this* case there was absolutely nothing I could find that I could try. I was literally in an information black hole.

Comment: @PeterMorris Stop considering StackOverflow as a Forum, it is not a forum.

Comment: @Cerbrus Surely you know that Google results are tailored differently depending on who is searching? That search result certainly was not showing for me during my searches at the time.

Comment: @Tensibai I am using the word "forum" as per its English definition.

Comment: @PeterMorris if you mean "forum: a situation or meeting in which people can talk about a problem or matter", then it's not. Meta could be, but main SO is supposed to be a knowledge base, not a discussion place.

Comment: @Peter, if you search for that exact string, I'm sure you'll find some useful results too. That has nothing to do with personalized results. SO is not a "forum", just like SO's "reputation" system ins't related to the dictionary definition of "reputation". Dictionary definitions are inferior to context.

Comment: It's not a forum for discussion, but it is a forum for exchanging ideas. Of course it is, every answer given is someone's idea. You are being pedantic. I just didn't mean forum in the way you assumed, it's not a big deal.

Comment: The problem with people referring to SO as a forum, is that it gives other people the idea that it's indeed a (discussion) forum and it's okay to use it as such. SO is _not_ a forum. It's a Q/A site.

Comment: @Cerbrus If people don't understand English in a conversation taking place in the comments of this post, that isn't my problem.

Comment: If it's not your problem, don't get defensive when asked not to call SO a "forum".

Comment: @Cerbrus I didn't get defensive at all, I was being clear that I wasn't saying what you inferred.