# Handling 'Lack of Knowledge' in Question

Tags: discussion, edits

I was recently faced with the following situation and would like to know the best way to handle it.

I tried to provided an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41801864/how-to-get-model-description-list-in-unity3d/41802570#41802570), but it shows a clear *lack of knowledge* of the Unity3D environment.
The wording of elements shows that the poster is mixing things up.

Should I edit the title and the question to the proper wording or is this harming the intention of the user?

Comment: If the questioner lacks basic knowledge of the topic they're asking about, it makes their question too broad most of the time (where to start and where to stop if you want your answer to be useful ?). In this situation, I usually run away.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi so `Flag` would be the right solution?

Comment: I usually vote to close as *too broad*, yes, so a close flag would be warranted IMHO. Not a custom flag, though.

Comment: Nice answer, but this Q is begging for a tutorial and should be closed IMO.

Comment: Tensibai, i already flagged it. @FrédéricHamidi maybe you can post your comment as answer?

Comment: Now i got 5 Up-votes and the question is still not closed...

Comment: related: [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a “no comment” close reason for these?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601)

Comment: @Smartis - I don't think it needs to be closed any more, and the 5 upvotes you've now gained are probably a result of the meta effect.

Comment: SO made a policy change a few years back. We are no longer allowed to close questions because the OP is a dummy who doesn't even know programming. To assume that "if you don't know the topic you always ask too broad questions" simply isn't true. More likely perhaps, but not always the case. SO is no longer a site for professional/enthusiast programmers, but mostly a site for would-be programmers. Quantity instead of quality gives the site more traffic, which gives more profit to the site owners.

Comment: @lundin "Too broad" still works flawlessly for me. Easily defensible, as if the asker doesn't know programming, you'd have to write an entire book to teach it to them in order to answer their question, which won't fit in the answer box.

Comment: @CodyGray Suppose the question is "I don't know a thing about x language, but I heard about something called very-specific-language-feature. What does this do?" Suppose this question can be answered in a few sentences. Then you cannot flag it as too broad. Even though the OP doesn't have a clue and could easily find the answer  themselves in a beginner-level book. Or "how do you write hello world" followed by a completely failed attempt by the OP. Etc etc. We get a flood of these kind of very bad questions. They are not too broad and they are on-topic.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know enough about unity but I'm not sure that the given example warrants being closed as too broad when the answer you've provided is what appears to be the correct answer - even if that isn't the answer the op was expecting. I'd imagine a lot of the [reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) badges were awarded for these kind of question and answers.

However, had you found this question unanswered, then a VTC as too broad may have been warranted as it would have appeared to require a long explanation as to the mechanics of the framework.

> should i edit the title and the question to the proper wording?

I wouldn't as the core question wouldn't be improved with the proper wording and similar confused users may attempt to search for the same thing the op was asking

Answer (score 7):

I keep pre-written text in my Bookmarks. When I encounter a question like you describe, it's usually a noob. I remember what that was like, but it's easy to get frustrated at a perceived lack of effort, so if I don't even want to bother with it, I give them the text.

It welcomes the noob to Stack Overflow and suggests a process for asking questions:

- Google
- Refine/Add question
- Refine/Add code
- Make the error stick out
- Make your question stick out
- Cite other posts
- Say what you've tried and why it didn't work

I take out things they already have, and explain things they're missing. Or, if the question is *too far gone*, I just leave the text as a comment, and flag it.

They should teach Stack Overflow in college. It's hard to figure out what a "good" question is. Maybe the expectations are obvious in Silicon Valley, but not where I'm from. It took me a lot of time, sadness and frustration to figure it out. And I still don't have any "great" questions.

Write it when you're in a good mood. Put links to posts that helped you learn, updated it when you find something new. It's easy to get frustrated when it seems like a noob didn't even search Google before posting a question, but if you know you can't be nice, just give 'em the text. Besides, the question's going to get closed anyway, and all you have to do is a quick copy and paste. Hell, you could even write an [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) script to do it for you.

A kind comment can go a long way to help someone become a better user. A lot of people don't fully understand what SO is, and a lot are intimidated because it seems like public speaking. Yes, its frustrating to get crappy questions, but the fact that they're trying to understand shouldn't be discouraged.

Comment: `Refine/Add code` should go before `Refine/Add question`.

Answer (score 3):

> So should i edit the title and the question to the proper wording?

Yes, and no. If the question asker had this wording, chances are other beginners might search for the question with the same wording. The real question is whether the question is more interesting for beginners or proficient people, and also if proficient people all use the same wording.

Weighing these factors, simply giving an answer where you clarify the wording or explain concepts can be more helpful than editing the question.

You always should consider searchability when thinking about editing things like that. Though often it makes sense to edit a questions title especially if the question could help future readers aswell, though, leaving parts of the old wording atleast in the question text can help searchability.

Also make sure to save your edits in a textfile or do them later, otherwise the author might edit the question and render your work useless through edit conflicts.