# How is this question "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen-closed

[UEFI application.. shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177177/uefi-application-shell-command) is asking outright "how do I call a UEFI Shell command from an application invoked from the UEFI shell". The question is if anything overly precise, asking how to run the "cp" command.

This is not a normal sandboxed operating system environment, and the answer is probably "you don't", but it can end up being a lot more useful than that.

Comment: My guess would be because he's asking for a pretty general solution (without the example).

Comment: The classic mistake he made was asking entirely too many SO users for help with a niche topic.  Without giving anybody a chance to learn anything about the topic.  Q+A is a two-way street, this one is heading down a one-way street, against traffic.  You might be able to rescue it by removing the [c] tag.

Comment: @HansPassant: Now that's an answer I can agree with, but as even this question has been closed as duplicate by people who don't understand the question, I guess it's time for my yearly frustration-induced hiatus.

Answer (score 12):

I was one of the close voters.

My close vote was based on the absence of any evidence of trying anything, making it much too broad ("*I haven't even started; please write it for me!*").  If the question showed the existing (mcve of) the claimed `app.efi` source, with a comment like `must copy foo to bar at this point`, then I'd have probably left it open at review.

Comment: ["What's a mouse?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601) :)

Comment: _"My close vote was based on the absence of any evidence of trying anything"_ that has never been a reason to close vote.

Comment: @TinyGiant Not inherently, but it will often make the scope of the question Too Broad.

Answer (score 6):

The exact text the author see is (emphasis is mine):

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with **enough
>   detail to identify an adequate answer**. Avoid asking multiple distinct
>   questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this
>   question.

Which is quite the problem here, there's no details on the context or what the author has tried before encountering a road block.

Quoting the How to ask page:

> Help others reproduce the problem
>
> Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is
>   with code you've written, you should include some.

This implies you already did try to solve the problem yourself, SO is not a free code service.

As is, this question could have been closed as 'off-topic => seeking for a tutorial' also. The reason is not really important at this point, the goal is to drive the author into improving the question (showing efforts) before reopening so it can get an actual answer and not answers based on guesses (at best).