# When should I stop trying to help?

Tags: discussion, help-vampire

Sometimes new users struggle to make obvious questions for several reasons. I like to be a good boy and try to help us anyway: at least try to make them "feel" what the community expects to see for a good question.

But, sometimes there's bad comprehension of the language and software development in general and everything becomes harder.

In [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45011967/no-handlers-could-be-found-for-logger-git-remote), I first asked in comments for a complete traceback (because, you know people usually just paste `Error: Foo`, but not the whole traceback, which makes it way harder to debug). But the asker doesn't know what a traceback is, so he pastes pieces of code with some explainations.

At this point I feel the guy is really trying to make his question better, but does not know how to do so. So I tried to help again, asking for whole functions + traceback.

Well, after the last comment it finally appears that the `Error: Foo` was only a warning... I made my part of the mistake here, but it's not really the point.

---

How do you deal with a fellow who really tried to ask a good question, but needs a long comment discussion to finally make it (because of being new to SO + not confident with the language + not confident with development at all)?

**And especially when the comments section starts to be a long discussion between only two people - not even code related, but SO related - when should I end it?**

Because now, all comments under the questions are just useless for future users, but nobody would never reply without this long discussion to make the question answerable.

I'm not sure if I should avoid clogging up the comments section, or keep trying to help.

---

Plot twist: By the time I wrote this, some answers have been posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> when should I end it?

Whenever you grow tired of it. As you already know, this back-and-forth isn't the model or purpose of Stack Overflow, and it isn't helping anyone else.

Questions that require this type of engagement will suffer one of two fates:

1. Ideally, the user will take heed of your little back-and-forth chat to substantially improve their question. At that point, the question will become suitable for Stack Overflow, and all of the obsolete comments can be removed (either by each of you, or via a moderator flag).
2. The question will be neglected and eventually deleted.

In either case, it really just boils down to how much time you want to waste. Err, I mean, how helpful you want to try and be.

Some users will caution you that engaging in back-and-forth discussions like this is ["feeding the help vampires"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/366904), or otherwise [encouraging users that ask insufficiently specified questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86319/153008). But I'm putting that aside here, because you specifically asked about the case where the user is obviously trying hard to ask a good question, and I'm assuming that this is an isolated incident.

Whether you decide to try and help in the comments or not, if you see a question that is too broad, unclear, or otherwise unanswerable in the Stack Overflow format, please do us all a favor and flag it as such.

Comment: To remove my comments and ask for op/moderators to clean comments sections may be the way I'm more confortable with. As you can see after I edited my question, it start to have answers, so maybe I really helped here. Yep, I flag too broad questions, but like to gives people at least one chance to be better.

Answer (score 6):

In such a situation SO isn't the right tool for the job.  They need a tutor, a teacher (in a class), a tutorial on the subject, a book, or some other source that's designed to convey more than is suitable for an SO question.  At that point [the SO question is simply Too Broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/1159478), given how much one would need to cover in order to help the OP get to an answer.  If you would like, you could suggest a more suitable means of getting an answer in a comment (like one of the options mentioned above).

Comment: I'm not sure it's really too broad here, but I got the point and will have it in mind for the future, it's maybe pretty hard, but well, pointing out people needs to **learn** and ask after is one of my favorite things in SO - so I understand

Comment: @Arount The question wouldn't be too broad if someone had suitable background knowledge; what you're describing is a situation where the question author lacks so much background knowledge that explaining enough for them to actually understand the question and the answer *would* be Too Broad.

Comment: hmm, I'm kind of ok with your point of view but needs time to make it mine. I feel it's maybe a little too hard.. don't know.. Techically, you're write, but maybe it's ok to not fit the rules everytime?