# How was this spam question upvoted three times? Do we have fake users?

Tags: discussion, scope, users

EDIT: Question mark as duplicate is atleast related to code and having only one upvote. Here the question is totally different and having 3 upvotes.

Recently I checked a question which was off topic. I flagged to closed that question.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208798/which-restaurant-offers-the-best-chicken-karahi-in-islamabad-pakistan) of that question. And there is the one screenshot

[image]

I just want to know how anyone can upvote such a of question.

Is this fair?  I just want to point out that it may be possible there are fake user accours upvoting such off topic question stuff.

Let me know how moderator will deal with such users.

Comment: Indeed! This could be evidence of a voting ring. Definitely flag for moderator attention. Can you post a working link (or flag it yourself)?

Comment: With 3 upvotes I would guess that this could be a voting ring, but such posts also can sometimes get upvotes from users who randomly upvote stuff or in general upvote almost everything.

Comment: Was there an answer?  I like curries:)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks for indicate the link issue. I have updated that.

Comment: @MartinJames yes, There was an answer which should be in comment.

Comment: @Rizier123 I agree with your point but 3 upvotes ?? randomly ? does they have not read the questions heading ?

Comment: It is tagged [tag:php], what do you expect? Of course it gets up voted ...

Comment: It's not about "fair" or not fair. Yes, there are "fake users" (sockpuppets) on SO. SO mods delete them. The way to deal with this situation is just to cast a custom flag and explain the situation to the mods.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I am curious to know, how can I directly contact to mods? for such situation. I just want to know.  thanks

Comment: I just told you, cast a custom flag and move on. The mods will deal with this.

Comment: @rene upvoted just for tag !!!

Comment: @DavidArenburg I agree with you. and I did so.

Comment: This was the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208798/which-restaurant-offers-the-best-chicken-karahi-in-islamabad-pakistan

Comment: A high-rep user edited the question.  Strikes one as a completely insane thing to do, doesn't it?  Well, nobody is going to look at it with a title like that, maybe nonsense like this is necessary to avoid the [infinitely worse outcome](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261874/17034).  Hmm.

Comment: @HansPassant yah right, I have not noticed that.

Comment: *You know that feeling when you're just that hungry...* - Also... I can't wait to offer a bounty on this amazing question!

Comment: They should have: 1/. post it on a low Freq Tag so no one see. 2/. Then edit  php c# c++ tag into the question. 3/. place a 500 Bounty asking more information about shipping to EU and US. 4/. Became top post in a week!

Comment: Is question about chiken curry the only solution to bring back Jon and Hans?

Comment: Got same thing here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217225/how-open-tor-website-from-python-code-or-linux-console (bad question upvoted - I already flagged it, so can't ask mods)

Comment: @Arount Please cast your vote to close that question and also flag that question.

Comment: @CodeLღver hm, I think my english do not help me here, by "cast" what did you mean? I downvoted it + flag it as too board, so I can not re-flag for mods? (I am right ?) EDIT - Ok, that not my english, but my eyes. Ok, mods called

Comment: @Arount You did right. :)

Comment: Guys, upvotes on a question related to programming (although VLQ) can lead to genuine upvotes as there could be people straggling with the same problem- hence I wouldn't suspect a voting ring here right away, while a question regarding restaurants is a whole new story.

Comment: Guys relax, some people would upvote it just because it made them laugh and being so blatantly off topic.

Comment: @Alex for the question discussed here 3 upvotes seems about 2 too many to be explained that way. I regularly observe a single random upvote to senseless / blatant spam / abusive posts but no more than that

Comment: @gnat It's hive mentality. They see one guy upvote ironically, so they'd be edgey and do the same thing.

Comment: Also, @HansPassant mentioned the "high rep" user who edited this question, and that was me. I did it "ironically", because it was such a blatantly obvious spam question. Chalk it down to my inexperience. Will refrain from this in future.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ consider giving a read to [Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030/165773)