# How can this question get four votes?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, voting-fraud

*[Microservices with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225896/micro-services-with-asp-net)*

In nine hours. It's pretty appalling.

This is not a duplicate of *[How was this spam question upvoted three times? Do we have fake users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352542/how-was-this-spam-question-upvoted-three-times-do-we-have-fake-users)* - that question was spam.

Comment: @CodeLღver - that question was quite obviously spam. This one is not

Comment: Best is to flag for a moderator. They have some tools to check for patterns. The question might do well in Google results due to the current hype on *micro services*, the brand new concept based on technologies that have been around for 20 years ...

Comment: Agreed. I don't think this question is spam. I also don't see why it is considered low quality and I don't understand why it is unbelievable that it received 4 up votes

Comment: I agree with other peoples consensus, the question seems fine (even if it is a duplicate) and 4 upvotes in 9 hours isn't crazy.

Comment: @George you can't know the exact voting times. If all votes were in a short time frame it is suspicious. Not something we can see, only mods (or even Devs) can see that.

Comment: @rene Yes you can, you just need to get your detective monocle out, or you could just look at the user's activity and have a look at their reputation changes. They had three upvotes in the space of an hour and then one upvote an hour ago, which to me seems alright.

Comment: @George ah, yes, you're right. I didn't check the user profile. Those votes could well have been due to question being kept active.  Good call.

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName stop robo-reviewing please.

Comment: It might still be a dup-li-cate (bypassing [this annoying everlasting bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified)) of [Who keeps upvoting these terrible questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349820/who-keeps-upvoting-these-terrible-questions) though. Not that it has a definitive answer, because we simply don't know.

Answer (score -11):

I really don't see the problem with the question or why it is considered low quality. As a long time programmer I feel I have a very good grasp on a wide range of programming concepts and can answer a vast majority of questions. Yet, I did not know the answer to that question.

If anything, it is [a duplicate of a high quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498911/run-multiple-instances-with-one-click-in-visual-studio) *(which might even deserve to be protected)* that actually needed a paid a bounty for an answer.

Even then [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498911/run-multiple-instances-with-one-click-in-visual-studio) is prefaced with:

> "Not many people seem to know this, but this is perfectly possible,
>   though I admit it's not very obvious."

In fact, today at work I was running unit tests with Selenium against an ASP.NET MVC application using two separate solutions and two different instances of Visual Studio, because I didn't know until reading that question that I could start more than one project at the same time.

I am just saying I personally would have upvoted that question. Why is it that you think it is a low quality question?

Comment: Background information isn't noise, @CodeCaster. There is nothing wrong with decorating the core question with a bit of context as to what you're doing as long as you're not writing a novel.

Comment: @BoltClock the only relevance is _"I have a Visual Studio solution containing various Web Application projects. When I press F5, it debugs only one of them. How do I start debugging multiple projects at the same time?"_. There is absolutely no need to bore us with irrelevant details about microservices, which is an ill-defined term in and of itself. I'm however not advocating the question's only contents should be _"How to debug multiple projects simultaneously in Visual Studio?"_, I'm saying that's what they should've asked Google before coming here.