# I know it's not too broad or is it?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons, needs-more-focus

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147137/how-can-i-get-this-format-tuesday-march-4-from-4th-march-2018) SO question.
The user wants specific output on given input, but the question has been put on hold as too broad.
It's very straight forward (OK not very straight forward but I understand it completely), so I tried digging into similar questions and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python) question with over 1200 votes.
Comparing both, I found them very similar, which landed me here.
What should I do in this case, provided I know the answer to the question?

Comment: Might have been better to close it as a duplicate to one of the other 100 date formatting questions.

Comment: Questions that used to be on-topic in the past is not necessary on-topic now. That's why historical locks exist.

Comment: @BDL Indeed. That question is possible duplicate of many date-formatting question, but I took that as an example.

Comment: Generating duplicates is okayish, but it does have a practical limit.  Google does not like sites that have a bunch of new content that merely links to old content and if google stops liking us then we might as well call it quits.  Anybody notice that we lost ranking in December last year?  Page views are down by ~13%, uh-oh.  If you want to help this user at all then tell him how to find the answer.  In a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a "no comment" close reason for these?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261858/reviewing-some-awful-questions-is-just-a-waste-of-time-can-we-have-a-no-commen)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is too broad in the sense that it shows neither context nor research effort.

The rationale is that without context or a show of effort, we might as well write a textbook to explain everything the OP needs to know.

Although in truth, "Too broad" is also used just to close it. It's a zero-effort question, and users want it closed before somebody tries to farm rep by answering it.

That also tells you what you should do: downvote. You *could* give the asker a solution in the comments, but quite frankly I'd rather you didn't. I'd rather not see zero-effort dumps like this rewarded with solutions.

The other question is older, but would nowadays be closed in the same way. Note also that a moderator, who is well-versed in Python, has given that question "protected" status.

Comment: Also if you look at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72899/timeline) it was posted as a community wiki in 08

Comment: There are many questions there on **how to**, **how do I do this**, etc., have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-to-check-whether-a-file-exists?rq=1) that's why I got confused.

Comment: As I don't have the reputation for closing a question, if I see something like this should I flag it, and how, and will it be useful?

Comment: @global_warming They are very very old, when it's unlikely to be a dupe. Now, no-effort -> dupe -> downvote.

Comment: @user202729 You could flag as "Too broad". There's some risk the flag will be declined. But since it's a zero-effort question, you can and should downvote. You could also look for duplicates, if you have some time to spare. Then flag as a duplicate.

Comment: @global_warming Those questions are very old. They were asked when Stack Overflow was new, and still welcomed these. Over the years, they gained many upvotes. But they are not examples of questions we want now. I admit that the many upvotes are misleading.

Comment: But is it too-broad? I understand downvotes and possible duplicates are valid though.

Comment: @global_warming Well... probably it isn't. But it doesn't worth the effort to reopen it just to close it again.

Comment: @global_warming Arguably. As long as you have less than 3k rep, flagging as duplicate is safer. There's probably a simple snippet that solves it, so in that sense the question would not really be "Too broad".  People just use that to close it ASAP.

Comment: @user202729 If I had delete votes I'd gladly use them.

Comment: I have seen it quite often is the alternative use of close reason generaly tb and unclear ok?