# Correct Flag for Extremely Basic Questions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49694090/add-some-thing-before-a-letter-in-string-in-python) that was posted. This question is something that most Python Tutorials walk through as you are learning the language. There seems to be zero effort in figuring out how to solve the issue.

It has currently attracted a few higher-rep answers. Granted, some of the answers provide feedback that will help the OP learn a "best practice" along with multiple ways to solve the answer,  but it seems that these posts need more than a down-vote. Based on this post [asking for such a close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back), is there any update on this? This just seems like a "rep-whore-galore" attraction type question.

At my current rep and privileges, is there something else that *should* be done? Or should I walk away with future cases such as this?

My intentions are not to shame the OP or the other posters.

Comment: I see that question as one of the better "easy" questions I've seen in awhile.  The author clearly spent time trying to solve their problem, they were able to solve most of it, they showed what they did, explained what does and doesn't work, has a problem that's narrowly scoped but not something that only one person could ever want to do, and (from the perspective of someone who doesn't code in python anyway) I could imagine how, given the approach they're using to solve the problem, I can see why they might not have found the answer to their question with a reasonable amount of research.

Comment: @Servy, fair enough! seems reasonable. Tim Post also did a nice edit since posting that made this more of the structure you are talking about.

Comment: A dup vote tends to be the correct choice.  But hard to find on a question like this, so doesn't happen.   You do have to wonder a bit if it is really that "basic" when everybody knows a solution, but they don't agree much which each other.  SO always did have a knack for being more useful to the contributors than the questioner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a "no comment" close reason for these?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261858/reviewing-some-awful-questions-is-just-a-waste-of-time-can-we-have-a-no-commen)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be duplicate. It's not an "awful question". It might seem basic and it could very well be a duplicate, but it's not an "awful question".

Comment: duplicate is exactly about questions like that. Question like ["What's a mouse"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601) isn't awful outside of Stack Overflow too, I dump questions like that to Google search every day. It only becomes awful if asked here because it's a poor fit to SO format which is not designed for basics tutoring

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's not really a *correct* flag for this as while the question was in need of some polishing, it contained everything that we ask folks to supply. A look at the original title makes it pretty obvious that the OP just didn't know what to search for, even though they seem to understand the root of the issue.

In *most* cases, you're probably looking at a duplicate, so you've got some options:

- Edit, if you have the time and inclination - people vested in the tag will mark it as a duplicate of the best canonical version if there is one. ***This is what I usually do, since people with Python tag badges tend to know what they have in 'inventory' better than anyone else.***
- Leave a comment to let the OP know the terms they *should* have used while searching which will lead them to probably 15 incarnations of great answers to that question
- *If* you're sure that you understand the question, you can flag / cast a close vote as a duplicate, but please be pretty certain. The best way is just to engage in a comment and see if a light went on for them.
- Just answer it :) This depends on how much time you want to spend when you *know* it's a duplicate, you just aren't sure what the best target might be.

But when you get a question that has an example, what they actually got when running it, what they *wanted* to get when running it, etc - ***you have a good question***, so assume the best in the asker and do your best to help them. 99% of the time, they just weren't aware that there was a term they could have used to turn up what they needed without much effort.

Fun fact: over 90% of people asking on Stack Overflow search prior to asking (we tracked this and surveyed it as we were looking into tests to run on how we could improve the ask question page). So when you see potential in the form of a question containing everything needed to answer, it's generally worth a small investment of your time to help.

Or, and this is totally fine, just move on - no worries if you do, but it'd be a shame to just shoot it down when they put the effort into giving us everything we asked for.

Answer (score 6):

There is no flag for that. Sometimes extremely basic questions are necessary.

The questions you need to ask yourself about an extremely basic question are

1. Is this a duplicate? Most of the extremely basic questions have been asked and answered ([some of them very well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it))
2. Is this a minimal question? We have a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requirement and minimal means minimal. If you can answer the question, and it's not a dupe, answer it or leave it. It might not be a *good* question, but we want to help people if we can.