# How can we prevent users from doing asker's homework for them?

Tags: discussion

I come across many questions on SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078807/how-do-i-take-a-user-inputted-msg-and-decrypt-or-encrypt-the-msg-using-2-lists) where the user is very new to programming, still needs to learn several foundational concepts, and is likely doing homework or some kind of personal practice problem. This typically leads to the following problematic behaviour from other users:

1. Downvotes if the user doesn't seem to have made enough effort to solve the problem. Some users don't seem to understand that a beginner may be at a complete loss at how to even start tackling a problem.
2. Answers that completely solve the problem and prevent the asker from learning how to solve a problem themselves, possibly doing their homework for them.
3. Answers or comments involving very high-level concepts or functions that the asker probably won't understand, where the asker probably needs to use much simpler concepts so that they can build a proper foundation for their programming knowledge. For example an answer in the linked question uses Python's extremely high-level and specific `maketrans` and `translate` functions for strings. Meanwhile the user just needs to write a couple of `for` loops and maybe use a dictionary or `.index`, and really needs to learn how to do so.

Personally when I see questions like this I want to guide the user step by step towards solving the problem themselves to give them a more useful learning experience. I don't think I'm the only one who feels this way. But inevitably *some* users will do the above. In particular, when a user answers the question with a complete solution, the asker will no longer care about replying to my comments and learning. Their homework is done.

What can we do about this?

1. Is it acceptable to downvote or flag answers that essentially do the asker's homework for them? I'm guessing the answer is "no".
2. Can we close/flag questions as homework? Once a question is closed then no one can answer it and thus the user is forced to solve their problem more gradually. I've seen other meta questions covering this topic and the answers are essentially "no, the existing close reasons are good enough". I'm not quite convinced by this. Taking the linked question as an example: the user has provided some code and mentioned searching for other questions, which seems to have satisfied viewers and prevented any close votes. But the code doesn't actually relate to the problem the user has, it's just a user interface.
3. Can we have a site for beginners and homework? Again I can see that this has been discussed repeatedly here, but I'm not satisfied with the other questions and answers. In particular I'm not suggesting a split based on reputation, and I'm not expecting only beginners to be on the site. I'm thinking of a site where beginners ask questions and experts answer them step by step, not spoonfeeding the asker. Behaviour like the above would be discouraged, and questions that would be downvoted or closed here might be handled more gracefully there. Homework questions on SO could be migrated. I understand that this requires more patience and there would probably be fewer volunteers, but I think it's worth a try.

Comment: I also like to help people understand their problem and to help them find their own solution but that is contrary to the culture here.

Comment: @Elin who’s culture? Why do you think we ask for an MCVE and detailed description of the problem in the first place, if not to help the OP towards a solution?

Comment: @gnat I don't see how that question is mildly related to mine.

Comment: [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601) explains exactly what is expected of you in cases like you ask about

Comment: @gnat (1) in 2 hours, the linked question has received 1 close vote (was that you?) so I think it's worth discussing a bit more how to tackle this problem, even if that just means figuring out how to get more close votes on such questions. (2) closing the question doesn't bring the asker any closer to solving their problem (3) I'm specifically proposing a site where lots of text and patience explaining things to noobs is the expectation. (4) the lack of understanding in these questions is typically not that extreme.

Comment: @AlexHall: this is already well-covered ground. See the duplicates I closed this to. I have an urge to ask if you did your homework before posting this. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did look at several questions, none of those came up. I see some useful material in there but I don't see any tackling of the core problem in my question, which is that beginners who need to learn how to solve their own problems are having the problem solved for them. This wouldn't be a problem if everyone followed the answering guidelines in "How do I ask and answer homework questions?", but we can't practically expect such perfect cooperation, especially if explicitly told not to downvote answers that simply do homework for the asker.

Comment: i mean... that's assuming the downvotes on the answer are for that reason. You're probably right at the end of the day, but... it's certainly not an every case is X kind of situation.

Comment: @AlexHall why is that a problem you need to see solved? The asker suffers in that they won’t get a proper education (not understanding code will hurt them sooner or later).  SO doesn’t suffer, we instead get more content. And you can’t always know, with certainty, that homework is involved at all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters (1) I don't understand the question. Why don't I want people to get a proper education? (2) It's not so much about whether homework in a formal class setting is involved. It's about beginners who need to learn rather than be fed code.

Comment: I don't see why should you care. If asker doesn't want to be given a full solution of a problem - he can just state that in a question (and I saw a couple of such cases, though of course it's very rare). Otherwise, there is no reason to treat this question differently and assume you know what is good for other people better then themselves. Asker can learn a lot from a detailed answer, even if it contains a full solution, if we wants to.

Comment: @Evk thanks, you're right, although it's taken me a while to see it. There are probably cases where offering a full solution is harmful, but it's too difficult to correctly identify them and do the optimal thing instead.

Comment: @Lankymart I mean something more detailed than that even after they have an example.  I'd just rather help someone figure it out than give them the answer e.g. by asking them questions I know the answer to. Like "what is g() returning?"

Comment: It seems like a split site would kind of become a "gimme teh codez" site, which I really can't see working well.

Comment: "There are probably cases where offering a full solution is harmful" - but we are not in school here. In school, it's arguably reasonable for teacher to assume he knows what is better for kids then kids themselves. Not the case here. Such behavior might even feel insulting to asker. For example person that solves "some kind of personal practice problem" might only be interested in solution and not for you to teach him step by step.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it acceptable to downvote or flag answers that essentially do the asker's homework for them? I'm guessing the answer is "no".

Correct.

> Can we close/flag questions as homework?

No. We can close/flag question for many reasons, but not just because you think (or indeed know) it's someone's homework.

If the **subject** of the question is on topic, then votes and flags should be on the **quality** of the question. However, you should also be looking at editing the question (if possible) to improve it rather than just down-voting and/or voting to close. Also be careful of assuming that just because the situation described appears to be artificial that it is homework. There may be genuine reasons that the poster hasn't gone into that mean that things have to be done a certain way. For example if it's a legacy system.

Engage the poster, help them ask a better question. Even if it turns out to be homework they'll be able to ask better questions when they're working on a real system.

> Can we have a site for beginners and homework?

You are correct this has been done to death already. The biggest problem with a site like that would be attracting the necessary experts who were prepared to answer *nothing but* beginner's questions or homework questions.

While I'm probably as guilty as the next person of answering such questions once in a while, I don't think I'd want to hang around a site where that was all I could answer.

Comment: Right, this is what I expected, but it's the last point that bothers me the most. I understand that attracting what amounts to volunteer tutors is hard. I don't think it's impossible. To what extent has it been tried? If it hasn't, why are we so sure it's not worth trying? Personally I'd be willing to answer such questions now and then.

Comment: @AlexHall: but do you understand the problem with plainly answering such questions? Yes, the OP can submit their code and pass the bar. But will they have learnt anything? Other than that there will hopefully always be someone else who can do their work for them? The better answers attempt to *teach*; but that is quite difficult, given that you don't know the full extent of an OP's background, and whether or not they bluntly copy the code part at the end of your long and detailed explanation.

Comment: @AlexHall I think it's the "now and then" part that's the problem. I think a lot of people would be willing to answer "now and then", but I don't think there's enough of us to do the site justice. Unfortunately I'm not in a position to set up an experiment so I can be proved wrong.

Comment: But *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)* is (was?) all about answering homework problems (straight homework dumps are happily accepted). And it is doing well. [Sample 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383557). [Sample 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2757774).

Comment: @PeterMortensen but it's not **just** about answering homework problems (unless I'm misunderstanding the scope of the site).

Comment: @usr2564301 but I'm specifically talking about a site where plainly answering homework questions is discouraged, and askers are taught instead.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Math.SE being able to manage homework dumps the way they do is an extremely interesting phenomenon, I've been pondering about this quite a lot in the past. My theory is, they can afford such a lenient attitude primarily because of specifics of their topic and audience and that this can't be replicated on a Q&A site handling programming topics

Comment: [1/2]@AlexHall: There have been plenty of sites that tried to be specialized on beginner education. Non of them turned out well for more than a few years. For all of this sites I participated in the problem was that either askers were so demanding (not even looking up the slightest bit of information themselfs, nothing worked unless you spoon-feed them) that it drove away experts or that experts got exhausted by explaining on a daily bases very basic algorithms (for example, how to loop over the characters of a string).

Comment: [2/2] Don't get me wrong, I'm absolutely not against education new programmers. I'm teaching beginner level courses at a university since years now and really like it. I just don't think that it can work out in an online community with volunteers.

Comment: @BDL thanks, I think this answers my question. Can you point me to any of these sites? Side note: I didn't get a notification for your comment. I think there might need to be a space before the @.

Comment: @AlexHall: I participated a lot in [tutorials.de](https://www.tutorials.de/) when it was new (it's in german). Then moved to [informatik-forum](https://www.informatik-forum.at/) (also in german, the programming forum is gone since years now). Some of the other sites closed down completely.