# But seriously. How to be nice when trying to say the code is crap?

Tags: discussion, code, behavior, welcoming

I came upon a question just now where the OP's code has serious errors which leads to problems, and the OP asks how to solve the problems. So far, so good, but after having the serious errors pointed out to them, they refuse to correct those, they only want a solution for the resulting problems!

How to proceed in a case like this? How to not break the "be nice" rule while trying to explain that their question doesn't fit the SO quality standards, and will probably be deleted? (In many cases, the OP doesn't mind about the quality standards, so that's not even a good reason in their eyes not to provide them the quick fix.)
Also, if they don't listen at all, which close reason to use? "The code is crap and is not salvageable" is not among the close reasons.

---

Note: the last sentence above was an afterthought, and it is addressed in questions like [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a “no comment” close reason for these?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261858/1016716), but that is not the main focus of my question.

Comment: I'd downvote and close perhaps as "unclear what you're asking"? And possibly add a comment along the lines of "I'm sorry, but the problems result from the serious problems in your code pointed out above. If you're not going to fix those, there's nothing we can do to help."

Comment: I lean towards _Too Broad_ since explaining things to OP in such cases would probably need a full fledged tutorial or the singe question may have multiple issues needing multiple questions.

Comment: Don't say anything. If there are many serious problems throughout the code, then the question is too broad, we should vote to close it as too broad, and move on. Comments made to help improve the question won't likely help in this situation.

Comment: *Hey @MrLister see how Mr Nice Guy answered all my demands. Was that so hard for you to do?*

Comment: Helpful for the community and future visitors is probably a close vote, too broad will work or a custom reason: *I'm closing this question because it has too many unrelated issues to the core problem and answers would be confusing if they address the core problem but not the other issues or vice versa.*

Comment: Consider cleaning up comments under such questions to prevent being haunted by them forever ....

Comment: The eternal question:(

Comment: @rene "haunted by them forever" -- Isn't this a little too... fearful? The question here doesn't even quote the existing comments.

Comment: @duplode it is fearful, yes. I assumed the eggshells could carry this weight ...

Comment: @rene I just mean I don't think we should preemptively delete our own constructive comments aimed at driving improvements to a post.

Comment: @duplode the problem is that we usually do a bad job at judging how constructive our own comments are. If the receiving party doesn't seem to find them constructive, they obviously aren't and doesn't become better by keep hitting the user with extra comments how constructive, welcoming and helpful your comments are. They have already been dismissed, you've lost the rally. You're hardly ever going to gain trust in that conversation again. The persistent idea of the old bunch here that they are leaving constructive comments, is the problem. Stop doing that. That is nice.

Comment: at least this is the question, but it's even bad when someone answer with wrong code and you try to correct him ... and even worse when such answer get upvoted or accepted.

Comment: Be nice - so what, OP has not got an answer from you.  Be not nice, so what, OP has not got an answer from you.  Be welcoming, so what, OP has not got an answer from you.  Be really snarky and rude, so what, OP has not got an answer from you.  Whatever you do, so what, OP has not got an answer from you.  So, just go with the minimum effort on your part - down/close/delete vote.  Commenting is often just a waste of typing that identifies an abuse/retaliation target:(

Comment: @rene I agree there is no point in repeating the same point over multiple comments, and I have said as much in my answer. However (1) according to the question here, the point hadn't been repeated *yet*; and (2) there is a line to be drawn: for instance, if there is a *single*, technically correct comment saying literally "The root of the problem here is X; once you fix that, further workarounds won't be needed", and the OP replies "This is not constructive" without having ruled out answers addressing X beforehand, *the OP is simply wrong*.

Comment: @duplode sure, and what are you going to do about that OP being wrong? Send electric shocks through their keyboard? I mean this [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/386/) is not joke. That is us.

Comment: @rene "what are you going to do about that OP being wrong?" -- Disengage and move on. All I'm saying is that, in such a case, I won't delete my comment in addition to that. (It is not even just a point of principle: it might discourage someone else to make the same point again.)

Comment: Ca I hear more about the 'electric shocks' plan?  Can it be done cheaply enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a "no comment" close reason for these?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261858/reviewing-some-awful-questions-is-just-a-waste-of-time-can-we-have-a-no-commen)

Comment: You mean like [this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198640/c-sharp-sqlcommands-are-not-working) though IMHO this case is worst, since there where already two harmful answers when I saw it. Depending on how much time I have and the mood I'm in, I might post answers like the one I did, but I usually don't bother and just leave a comment on the question saying the code have multiple problems (I might even name a few) and vote to close as too broad.

Comment: The dupe candidate asks for the option of a comment-less close reason for obviously crap, this question asks for the possibilities of a nice commenting of a crap code. I see too significant differences here to accept their dupe-ness.

Comment: I take it back. Your case is worst. Seems to me like you and the other user trying to help the OP have done more then enough - It might be unpleasant to say but some people are just not that good at thinking (and yes, that was me trying to be as nice as I can about it. PC and all that). I think this is just one of those cases where the best thing to do is just give up explaining and vote to close.

Comment: Just walk away. You've offered help, it's been declined, don't waste any more time on this person. Let them dig themselves deeper into their hole. (More seriously, think about your motivation. Why do you feel compelled to make them listen to you? Yes, we all hate it that there are incompetent people in our profession giving the whole industry a bad name. But you're not going to solve that single-handedly)

Comment: Do not try to sell fixing the code as "quality standards". Tell them "fixing X will help you solve Y, that 's why I recommended it". Also, there's crap and there's crap: something that betrays a fundamental lack of understanding, vs legitimately shortcutting that a busy person might do. It's hard to triage.

Comment: You have to remember to focus on the problem expressed by the OP. If I take my car to the mechanic because I have an oil filter problem the last thing I need my mechanic to say to me is go paint your car and them bring it back that color is aweful. I know that I don't always write great code when I'm just trying things out.

Comment: @dannyhut No. First, the primary purpose of this site is to have a bunch of questions that help others as well in the future. Unsalvageable code is not useful. Second, I'm talking about actual bad code; things we are taught at school we shouldn't do. UB, invalid HTML, memory leaks, SQL injection etc. Not how their result looks aesthetically, if they're using HTML tables where they're not needed etc. Not even using C libraries in C++ programs! Oh, and if you're just trying things out and posting about your attempts here, then you should welcome comments about how you should do it instead!

Comment: Anyway, I find it difficult to accept one of the answers here. Most of them say just downvote and VTC and move on, but that won't help the OPs. If we can teach the OPs to write better code, then we can expect them to come up with better questions in the future, rather than turning them away and letting them continue writing bad code.

Comment: @MrLister: "*that won't help the OPs*" Like you said, the purpose of the site is to have questions whose answers help others. Helping the OP is only useful as a means to that end. If the OP is told what to do, but refuses to do so, *let it go*.

Comment: @NicolBolas But is that nice to the community? That way, we end up with lots of deleted bad questions (that could have turned into good questions, with some effort) and lots of disgruntled people who only posted once and never return because they think SO is elitist.

Comment: @MrLister: Guidance on how to ask is what the *system* should provide, not users. You may have missed that part of the blog post. You're in good company; lots of people did.

Comment: Mr Lister If I'm simply trying to solve a problem by writing a piece of code that will never be used for any other reason than trying to solve my problem, then I can pretty much guarantee I'm not going to worry about a memory leak or two. As for welcoming comments about how I should do something, if your referencing my question then yes but otherwise who decided the commentor knows best. Personally I hate using while(true) {} to avoid a goto but that's just me, should I expect someone to remove this in a question before I answer that question?

Comment: My argument is we shouldn't assume we have a handle on what constitutes well written code. Programming is about managing complexity, if the code does that then how its achieved should not be an issue.

Comment: It is very unlikely I'm going to post production code whether I own it or not on a public forum, I'm going to hack up an example that illustrates my problem. I'm not going to worry about catching exceptions, checking values or any other things that just add to the complexity of my example. This comment was meant to go at the end of my last comment.

Comment: @ZoharPeled funny enough, the biggest problem on the post you linked is the OTHER answer. I.E the user with 33k reputation, 300 questions of abysmal quality, terrible answers, yet is constantly posting more. Your answer has +4, and his is accepted with -1. THAT is a real problem on SO. I have had the same conversation (elsewhere) with that same user about his poor quality. He doesn't care, but has 33k+ reputation! How is that even possible? People just keep feeding into his poor questions and answers though...

Comment: You can't. it's inherently not nice to say someone else's work is crappy. Just give up, you don't have to argue on that, explain it one time, it's OP's problem if he wants to understand it or not.

Comment: @JacobH There comes a time when you realize that the post owner reputation is far from being the only thing to consider when estimating the post quality.... I've seen worst posts by 100k+ rep users (though admittedly, not that many). I've also seen good posts by that user, BTW.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sure, the rep isn't a good sign, although it *should* be. Aside from rep, the 300 very poor quality questions tells me that user is a help vampire for the most part.  You've noticed the [same garbage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281183/delay-in-a-task) [as I have](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23ed61a7-fa23-4f01-8c1a-451042eb4faf/view-source) [for sure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45492282/trim-hashsetstring)

Comment: @JacobH I wouldn't call a user that have 10 times more answers than question a help vampire. Since him and me both post questions and answers about c# and Sql Server, I've seen him around. He is not half as bad as you make him out to be. I admit I didn't go through his answers or questions methodically, but what I have seen, some are bad, some are good.

Comment: @ZoharPeled well that's kind of my point. For someone who is effectively a full moderator of this website, he shouldn't have half good half bad posts.

Comment: @JacobH reputation builds up... upvotes weight is much higher than downvotes weight (10/5 vs 2). I'm sure you can do the math yourself - for our conversation - it means that even a user with a negative score on all their posts can still have a high reputation, if they have enough posts.... You are welcome to suggest a different scoring system, but I think the one we have now is quite good, even with all it's inherent problems.

Comment: @MrLister "Most of them say just downvote and VTC and move on, but that won't help the OPs" -- My answer (and, I presume, most of the other ones) take it for granted that the problem with the code was already explained to the OP, and assume that the discussion here is about how should the exchange of comments evolve after that has been done.

Comment: People are still confused as to what to do with help vampires? Seems we need a Stack Overflow for masochists.

Answer (score 88):

The idea you're trying to communicate is inherently not nice. So don't bother trying to communicate it.

Downvote, close vote if it's appropriate (if a post has lots of disparate bugs, then it's Too Broad), and move on.

Comment: I agree for the most part, but I think "don't bother being nice" somewhat implies that it's OK to be *not* nice, and I don't think that's the case. There's nothing inherently "not nice" about constructive criticism, and you *can* deliver it in a manner that isn't sarcastic or belittling, which is the part that a *small* part of this community sometimes misses.

Comment: @meagar no, it actually implies "if you can't be nice, just SYA and don't say anything".

Comment: @Braiam I realize that's what people *should* infer from it, but it's easy to take it the wrong way.

Comment: @meagar: "*"don't bother being nice"*" That's not what I said. I said don't bother "trying to communicate" things that are "inherently not nice".

Comment: To me, this is an example of where we (I) have issues with the now *infamous blog* and being nice in general. Because voting and moving on doesn't produce the desired results for SO and voting without specified reasons now falls into the not-so-nice category, we (I) have an obligation to at least create data that can be used to determine our effective niceness. We can do that by providing examples of what we (I) see as the "real" problem.

Comment: @meagar And your attitude creates the one of this answer: do nothing to help the person. How is that nicer? This "be more welcoming" nonsense has users afraid to actually criticize anything, even constructively. That is *not* healthy for the community. We're not here to make people feel good about themselves. We're here to help them be better programmers; they can feel good when they become better programmers.

Comment: Reminds me of dating and how ghosting is deemed to be accepted practice, but on the other end, you're just left hanging.  Wouldn't it be better to tell the guy/girl the code is crap?  I get seriously annoyed with the anonymous downvote with no feedback.  It's BS.  We should have the courage to give the feedback, and not worry about being mean.  Feedback will help them improve.  A downvote will not.  I was going to simply downvote your answer, but wrote this as well.

Comment: This answer seems to be ambiguous. The two comments above appear to be assuming that the "inherently not nice" idea you talk about is "there is a serious mistake in your code", as opposed to "your code is crap" (which is what I believe to be the most natural interpretation of what you have said).

Comment: @jpmc26 "do nothing to help the person" -- Cf. my comment just above, and also note that the Meta OP had already pointed out the mistake in the code, so that probably shouldn't be the primary focus of this discussion.

Comment: @duplode "The two comments above appear to be assuming that the 'inherently not nice' idea you talk about is 'there is a serious mistake in your code', as opposed to 'your code is crap'." These are just different presentations of the same point, so the answer is not ambiguous. "Crap code" is just code with major design flaws.

Comment: @jpmc26 (1) Presentation matters. (2) "Your code does XYZ, which is a serious mistake" is an objective, likely actionable assessment that the asker and other readers can build upon. "Your code is crap" is a value judgement that, in comparison, adds very little to the discussion. So there are relevant differences.

Comment: @duplode Obviously there are differences. Nonetheless, this "be welcoming" mess is having the exact opposite effect: a chilling one. Because this answer is right: telling someone they did not do a good job is fundamentally never going to be pleasant. It is always going to pose the risk of offending the reader.

Comment: @jpmc26 Of course the risk is always going to be there. The question always was, and still is, how much risk we should accept -- too little, and no criticism is possible; too much, and criticism becomes counterproductive. *It is not an all-or-nothing situation*. Those who frame it as such are making a questionable risk assessment, which achieves little more than radicalising the debate and entrenching fears.

Comment: Meagar I agree but we have to be careful that we are not imposing our own views onto others. You may think that I have done something wrong and pointing that out to me is great, but if I don't agree with you then it becomes a question of who is right. As its my code shouldn't I be the one to decide.

Comment: @duplode You're missing my point. This "be more welcoming" push has driven many users to decide on the "nothing" approach, because apparently the balancing we've done over the past 10 years isn't good enough anymore. Keeping a neutral attitude isn't good enough now. It's considered rude to point out that the line of code that appears in an error message is missing from the post if you include the word "clearly" when saying it's needed! Now we have to kowtow to the feelings of every person who types something into the box if we want to say *anything*.

Comment: @jpmc26: "*Keeping a neutral attitude isn't good enough now. It's considered rude to point out that the line of code that appears in an error message is missing from the post!*" I do not recall any statement about site policies regarding this. I suggested not engaging because the sentiment "your code is crap" is not something that needs to be conveyed through text. That was just as true last year as this year. That some people have decided to overreact and stop commenting wholesale is up to them; there have been no policy changes that I am aware of.

Comment: @NicolBolas SO employees have linked [this commentary](https://medium.com/@Aprilw/suffering-on-stack-overflow-c46414a34a52). That's where I got it from.

Comment: @jpmc26: Also, it should be noted that the comment in question did not say that the line was missing from the post; it said that they couldn't tell which line was that line number. Also, that's not all the comment said; it reminded the user that an error with a line number means that the error happened on that line. Last time I checked, human beings with basic reading comprehension can figure that part out, which makes it rather condescending to be reminded of that. I wouldn't go so far as to call the comment "rude", but it was definitely in the ballpark.

Comment: @jpmc26: A "neutral attitude" would have been "Could you tell us what line #49 is?" And that attitude would have been just as neutral 10 years ago as today.

Comment: @NicolBolas I would not call that a neutral attitude, as it fails to communicate that there is a fundamentally unacceptable problem with the post stemming from the OP's failure to think their question through at all when they wrote it. As such, it is timid, rather than neutral. That is not behavior we should tolerate. How would you communicate that? Also, it is not uncommon for error messages to include the text of the line that caused the problem; if the question's language did so, then it would have to be that the line is actually missing from the post.

Comment: @jpmc26: "*I would not call that a neutral attitude, as it fails to communicate that there is a fundamentally unacceptable problem with the post stemming from the OP's failure to think their question through at all when they wrote it.*" ... That right there is what the blog post is talking about. The stuff about "fundamentally unacceptable" and "the OP's failure to think their question through" is entirely unnecessary. Like I said in my answer here, if that's what you're wanting to say, just don't engage. That you describe non-confrontational statements as "timid" is really the problem.

Comment: @jpmc26: You communicate "unacceptable" with a close vote. You explain what is missing with a comment.

Comment: @NicolBolas Low rep users can't see close votes until the question is closed, if I recall correctly. How are they supposed to learn what they're doing is not acceptable and improve if people don't tell them? It's like I said: we're not here to make you feel good; we're here to help you be a better programmer. The hardest thing to do in programming is to learn to think things through and to analyze a problem. People won't learn to do that if no one tells them they need to. Being unwilling to tell people that is a failure on *our* part, and that's what you're discouraging people from doing.

Comment: No jpmc26, you are not here to make people better Programmers. People ask questions of people they hope can help solve their problem, if in the process they end up better programmers that's great but I fail to see who decided the commentor know best. I can assure you there are many things I do people would say I shouldn't. Making suggestions and recommendations is fine but disparaging some one because they don't follow your rules is wrong. I have seen many cases of this behaviour here and on other forums. How are people to learn if you offend them to the point they stop listening to you.

Comment: If a question has lots of disparate bugs, then the MCVE close reason seems more appropriate, as this provides more specific feedback regarding how we want OP to change their question (whether or not they actually do that is another matter altogether).

Comment: This all boils down to the idealists who love to say "there is no such thing as a stupid question", which I personally think is such a thing as a stupid saying. The idealists are in war with the cynics, who believe that a percentage of the world's population are unfortunately morons and that's just how it will always be. These two groups form camps on SO meta and debate endlessly, where one group insists that there are no stupid questions and the other group insists that of course there are stupid questions.

Comment: Probably, the only way to make both those groups happy is a close reason that allows the cynics to tell the moron that they are a moron without being so rude, while at the same time allowing the bad question to be archived/edited for eternity, thereby also sating the idealists. The "poster must demonstrate minimum knowledge" close reason was the solution to this.

Comment: @jpmc26 [1/2] Nicol has already made most of the points I could have raised with respect to your last few comments. I'll just add that (1) Latching onto that specific "clearly" example and taking as an injurious attack, or as evidence that we supposedly can't criticise anymore, is a good example of the pernicious all-or-nothing approach I was talking about.

Comment: @jpmc26 [2/2] (2) I'm not missing your point. I see what you describe as a chilling effect as a largely self-inflicted condition. If those people who feel compelled "to decide on the 'nothing' approach" are really so adamant about owning up to one's own feelings, they would do good in having a look at the mirror. Their defensiveness is making they throw nuance out of the window, and getting in the way of proper critical reading of what is being said in this debate.

Answer (score 40):

I usually call these situations "extenuating constraints"; the code that is presented to us is not code that anyone would actually want to use in production, but is code that the OP has decided to constrain themselves to.

The big thing to keep in mind is to respect the OP's constraints and try to answer their question as best you can within them.  If your answer *breaks* those constraints, explaining why it does would be valuable.

If they still refuse your answer even after that, then there's not much else to say; disengage with them.  You've done your part in answering their question; if they don't like your answer, they at that point have the right to downvote and not accept your answer.

---

As to the title of your question:  if you want to call someone *else's* code "crap", then poke around at your repository and see what you've written three or four years ago.  We all had to start from *something*.  Otherwise I agree with Nicol's sentiment; what you're trying to say isn't inherently polite to begin with, so there's no benefit in you saying it.

Comment: You make an important point. Approaching the post from what "you" or anyone would use in ***production*** is at the very least ignoring the OP's constraints or position.

Comment: "The big thing to keep in mind is to respect the OP's constraints and try to answer their question as best you can within them." Nope. Nope. Nope. Never do this. Always tell them why their approach is fundamentally flawed. We have enough material for DailyWTF, thanks.

Comment: @jpmc26: Yeah... I can understand respecting constraints that are out of the asker's control, but this?

Comment: @jpmc26:  When the situation warrants it, *sure*.  If they want to be obstinate and not accept that their way isn't suitable, then there's really no incentive in continuing the dialog with them since no one's going to get anywhere with it.

Comment: I fully agree with you Makoto. We need to remember no one is perfect and we all started knowing nothing. To disparage someone for being at this stage is wrong.

Comment: Makoto I still don't know who decided that the commentor knows best. If you believe they aren't writing the code correctly send them an EMail and explain your concerns, don't just comment and leave. The comments should not be for debate and yes considering what I'm doing now I do see the irony. To comment on some ones programming style or method is inviting debate and has no place in the comments section of a forum, IMHO.

Comment: I welcome people call out my crap code. I do it to myself all the time. I don't understand how anybody would expect to get better if they're coddled all the time.

Comment: Some level of improvement can only come with experience. Everybody writes crap code in the beginning and without _any_ experience it is hard to learn from many suggestions, set the user on track and help them to improve step by step.

Comment: Nobody writes 'i++ + ++I' code in the beginning, the middle or the end, except profs/TA's after a tequila too many.

Answer (score 15):

Being nice is easy, just struggle doing it like me.

*Disclaimer: I think judging someone's effort as "crap" is "pre-not-nice". Although it may be of the majority's opinion, "crap" is a not-so-nice way to pass subjective judgement on an individual's effort without consideration to their "self". ("self" being all things related to being oneself)*

The people who I respect, if not admire, are those who, despite the circumstances, persist with niceness. This is true for more costly forms of learning like courses or bootcamps. No company will berate or pass judgement on a paying client no matter how "crap" their efforts are; there are better ways. And none of those ways includes voting them down or failing to provide guidance. And when guidance fails, you can *still be nice!*

Simply say:

> "I've provided you with what I believe is the minimal amount of edit suggestions required to bring your post up to the standards which we hold dear; please address these issues. When you do, I will be glad to assist you further."

That's surely nice enough. But, more importantly, you've clearly set the boundaries for yourself and in some, if not most, cases, the community. That accomplishes what voting, flagging, and moving on does not.

If SO wants a more inclusive community, we have to provide the path to inclusion.

Comment: I sometimes comment on beginner code to point out how overcomplicated it is (and what a simpler way is), but I usually (or at least sometimes) try to say that it's *normal* for beginner code to be a mess.  And that writing bad code in a language you're just learning doesn't make you a bad person.  But usually I only comment like this when there's a reasonable question and it's just surrounded by a mess, not really like what this question is about.

Comment: I don't think making an edit (or suggested-edit) on the question really fits with what this meta question is about.  I think this is about handling questions with serious separate issues in their code attempt at doing whatever the question title says they're asking about.  So an edit wouldn't be appropriate at all; if you want to correct the code you'd post an answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes, fair enough. To be honest, I'm interested in learning about and adhering to what I consider the *new* expectations of SO. Like I meant to say, we should consider ways to progress past these issues or at least hit an obvious wall where it's clear the OP has no intent to adhere to even the basic expectations.

Comment: That will squash the issues brought about by those who I struggle to identify with. I put a lot of effort into my questions, others don't, but how do I bring them to that point? Voting, flagging, or closing, alone, in may cases, doesn't do it and taking that approach seems to be at least discouraged as of late.

Comment: You forget the goal of the site, we are building a knowledge base for programmers, not a one-to-one tutorial service for clueless people. Those questions *should not exist* in the first place, and no future visitor will benefit from them, they are garbage. "voting, flagging, closing" will trigger the garbage collector to clean up the site, this is all we should do.

Comment: @liliscent, that's obvious. But what's not obvious is how we reconcile the current concerns against our own expectations. I fully understand your point and have done my best to adhere to it. But am I adhering to a subset of user's interpretation of it? It seems so. As we see it, we are moderating the site: oh, this is bad -> close -- this is x -> action. That isn't very different than passing on every person who doesn't immediately know everything. If we want better quality through means other than try/fail/try-again, which seems to not work, we have to be more creative.

Comment: -1 for supposing it is desirable or even possible for a free library website to have the same relationship to a minority of its patrons as an expensive bootcamp has to each of its customers. What's more, your assertion that "No company will […] pass judgement on a paying client no matter how "crap" their efforts are" isn't even true in the first place. Or have you never heard of courses passing out failing grades?

Comment: `You forget the goal of the site, we are building a knowledge base for programmers, not a one-to-one tutorial service for clueless people` Well I'm kinda questioning this statement, to be honest. I mean, we're all "don't just ask questions, provide code so that we know what you tried" which actually switch the focus from a general answer to precisely a one-to-one help session. Aren't we contradicting ourselves a little bit?

Comment: @KevinGosse "What have you tried" shouldn't be seen as a requirement in and of itself. Asking for that should aim at making the question answerable without guessing, or adequately scoped, or easier to understand, or more useful to future readers. Before asking that (or, for that matter, before asking for an MCVE) from an OP, it is worth asking oneself whether it will help towards those goals.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, thanks. I wasn't clear; I wasn't suggesting the relationships should be the same. Getting help on SO isn't like formal training or bootcamps. I was saying, if you're going to volunteer to help, don't find creative ways to tell someone their code is crap or flag it as crap, help as much as you're willing then close it off with a nice see-ya later.

Comment: @NathanTuggy,I also didn't mean passing final judgment like "failing grades"; it's Q&A like asking for help while learning. Trying to get help might go better if it didn't end with your code being called crap. I believe in cases like OP's where you've already decided to help, don't end it bad by being an ass. It gives fuel to the arguments being laid against the community and our desire for quality is overshadowed by the tone.

Comment: @KevinGosse: Well tbh finding the balance between "tightly-scoped enough to be immediately useful to someone with an essentially identical problem" and "loosely-scoped enough to usually be useful to more than a dozen people" has been one of the major challenges to exercise meta since the site started.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: It's perfectly reasonable to tell people that downclosevoting is enough without insults, or even rude remarks about someone's code, but the analogies used don't appear to match very closely, and have unfortunate implications.

Comment: I agree Peter with your comment on editing questions, I have had other posters edit my questions few times and they have all been greatly improved by the effort. Great stuff.

Comment: This is pure vitrol. You _must_ at all times separate a persons work with the person itself. If someone says my code is "crap", it's my problem if my "self" is hurt. I agree however, that "crap" is not a very nice way of putting it, and would not express myself that way. However, you have all the wrong reasons, and this type of reasoning it _vey_ dangerous.

Comment: @vidstige, I hope to have time soon to edit the answer well-enough to convey my point better but I disagree with your thoughts. Yes, we should separate a person from their work (*when appropriate*) but "your code is crap" isn't doing that and "crap" is just a secondary problem. If you feel that it's whatever user's problem that another user who was supposedly helping them was "not very nice" then I don't think you've grasped the issue OP is referring to. Note I don't think it's always appropriate to separate the self. That's implicitly exclusionary in some cases and that's unfortunate here.

Comment: Just to clarify, I felt your took a wrong turn already in the disclaimer. Here an unreasonable, selfish, and unfair focus is put on the "self" of the asker. When you look at questions at SO, you marvel at how many people have _read_ them, although only (usually) one person asked the question. Therefore, when giving feedback on questions, it's of utter importance that the community at large is considered before the "self". However, I still agree one should be nice. And extra nice to new-comers. I feel for example it's nice gesture to start the comment with "Welcome to Stackoverflow" or similar.

Comment: @KevinGosse: Debugging questions usually have the least future value of any kind of SO question.  Encouraging people to turn their questions into debugging questions is the last thing we should do.  But for homework questions, that's often the only way for it to fit on SO at all.  Find the max integer in an array and print it to stdout is not an interesting question for anyone that knows the language and how to program in general, but usually it's specific enough that it's not an exact duplicate of an existing find-the-max question so we can't just duphammer it.

Comment: 'That accomplishes what voting, flagging, and moving on does not.' - yes, it does, it provides a username as a target.

Comment: I mean, I don't see how 'this code is trash' can personally reflect upon the OP's programming skills when they didn't write it, and have plainly copied it from homework or an online quiz, but SO is not my site, so fine, I no longer describe 'i++ + ++i' trash code as trash.  That saves me from getting suspended, and I can just down and close vote as dupe.  Imma happy with that, SO is happy, we're all happy:)

Comment: @Martin, over the six years I've been here, I've never been targeted even while having little restraint for making myself a "target" the majority of the time. But it's a valid point.

Comment: @Martin, I think you're making some assumptions there but ultimately everyone's happy so great.

Answer (score 7):

If the mistakes have already been pointed out, but the OP refuses to listen, there is nothing much that can be done, and there is also little reason to further escalate the argument (I'd say "trying to say the code is crap" is a bit of a red herring). Posting your fix to the blatant XY problem and letting the OP make of that what they will could be an appropriate course of action, depending on how useful you think the answer would be. Downvoting the question as not useful and disengaging could also make sense.

(I'm not making a blanket suggestion about closing, as it really depends on the individual situation. "Too broad", for instance, might apply if there are many serious mistakes that would have to be addressed.)

Comment: In this particular case I don't think Y is solvable but otherwise agree.

Comment: This. Harping on is inherently *not nice* and a waste of your time. Also, others will often pick up and take your place in the chorus of voices, at least by upvoting your previous constructing comment.

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly possible to say something which is truthful and helpful yet won't risk a "be nice" violation:

*"You rejected the suggestions which I offered you on how to improve(/clean/refactor) your code and fix the errors, so I'm unable to help you (further)."*

and also *"Asking for solutions without fixing the code is not what SO is for"*.

Comment: Yes. That's where I have a tendency to get snarky. I really have to unlearn that. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @MrLister: I have empathy because I'm sometimes also on the receiving end of that situation. Sometimes a respondent has not made a compelling case why I should rewrite things their way, sometimes the advantages are not obvious or are outweighed by disadvantages, sometimes a respondent has misunderstood my question, sometimes even a respondent is (gasp) wrong, sometimes the OP is not in a learning mood and just wants working code urgently. It helps to stop and look at the exchange and see if they misunderstood the advantage of what you're suggesting, or where things went south.

Comment: I recently finished a comment with: *I wish you luck*. With a lot of effort I managed to omit the *you're going to need it* part. Having the unsaid part echoing through my head made me fell better.

Comment: @Oldfart: what is the toxic snark level with you guys? :) If someone rejects our advice, it's just part of life.

Comment: That snarl has come out once in the last six months. I don't mind stupid questions. I do mind moronic code which you spend 30 minutes on to clean up and point out where they are wrong, then to hear in derogative wording that they know better. Those 30 minutes I could have helped somebody else.

Comment: @Oldfart the problem is no one decided that you know better. May be the OP is right and their way of doing something is the right way not yours. This sort attitude is the problem. You say your right they say their right, to get upset about them saying your wrong is a bit like the pot calling the kettle black.

Answer (score 5):

If the purpose of replying, at all, is to be helpful, either to the OP or to the community, then perhaps the approach to take is to use it as a chance to educate about the circumstance.

For example, you could say, from the question, I would suggest we could represent the problem or situation as follow:

> Your version of the critical code elements that represent the actual problem

For situations like this, an approach to a solution may take the following form:

> Your approach to solving the problem

You're not talking about the person, their code, their understanding, etc.  You're looking at the logical or technical situation and trying to share wisdom with those who come across the question so that people in similar situations may find useful directions towards solving their problems.

It's probably a good idea never to make the solution about the person, but about the problem?

Comment: "It's probably a good idea never to make the solution about the person, but about the problem?" Yes, this is psychology 101 - address the problem, not the person