# Duplicate solves "a" problem OP will have but only after they solve "the" problem they asked about

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792825/unexpected-token-error-on-java-while-loop) question is about a syntax error OP's getting. The problem is that they're writing

```
while (1) {
}
```

When Java expects a boolean, not an integer, as a condition for a `while` loop.

The question has been closed as a duplicate of [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559539/java-identifier-expected) question which will solve a problem the user already has but will notice only *after* they solve the actual problem they're asking about.

In particular, the linked question is about the fact that the code is outside a method, which causes a different error then the one OP asked about.

OP's code *is* outside a method, but this is not what they're asking, even if they *will* encounter that problem as soon as they solve their current one.

Is that a legitimate duplicate?

Comment: Let's just add this one to the dupe list and call it a day: [Passing an int function to a while loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52574699/passing-an-int-function-to-a-while-loop-in-java/)

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Done.

Comment: Since this is my first question on meta, can the downvoters please explain to me why this question deserves downvotes?

Comment: @JoshCaswell:  That was...not the right dupe to use.  There's a better Java-specific one.  I've added it in.

Comment: Your original question was not clear at all. Remember, we’re not all Java experts! That’s likely why it was downvoted, and definitely why I closed it. After your edits, this is much clearer and better. So, I reopened. I imagine some folks just haven’t had time to reverse their downvotes. Also worth noting that downvotes on Meta are often used to indicate agreement or disagreement with the issue you’re raising. So, some voters may be trying to say this isn’t an issue worth discussing.

Comment: Thanks, @Makoto! I thought it explained the error pretty well, but I also don't know Java.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca understand that downvotes on meta are a way to express disagreement. It doesn't necessarily mean you did something wrong the way it does on SO.

Answer (score 18):

In the past it used to be the case that, if a dupe couldn't answer *every* tenet of a problem, we would have to reopen the question and allow a more specific answer.

Now, if a question is duplicated by two existing answers, we can add that in fairly straightforward.

I stand by my dupe closure here; the first dupe solves the *immediate* Java-specific problem that the OP is facing, and the second dupe (added later, admittedly) solves the problem that the OP will face *later*.  There's no reason for us to duplicate this information anywhere else on the site.

Comment: Not only that, but if we didn't close this question as a duplicate, we'd end up having to close it as "too broad". I personally prefer to err on the side of marking as a duplicate when possible, since that is more helpful to everyone.

Comment: I prefer, since the question is readily available, to just delete this duplicate. It's not an useful signpost for either of those questions due having multiple issues.

Comment: @Braiam:  I think the system should take care of it.  I don't see it as pressing enough to delete before the system has a chance to.

Comment: The system will **never have a chance** since it has an answer.

Comment: @Braiam:  The answer doesn't score above 0, so it falls in the more aggressive timeline for auto deletion.  I don't see it *likely* that anyone's going to give this question enough attention to upvote the answer, but...

Comment: I think you need a refresher on the roomba rules: If the question is more than 30 days old, and: has −1 or lower score; **has no answers**; is not locked. The score on the answer isn't taken into account when deleting by the rules except when it's closed as non-duplicate.

Comment: Ah, I had missed that entry when looking at the Roomba rules.  Irrespective of that, I really don't see this matter as so pressing that it warrants *immediate* deletion, however I don't have an opposition to seeing it gone.

Comment: It needs to no immediate deletion, but someone needs to kick the can if we expect it to see it gone at any point of time.

Comment: @CodyGray: Wrt. "... close it as "too broad"" - In *what* universe is that question too broad?! Yes, it's a duplicate, and it should be closed as such - but anyone who thinks that question is "too broad" should stop flagging and look in a mirror. Groundless kneejerk closures are a huge problem on SO - please do not add to that problem. I get that people want to "get rid of the trash" quickly, to keep it from building up and turning the place into a "dump", but throwing the baby out with the bathwater is counter-productive.

Comment: @Aleksi Questions that require that an introductory tutorial on a programming language be typed into the answer box are generally considered "too broad" on Stack Overflow. This is not a tutorial site; we exist to answer (indeed, to build a library of answers to) *specific* programming questions. When there are multiple different problems going on in a single question, reflecting a fundamental lack of knowledge about the language, that is really getting outside of our domain. These quickly become chameleon questions, where the topic shifts as soon as an answer is given, which are problematic.

Comment: @CodyGray: Sure. But that question doesn't require an introductory tutorial to answer it. The question boils down to "Why does `while(1)` give me an error?", and I personally struggle to invent any example of a less broad question. That is very much a specific programming question. If you think that's too broad, you're not judging the question on its own merits, but rather judging the user and extrapolating what you *think* will happen after the question has been answered.

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo:  Please note that said error was only the *second* problem with the question.  The first one was, obviously, that the code in the question wasn't in a method.  It's this slippery slope which I think Cody is referring to; one problem turns into two; two problems turn into three; three problems turn into a help desk session.

Comment: The case for "Too Broad" here, as explained by Robert Harvey: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/

Comment: @Makoto: Yes, I noticed that (although I'd say the numbering is the other way around, as Java seems to complain about the other one first). There is a second problem in the code given, but that wasn't what the question was about. Based on the code, the asker will face a second error after he fixes the first one, but that's neither here or there - the question that was asked isn't "too broad" by any means. And it is a sad state of affairs when questions are being closed just because of how someone *thinks* the asker is going to react to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> In particular, the linked question is about the fact that the code is outside a method, which causes a different error then the one OP asked about.

That's not true.  That is the problem that the Original Poster asked about.  I quote:

> on while loop it gives unexpected token error.

I admit it's not literally the same error.  It's unexpected token instead of identifier required, but that's just that the code has a `while` loop there where the other had something (`input.name()`) that was not a reserved word.  The solution is the same.  Put the code in a method (where a constructor is a special type of method).

Now, it may be that we should have picked a different dupe target.  One that said essentially the same thing but about unexpected token.  But putting the code in a method is the correct answer to the question that the OP asked.

The part about needing to say `while (true)` instead of `while (1)` is the additional problem that they aren't reaching.  The code would get a Boolean required error on that, but the compiler hadn't gotten that far.  It still didn't understand why there was a `while` token where it's expecting a field, method, or interior class declaration.  If they had fixed this problem, then they still would have had the unexpected token problem.  It would have seemingly made no difference.