# What should I be flagging this question as?

Tags: discussion, flags

The question: *[Whats the best method of matching and storing results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55882633/whats-the-best-method-of-matching-and-storing-results)*

I'm between `off topic` (since there's not really any programming involved at the OP's stage), `unclear` (since the question doesn't state a specific scenario), and `too broad` (for the same reason as unclear).

Off topic doesn't seem to have much though, so it's probably between the latter two.

Opinions and reasons please!

Comment: Why not primarily opinion based? It seems to fit a lot better

Comment: I felt like there probably would be a best way for an OP specific scenario... You're probably right though.

Comment: Maybe. But then we need to have that OP specific scenario laid out. Until it is, this is just asking us for a popularity contest between different solutions. If there are constraints that limit what the answers can be, the question is POB until these reasons are established (in my opinion at least)

Comment: @gnat I don't think that is at all related, never did I mention a no comment close reason or even imply it.

Comment: I think [second top answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601) over there fully applies to the question you asked about

Comment: Ok, so you don't think the flag should be "primarily opinion based`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such a situation, there likely is a 'best' scenario, that is the most helpful to the OP. However, the OP gave us a total of 4 lines for us to know that context and make that distinction. And the context, in these four lines, is... Well, not explained at all.

Therefore, because we can't see the context, to close as POB makes the most sense. Now that that's being said adding the context wouldn't necessarily make that question a good one. I can see it shifting from POB to too broad if the OP adds the context, but still basically simply asks 'what do now?'.