# Unreasonable question closures are my biggest annoyance with Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I was a long time contributor but rarely bother any more. One of the reasons is that when people read a question and

- ...don't understand it after first read through
- ...don't believe the OP has made an attempt at solving it him-/herself
- ...thinks it could *potentially* be homework
- ...*<insert other reason for feeling frustrated over the question>*

they vote to close it with some random silly close-reason. (Close reasons have varied over time but they are imo often misused.)

It's like people are thinking "This question looks like something I would be able to answer if I had the energy to actually try to understand the question, but it's too much lift for me in its current form." and then they vote to close out of frustration, preventing people with "more energy" to take a stab at it.

I generally don't get behind "we need to do X to make newbies feel more welcome" but not closing questions that *can* be answered (even though they are not written in the best possible way) is a change I'd really like to see.

Comment: FWIW [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61239755/276052) was the question that prompted my rant, but I could probably collect 100 questions over the past week.

Comment: What you linked there **isn't even a question**. It doesn't meet Stack Overflow guidelines in its current form, and was rightly closed. If you want to expend energy trying to salvage that question, then you are encouraged to do so by **editing**. But we do need to get questions closed early in order to prevent answers getting submitted that may be obsoleted by clarifying edits to the question. Closing means "this question needs editing/improvement to comply with our quality standards".

Comment: @CodyGray, could you clarify? I think the question was super clear. OP was asking how to parse that sample string into a list of characters sorted according to the number in front of it.

Comment: What do you want me to clarify? The "question" you linked isn't one. It doesn't ask a question. It is, at best, a requirements dump. You're right that I could probably understand what the person wants with a lot of effort. I spend a lot of time in my day job reading minds. It doesn't always end well. If you want to try your hand at mind-reading, then you are always welcome to do so. You have full editing privileges, so you won't face any roadblocks. But requirements dumps or unclear questions shouldn't command the attention of our answerers. We aren't lacking for questions that need attention.

Comment: I commented here instead of answering because I thought this is a duplicate and was planning to close it. I can't find the dupe I was thinking of here on MSO, but [it has been discussed on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/how-soon-should-i-vote-to-close), [several times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92636/why-are-questions-closed-immediately).

Comment: *but it's too much lift for me in its current form* --> this is why there is a close reason saying *needs to be more focused*

Comment: Apart from being lazy/a bit rude, what's wrong with a requirement dump? I know it sounds silly, but I'm serious. Personally I don't mind a requirements dump if it's a fun challenge.

Comment: Because it is not useful to **anyone else**. We are not here to help just one person with a requirements list. We are here to help people with a clear problem description and answers that *other people with similar problems* can apply to their code.

Comment: My biggest annoyance is voting pattern change suggestions from users who have issued 13 times more upvotes than downvotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a "no comment" close reason for these?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261858/reviewing-some-awful-questions-is-just-a-waste-of-time-can-we-have-a-no-commen)

Comment: "*I don't mind a requirements dump if it's a fun challenge.*" then it sounds you want to visit a coding challenge sites. That's what they are - they give you a task and you solve it. Stack Overflow, however, is not a coding challenge site.

Comment: @VLAZ, that's basically what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I seems to me to be more useful than most of the debugging Questions that don't get closed. How is parsing and sorting in one go not useful?

Comment: I wish this question would give at least a couple of examples (the more the better) in order to give some statistical evidence to the claims. We could still discuss the real occurrence rate of unjustly closed questions, but it would be nice to have at least some examples to convince the general public that the phenomenon exists.

Comment: @Trilarion, yeah, that's on me, sorry. I agree that this discussion had been much more interesting if it hadn't narrowed down on that 1 question I linked to in the first comment. Maybe I'll get around to collect more data and open up a better discussion (and try to avoid expressing it as a "rant".)

Comment: My advice would be that you list some examples that you think are clear examples, say 10 closed questions that remained closed for some time despite your reopen vote, then argue that even if some of these are disputable maybe not all are and you are prepared to deliver more if needed . Then ask if this constitutes a recent trend and how it maybe could be stopped. Maybe the close vote threshold should be increased again? Instead of ranting explicitly say that this demotivates you to further participate. You may not get different answers but it may make a better question.

Comment: Basically the question should be to estimate the current rate of false positives in the closing process, that is estimating the number of answerable ontopic questions that get closed and not reopened nevertheless.  If we all could vote on every single closed question instead of only three of us how would the result differ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I find it strange that there seem to be a big consensus around closing questions who's answers aren't useful to anyone but OP, yet there's no such close reason. Do you know if there's has been any discussion around adding such close reason?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, the "Needs to be more focused" close reason is for questions that "[...] includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only." and should not be used for questions that are hard to understand / sloppily written.

Comment: @aioobe: that's not a reason to close a question in and of itself. The *site* is about helping more than just the original question asker, and it is from that core use case that the off-topic reasons we have, flow; these give clearer feedback as to *why* a question isn't suitable. We did have, a long, long time ago, the 'too localised' close reason, but that was [rightfully removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154) as it was too vague and open to abuse. The current 'debugging questions require a clear mcve' reason replaced it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, hmm.. ok. I don't think your last two comments give a lot of clarity. Your first comment basically says (correct me if I misinterpret) "Questions like these should be closed because they are not useful to anyone else", and then you say "Questions should not be closed for that reason alone". Are you saying that if a question is only relevant to OP, but meets all other criteria, you would not recommend closing the question?

Comment: @aioobe: I'm saying: "Closing questions should be done for one of our specific reasons, not for a blanket 'not useful for anyone but the question asker' catch-all". You state in your question that *they vote to close it with some random silly close-reason*. I'm giving you the underlying motivation for the close reasons we have. They are **not** random.

Answer (score 6):

Putting the only comment that resonates with me as an answer:

> Because it is not useful to anyone else. We are not here to help just one person with a requirements list. We are here to help people with a clear problem description and answers that other people with similar problems can apply to their code. -- [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297).

I think it's unfortunate, but I buy the reasoning.

I like mentoring people and see it as a bonus if my answers are useful to others. For this reason I tend to like answering questions that other people sometimes vote to close.

Somewhat paradoxically, if someone posts a programming question he/she (and only he/she) would like an answer to, and I find it interesting enough to answer, the activity is simply not welcome on Stack Overflow. Such interactions are probably better off elsewhere.

I've found it annoying, because I've always seen such situations as a win-win (for me and for the person asking the question) and that our interactions should be of no bother to anyone else. However, with this sorted out, I can at least put my finger on why I've lost interest in Stack Overflow over the years.

Comment: As I suggested above, please channel your desire to help and mentor into *edits* on the question. This will do many things. First, it will solve the issues with the question, obviating the need for closure. Second, it will stop others from wasting their time reviewing it and votes closing it. Third, it may even teach the asker how to ask better questions in the future. You can edit and then follow up with an answer. Now you're back in the "win-win" territory, with an extra win being added: everyone else who comes across that Q&A in the future.

Comment: It's hard to get a question reopened though. Even if I'm really quick it will have gotten 2-3 downvotes and close to 0 attention after I've improved it, which means I won't even be able to answer the question.

Perhaps questions should be given a second chance (automatically reopened) if a 10k+ users has made a non-trivial change to it.

Comment: Well it's reopened now and still waiting for an answer that will make it potentially useful for future visitors who are looking for a way to extract characters from a string following integers while adhering to the order of the integers

Comment: Yeah. This particular question was reopened, as usually happens when a question gets attention on meta. My post here was not specifically about this question though.

Comment: My point is that the question is still failing to be useful.

Comment: Yep. And my point is that I don't care much about this particular question.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I read in a comment that it prompted the entire rant but I guess I misunderstood then. Carry on.

Comment: You win, question asker wins, all people trying to search the site loose, when they search for some generic regexp explanation and can't find it buried under tons of requests for expression solving some particular problem.

Comment: As a thought @aioobe - if a question is not useful to others but you still would like to answer it, you can do so in a Gist or external pasteboard. The OP will get their answer despite it being thought of as off-topic, you get your challenge, the community gets to keep the question closed. Is that win-win, or still not ideal?

Comment: @halfer Yep. I'd have to put the link as a comment, which is sad, but that's basically what I do today. (Thanks for the edit on the post btw. )

Comment: @TadeuszKopec, I don't know man... if you're searching for some generic regexp explanation I think you're probably screwed anyway.