# What is the correct use of the [details] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I just used the [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/details) tag for a question that talks about the new HTML5 `<details>` element.

Looking at the tag, I see that a lot of questions are using it in the way I did, referring to the HTML element, but others are using it just to pad their tag lists.  For example, I see no reason for [any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476437/paypal-transaction-types-for-which-no-details-can-be-retrieved-via-api) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521073/printing-report-footer-at-the-end-of-last-pagedetail-section-in-crystal-report) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595682/azure-failed-request-error-details) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131623/facebook-share-url-show-preview-details-only-on-second-time-click) to have the tag because the fact that the questioner is looking for "details" about something has no technical relation to the question.

I would like to suggest the removal of this tag, with replacement by more-specialized tags like [html-details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-details), or similar.  Note that my cursory examination found no questions that deserve some other kind of "details" tag - most of them should just have the tag removed.

**Note:** that this is similar to the discussion around [header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/header) and [footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/footer)

[here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253560/re-tag-header)

Comment: [details] sounds like a meta-tag on its own. [html-details] sounds proper

Comment: Is that html tag really so fundamental adding such an SO tag is justified? Or wouldn't it be better to just burninate the details?

Comment: @Deduplicator Sure. We're asking people to include more details in their questions, and now we want to burninate all the details! Sheesh! ;)

Comment: LIke a, p and head tags before, there's little use for html elements tags.