# The Devil is in the [details]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

For some reason there is  a [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/details) tag which is being applied to everything from the HTML `<details>` element to getting details about a file.

- 148 questions
- No excerpt
- No wiki

"Details" is a very broad term that refers to no specific software or methodology, and is being combined with virtually every other tag on the site. No one is an expert in "details". All of the questions I looked at that have the tag could easily survive without it.

According to [Does this tag even need to be burninated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous? **No**
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? **No**
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? **No**
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? **No**

Comment: It has no wiki? No one has filled in the [details]

Comment: Hey! A burnination request that I agree with! You should earn a hat for this. Maybe a nice pair of spectacles...

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265852/what-is-the-correct-use-of-the-details-tag

Comment: There is also the equally bad [tag:detail] tag that should be burninated, too.

Comment: @CodyGray maybe feature it if you agree with it?