# Is there no limit to edits you can make in a day? (rep farming)

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits, users

I was going through my daily suggested edits when the same user kept popping up. Around 14 times in a row.

Most of the edits they made where removing "Thank you" and removing the tag "run". Now as far as I know "run" is relevant to pretty much everything on SO. As you run code, scripts, programs etc. So I see no problem with using the tag (it got a lot of followers but still nothing wrong with it). And removing "thank you" to me is a minor edit.

The user has clearly just searched all the questions with the tag "run" and started removing them without looking at the question. As these are being accepted (I have no idea why) the user has gained a ton of rep from this. Surely there should be some sort of limit of edits per day for users under 2k rep?

I felt the need to create a question to better understand if this is something we allow, the user will gain more rep and be able to have more responsibility even tho they are clearly "rep farming". If users are allowed to do this will this not cause problems a bit later when they gain more privileges?

Overall my question is: Is there anything we should be doing to stop this? Or is this something that is allowed and I'm being stupid not knowing it.

[You can find the user here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1193596/amicable?tab=reputation)

Comment: At least you've helped us uncover robo-reviewers.

Comment: @OGHaza That user has more then 40 edits in an hour =/

Comment: @ChrisF :O say whatt!!!!

Comment: if you check the edits the user was suggesting the majority should have been rejected as "too minor", yet they were accepted.

Comment: Wow, deleted my comment, thats a lot of edits!

Comment: The run tag deletions relate to this question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252760/burninate-the-run-tag

Comment: @OGHaza 94 edits.

Comment: @StuperUser I see, thanks for the link! surely if this was a official thing then they would just remove the tag... Not have this person remove all the run tags after seeing a user post. Who gets to decide if they tag stays or goes? Around 10 people that are in that post? Seems very odd to me. Either way I don't think this user should be allowed to do this.

Comment: @StuperUser - be that as it may. If you're editing a post for any reason you should improve the **whole** post.

Comment: @Ruddy the removal of tags is a community thing. The user did nothing wrong in trying to remove the tag. The issue is that the reviewers should have rejected the edits.

Comment: @ChrisF I understand that but you said "community thing" from the post there around 10 users commenting and 71 upvotes? That's not that much to justify it is it? (not really been around meta to know these things). Also so will happen to the user now?

Comment: @Ruddy - 71 upvotes is a good indication that it's a good idea. As to what will happen to the user - there's not a lot we can do. You can only get a max of 1,000 rep from suggested edits so he'll probably stop soon.

Comment: *Now as far as I know "run" is relevant to pretty much everything on SO. As you run code, scripts, programs etc. So I see no problem with using the tag* Umm... that's exactly the problem with the tag. How is a tag that could be on every single question at all useful? Why would someone search for it or follow it? You might as well throw a [programming] tag on every question while you're at it, too. That said, tag burnination should be done by high-rep users instead of flooding the review queue with minor edits.

Comment: Just asked him about this, he said he's helping. I've edited five posts too (I'm very new to editing), but I've lost my editing privileges for 7 days because they were rejected (and they should have been!). I agree getting reputation for this is a silly thing and provokes farming..

Comment: I have actually been correcting spelling, grammar, formatting and removing other moot tags where applicable. I wasn't doing it for the reputation points though, I will find a suitable unanswered question and place a 400 point bounty on it.

Comment: @Amicable, doesn't seem to be the case in [your latest edit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9331088/464709)...

Comment: I did say where applicable. @FrédéricHamidi How would you improve that post further?

In a few of the other most recent I've removed signatures and thanks, as they where all the changes that needed to be made. If you go through the rest you'll find ones that required more major changes.

Comment: @Amicable, well, `I think its an Paramter for explorer.exe? But which..? Any idea?` arguably needs work too.

Comment: The retagging may have been pre-emptive, not sure any decision was made yet whether to keep the tag or not

Comment: I think, generally, one can always assume good faith. That has not happened here. The base assumption was that the person is "farming" or "stealing" the rep somehow -- up to no good. That's not a very positive attitude.

Comment: Seriously what is the issue? He's removing a tag...so he's performing a service what is the big issue, he's taking time out of his day to try and help the community. Why does it matter if he earns a little rep for doing it, are people so rep obsessed that they would rather deny an edit for being too minor then help encourage editors. Whenever I remove [tag:asp-classic] from [tag:asp.net] it really annoys me when I see one holy than thou decide it's "too minor", when is removing an incorrect tag ever to minor? If they are doing it because they don't like the `+2` I'll get that is even worse!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That is a flawed argument, so no edit is better then some is that what you are saying? Maybe the editor isn't confident with English grammar and doesn't want to look an idiot, maybe they are just doing the little bit they can do, what is your point? Hey in future Amicable if you're not going to completely rewrite a question don't bother. Great attitude that is.

Comment: @Lankymart, this community (read: the majority of us) believes edits should be as substantial as possible and has made that clear in several posts. Also, if the editor isn't confident with English grammar, why is s/he editing in the first place?

Comment: Didn't there used to be low level privilege that bypassed the review queue and rep gain for retag only edits?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi And this is something I'm very vocal about when is a tag edit ever going to be substantial? Someone could write a perfectly written question good grammar etc and tag it wrong, does that mean we just leave it because there is nothing else to improve? Like I've said the argument is flawed, especially so when the main drive is a complaint about rep farming.

Comment: @Lankymart, a tag edit is substantial if it is the only thing wrong with a post, simple as that. In fréd's example there were very clearly other mistakes to correct. Absolutely not editing can be a better option to editing sometimes, and there are MANY examples of that in the queue.

Comment: @Lankymart, what OGHaza said. I honestly don't care about the "rep farming" part of the issue (that's a matter of whether or not to remove the +2 bonus and is being discussed elsewhere), however I do care about not letting editors believe they're `correcting spelling, grammar, formatting and removing other moot tags where applicable` when it's not actually the case.

Comment: @Amicable: yes there was, it used to only require 500 reputation. It was removed a few months ago IIRC.

Comment: @OGHaza So are you saying the size of the review queue is the issue or the quality of the edits?

Comment: @Lankymart No, I mean that if you sit in the queue, you are bound to come across a few edits that clearly should not have been suggested. I was responding to your `"That is a flawed argument, so no edit is better then some is that what you are saying?"`, to which my answer was yes.

Comment: I'm someone who has approved some of those reviews (I can't approve anymore for 13 hours you'll be glad to know :-)). I thought it was doing a useful service and I don't really care about his rep (I see plenty of answers to dupe questions being upvoted everyday which seems a much more "undeserved" rep boost to me). I'll follow the result of this thread with interest though to see what the correct answer is.

Comment: @OGHaza That comes down to ability of the editor not the whether or not edits should be suggested. Personally speaking as someone who enjoys editing, I find it frustrating when someone rejects a suggested edit when I've removed irrelevant tags and correct syntax highlighting (which happens a lot in [tag:asp-classic] because `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` markdown is not attached by default.

Comment: There's already a max reputation gain of 200 per day for anyone doing anything.

Comment: @SW4: No decision has been made? I don't think I've ever seen a burnination request get 75 upvotes and 0 downvotes before. If that's not a suitable consensus for removing a tag I don't know what is.

Comment: @Wooble - you're right, there weren't that many when I posted, this thread has given it extra coverage!

Comment: There is a reputation limit for overall edits and that's 1000 rep so the user will keep gaining rep until he's edited about 500 posts.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I do not see a problem here. As far as I understood the user is removing overused tag `run` (what is the point of this tag if it can be used for everything?) which is nice. He also removes junk like `thank you` which is also nice. So the guy is spending his own time trying to improve the site in the way he can.

Yes this is not the best way, but hey, he is doing this for free. He is not spamming, posting random questions and answers. Is he getting "ton of rep"? He can not gain more than 2k during all his 'farming' (as far as I remember after 2k you can not gain rep from edits). There are better ways of gaining ton of rep than just editing posts.

Sorry, but I definitely do not see a problem with what he is doing.

Comment: I completely agree Salvador, not sure why people feel the need to downvote. +1

Comment: And the user just gave away 400 rep for a bounty.  So obviously not too attached to the rep.  It really is a case by case basis to see what the user's intent is.

Comment: @Lankymart people feel need to downvote because my answer disagrees with their opinion.

Comment: @Lankymart Because we are on meta, and meta voting is driven by opinion.  There is not always anything wrong with a -30 answer, it just means people disagree with you.

Comment: The whole rep farming thing on edits is a just pointless unless the edits are making the question worse what is the big deal. If people are so bothered just go edit some yourself instead of leaving them in an incorrect state.

Comment: @demongolem I realise that just think it's a flawed opinion and one the community could do without. If you're driven by rep you're here for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @SalvadorDali `people feel need to downvote because my answer disagrees with their opinion` - isnt that the point of the down vote button here? But yeah I see where your coming from, its nice to see other peoples opinions on this matter. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: FWIW, 200 rep in a couple of hours **is** tons relative to anything I've ever managed. He also generated 300-500 reviews in that time, but the reviewers are probably glad of that more than anything.. no downvote from me anyhow

Comment: @Ruddy may be you did not get it, but I just stated the reason why people downvoted. Lankymart asked a question, I answered.

Comment: 200 rep, well hey he's spent his time editing those questions so good on him. If it's generating too many reviews then that's another issue.

Comment: @Lankymart `he's spent his time editing those questions` - 94 edits in less then an hour. I would say that's pretty damn fast, I doubt much attention was being paid other then looking for the tag `run` and "thank you" at the end. Remember I was reviewing them as they kept popping up. More just kept coming.

Comment: @Ruddy That's possibly the only sound argument in this whole discussion, if he is making that many edits is such a short period of time what are the quality of edits, that I can agree with.

Comment: Removing a tag when you don't have tag edit privileges isn't the correct way of doing it. It'll bump up the questions in the list because there was an edit.

Comment: It's 1k, not 2k.

Comment: Why is it that "Thank You" is considered junk? I've noticed that people like to remove it from my questions as well.

Comment: @DavidB it is written in SO FAQ that you do not need to include it, because it conveys no meaning.

Answer (score 21):

> **Who should do the burnination after it is approved?**
>
> Burnination can be done by anyone in the community. The goal of a
>   burnination request is to:
>
> - gather feedback, and
> - organise a burning party of willing members to go
>     out and take care of the tags

[How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work)

Revisions to the community FAQ on the subject need to be considered if the community feels certain users should not participate.

---

The FAQ has now been revised.

> **Who should do the burnination after it is approved?**
>
> Burnination can be done by anyone in the community, regardless of
>   reputation.
>
> Keep in mind that if you have below 2000 reputation, it's especially
>   important to fix all other issues with a post, as there's some work
>   involved in approving your edit, and it may get rejected if it doesn't
>   fix all issues.

Comment: No one asked you to give up the rep, I created this question not to say your wrong. It was to find out why you was doing it, I had no idea any of this was going on. It makes a lot more sense now seeing a lot of this, you must have wanted the rep still as you stopped dead on 200 yesterday and today. You didn't need to give the rep away.

Comment: I think you took this the wrong way @Amicable, Ruddy was the one in error here, you were doing the right thing.

Comment: @Hogan Explain how I was "in error here"?

Comment: @Ruddy - Error is the wrong word... but Amicable is clearly taking this question the wrong way, so if this question is causing him to feel his actions were wrong -- then from that point of view... ect.  I think you know what I mean.  I want Amicable to understand that he did not do something wrong.

Comment: This meta question should be read as "hmm what's going on here?" with the conclusion "I see! carry on good sir"

Comment: I approved your burninate run tag edits, but I got a review ban because of approving such minor edits (You can check my post about the review ban here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253293/review-ban-because-of-approving-burninate-tag-edits/253295?noredirect=1#253295)

Comment: Thanks for putting the effort in to improve those posts.  Personally I think SO needs a lot more people like you, and you are welcome to any rep. gained from doing such house keeping.  In fact, I found the 'accusation' of rep. farming here to be a little offensive.  I myself have been accused of 'rep farming' on edits.  Fortunately in my case, I was already beyond 2K rep. (at which point the '+2 rep. for edit' disappears), so I could simply ROTFL at the suggestion. ;)

Answer (score 12):

I have reviewed some edits of the user. For the first three I rejected as "minor changes" but he kept submitting the edits using the edit summary `burminate the [run] tag`. I looked at meta and there is a [post, on community bulletin at the time, recommending to delete this tag.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252760/burninate-the-run-tag) I then proceeded to accept his reviews and then start ***removing the tag myself as well as editing the tag wiki***.

By doing this work that user :

- Is helping the moderators
- Is doing work that is repetitive and may bore others
- Successfully brought my attention as well as the attention of the other high rep users to contribute to ***implement*** the recommendation.
- Let to the tag being effectively be *"burminated"* in few hours
- Put in the queue some questions which I believed should be closed.
- Let to a valid point being raised (your own question)

I don't see it as a steal. If he got 200 rep from that today, he deserves it.

Comment: The user is adding *more* work to the community by suggesting these edits than he is by just doing nothing.  All of the reviews generated from these suggestions, all of the reviewer time consumed evaluating and approving them, the fact that he's pretty much *only* removing the tag and not making substantial edits that fix everything wrong with the post, the draw of reviewer attention away from other suggestions, having the posts locked while the edits are pending (on both all of his edited posts, and all of the questions that will take longer to be reviewed).  It's a *significant* net harm.

Comment: @Servy It is debatable. *The sole fact to request a burminate generate work* . If a user ***in a good will*** end up making things worse, it is the system fault. In this case it is better to implement feature which let mods do this burmination in one click of a button. Or not burminate tags.

Comment: I don't see it as debatable.  A fairly objective analysis of the situation makes it pretty clear that these edits are adding more work for everyone else, not less.  What should have happened is that his edits should have been rejected, not accepted, thus banning him from suggesting edits for a while after he had only just started.  We don't *want* a mod to just go and remove the tag globally.  They *do* have that feature.  The problem is that the tag clean up allows the edits to happen slowly, over time, not clogging the question list, and *to fix other problems with the posts*.

Comment: By having the user just go through and blindly remove the tag, as fast as possible, without even looking at anything else, it *doesn't* avoid flooding the front page, it doesn't help fix other issues with the posts in question, it doesn't allow for close-worthy questions to have attention drawn to them, etc.  Yes, a mod just one-click removing the tag is *much* better than what he did, but *that's because he was doing something he shouldn't have been*.  Proper tag removal is far superior to automatic removal.

Comment: By the way, it's "burnination", not "burmination"

Comment: You seems to be talking about the regular everyday edit of bad posts. Then something needs to be done about the [burninate info]( http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) and [posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work) which insist on removal of the tag only because it is meaningless.

Comment: @UmNyobe Most of that is about describing how to decide if a tag should be removed, not how one goes about actually doing the edits, however your second link *does* say: "Often a burninate request comes with needing to close or retag quite a few questions, not to mention that questions using inappropriate tags typically could do with some other improvements as well. There is an automated process available developers and maybe Community Managers, [...] it would likely be preferred to handle the questions manually so we don't lose the additional attention required on a per-question basis."

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to how many edits you can do in a day, but there is a daily reputation gain limit of 200. You can't farm reputation after 100 approved suggested edits in 24 hours.

There's also an absolute maximum limit of 1,000 reputation you can earn from suggested edits. Once you pass that mark, you'll no longer receive reputation for editing.