# How suspension days are calculated on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, consecutive-days, review-suspension

Before 3-4 weeks for some wrong review I was banned for 2 days and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253293/review-ban-because-of-approving-burninate-tag-edits) in some posts I can see that user can be banned up to 7 days also.

Can someone please tell me how banned days are calculated?

Also, up to what number of days user can be banned? Can user be banned permanently from reviewing also?

In other words, how does banned days decided for what type of wrong reviews?

Comment: We use the formula of 24 hours == 1 day. Being serious though - what do you mean - what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @Oded, I've updated question. :)

Comment: So, you would like to know what determines the **length** of a specific review ban?

Comment: Yes, Exactly that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The number of days of a review ban depends entirely on how many bans you already received in the current review window.

Quoting from [The time of automatic review bans should be increased with every new ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174118/the-time-of-automatic-review-bans-should-be-increased-with-every-new-ban/190562#190562):

> - each review ban counts (even manual ones made by moderators).
> - a 30 day window is used
> - 1st ban within the window -> duration: 2 days
> - 2nd ban within the window -> duration: 7 days
> - 3rd ban within the window -> duration: 30 days

You got a 2-day ban now; if you trigger another ban within the next 30 days, it'll be for 7 days. If you trigger a *third* ban, you'll lose the ability to review for a whole month.

Moderators can ban manually, for any number of days up to 30. There currently is no longer ban option, so no perma-ban from reviewing either.

Comment: In addition to this, moderators can manually impose bans of arbitrary periods up to 30 days (and I wish we could go longer than that sometimes). In general, the assessment I make is that if I see you approving one or more bad edits, and it's your first ban, I ban you for 7 days. If you approve clear spam or vandalism, I will often ban you for a full month, even on a first offense, because that kind of activity is damaging to the site. If I have evidence you have been cheating the audits, I will up your ban to 14 or 30 days even for a first offense.

Comment: @BradLarson: right, I knew there was a manual option, not that the number of days was free-form.

Comment: Brad for .... darn, we already elected him!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Imho you are currently inciting Brad Larson to further mis-use his moderator power. You can be sure: I will vote against both of you, if I see you on an election.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: A little touchy, are we? How is a little humour enticing anyone for mis-use of powers? There are better channels to address moderator power abuse, overreacting to a small joke is not it.

Comment: @BradLarson There is an automatic mechanism for handling failed audits, moderator action is only needed in cases not handled (or can't be handled) automatically. Your examples are clearly about manual actions in mostly automatically handled cases, and thus it is imho a misuse of the moderator power.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: Blatant spam edit approvals are *serious*. If people are not paying attention to the point of approving such edits in the queue, they certainly deserve to be jolted awake enough not to do that again. Temporary review bans are not exactly onerous; no one will lose their livelyhood when they cannot review suggested edits for a little while.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There is an automatic system against the not enough careful reviews since long months, and every moderator know that. There is no need for manual banning actions, especially to punish people on singletime decisions of single persons.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: Yes, and that system *doesn't always work*. Moderators have been given the ability to manually suspect *exactly because of that*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The system always works, it is an automatic thing. At least it is not perfect. For example, it rewards hostility against good-standing beginners. But: 2 of Brad Larson's 3 examples were cases, which are handled by the automatic system already. Only the third case (if there is an evidence of playing the audit system), which requires human intervention. I see this as a clear evidence, that Brad Larson continously misuses his power.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: Then *take that up with the community team*. I happen to disagree, but attacking me for some humour in the comments is not going to achieve anything.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: In my experience, however, the suggested edits review system has systematically failed at keeping out spam, even with audits and edit bans based on rejections. And if a moderator stopped someone from reviewing a few reviews earlier than the automatic system, **how is that abuse**?

Comment: @PeterHorvath: besides, I strongly suspect you are conflating the *edit* ban with the *review* ban. Users that detect audits are still perfectly capable of not paying enough attention to detect outright spam content being added. Those users will *continue to review* without a ban, and are just as damaging to Stack Overflow as the accounts injecting the spam. They are *not* being banned from reviewing by the system.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There is a wellknown phenomena of online communities, that a central core "group" slowly takes over the most "power" in the system, and starts to exterminate the "newbies". You can read thousands and thousands about this on the net. I suggest not to try incite somebody to use his power, normally every punishment based on single-person decisions should be rare, and not common.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: No, you are overreacting. Noone is 'enciting' here. I made a joke about electing someone and I cannot because he is already a moderator. Don't give me power-base abuse crap here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not against a review audit system, I am against punishments based on single-person, single-time decisions, especially if they have automatic alternative.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: You fundamentally misunderstand what moderators are for then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, I only believe things which you seemingly don't.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: You are welcome to make better suggestions on how to improve the suggested edits system instead. Currently, we have audits, automatic bans, and manual bans. If moderators are not supposed to use the manual bans, then *come up with a better alternative*. Bring statistics and explicit examples on how the current system doesn't work and yours would.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: But wielding the 'power abuse'! cry makes me think of you as [Dennis The Constitutional Peasant from Monty Python's Holy Grail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOOTKA0aGI0). I cannot take you serious.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The good news is, that this better alternative is already developed & deployed on SE, and this is the automatic review system, which handles most cases of failed review audits. In these cases, there is no need for additional manual moderator action, because a punishment based on a single-person, single-time decision is much worser as an automatic one. The bad news is, that seemingly not all moderators understand this on the spot.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I hope, there will be some possibility to link this dialog below your moderator applications in the future.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: I'm really fine with that. If ever I wanted to be a moderator, let it be known I stand by my convictions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If you don't apply, you won't misuse moderator power. If you apply, you will need to explain this dialog, especially this "constitutional peasant"-thing in the context of the power misusage.