# Why am I suspended from the review queues?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, review-suspension

I came to META to ask about my suspension and already the 2nd question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420322/what-was-wrong-with-this-suggested-edit) is about the exact same topic and obviously the same moderator who after the review got approved rejected it and rolled it back.
I feel like the suspension is in error.

I got three links as explanation on why I am suspended:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32586307 I can't see why I acted wrong on approving this suggested edit? It didn't change the body of the question, just improved its format and I didn't see a need to rewrite the question to improve the quality (like the moderator then did)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32601632 Here I don't know at all why it is listed as reason for my suspension.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32572406 it is marked as "plagiarism". I thought the added information is useful to the given tag.

Comment: In the first, `sql` isn't code, so it shouldn't be in code markdown. It also removes the `<br />` markup, but doesn't replace it with appropriate markdown to retain the line breaks. This [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32601632) was approved, it isn't contributing to the suspension. *"it is marked as "plagiarism". I thought the added information is useful to the given tag"* Plagiarism is **never** welcome here. For tag edits, there is an **explicit** reject reason for copied content.

Comment: To find that plagiarised content wasn't difficult either; a Google of "builds on the foundation established by .NET 6" (with the quotes) took me straight to the [original content](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-7-preview-1/)· For tag edits, reviewers need to spend more than 5 seconds on deciding if it "looks ok". Checking for plagiarism is actually one of the most important steps for such edits, as many suggestions are outright plagiarism.

Comment: When reviewing tag wikis and excerpts, it is required that you verify text being added is not plagiarized. Please see "[Stopping tag wiki plagiarism, Part II: Taking Action](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318288/3773011)", which states that for tag wikis and excerpts, "Approving blatant plagiarism is a one-way ticket to a review ban."

Comment: First of all, thanks for the detailed explanation. I should have known better. Regarding to the tag review, it just recently got the right to do that, I will be more careful in the future. One little question: if it doesn't lead to the suspension and also got approved. Why is it in the list then?

Comment: @Makyen I just read some articles about how long user got banned and how the duration is calculated. Based on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253870/15521392) I don't understand why I am banned for 2 whole months (till 13.11.2022). What am I missing ?

Comment: Re *"I didn't see a need to rewrite the question"*: It wasn't rewritten. In the default diff view (*"Inline"*) it often ***looks*** like that when there are ***formatting changes***. Use the *"Side-by-side Markdown"* view instead.

Comment: “What am I missing?” - Understanding that you have failed audits in the past, and those failed audits, determine and justified a longer suspension than your previous review suspensions.

Comment: It is not about that linked question (in my question). It was linked to the link provided in my comment what I am missing.

Comment: @Rabinzel - How was I supposed to know you were referring to the link a comment instead of the one linked in your question? You just referred to it as a shared link. The table in that shared link doesn’t appear to be valid. Longer review suspensions are used to make sure the user is aware they were actually review suspensioned .

Comment: That's why I linked my comment to a mod directly and see if he can help me with that. I was just curious, nothing else.

Comment: @Rabinzel - If you are just curious then you should welcome additional explanation from community users.  **I also stand by my comment**, what you were missing, was the fact you had enough failed audits in the past to justify the longer suspension.  I also suspect linked table is extremely out of date, since there has been numerous improvements to the review system (and the review suspensions), since that table was created.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32586307: The edit doesn't really improve anything. The first sentence should have been removed ("I've run into a problem with my Python code and I don't know how it can be solved") since it doesn't provide any useful information. Removing the linebreak without introducing some other structure (like paragraphs) makes the formatting worse. It also applies code formatting to non-code text (sql is not code).

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32601632: The edit adds code formatting to non code text. The word Python is not code, Jenkinsfile is not code. The code formatting is not even applied consistently, whl is sometimes changed to code formatting and sometimes not.
The images should have been removed instead of inlined since their transcripts are already part of the question.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32572406: If the text is plagiarized, it doesn't matter whether it's useful or not. The reviewing guidelines state

> Edits that plagiarize content from an external source without proper attribution. Reject as causes harm and write an explanation. (*Always check for plagiarism from common sites such as Wikipedia when a tag wiki/excerpt is created!*). For tag wikis and excerpts, there's a special reason copied content, so you can just go ahead and use it.

under "Common reasons to Reject".

Comment: The 2nd review is particularly serious. SO has a very long and annoying history with the problem of people editing posts to apply code formatting to random nouns, as some sort of random emphasis. So this is one of the most important things to look out for when reviewing. Each time I encounter such a "random code formatting" editor I even research the user to see if this is a recurring thing and if so flag for diamond mod attention. Such editors are often just confused over proper English overall and will stop once they are getting a nudge from a mod.

Comment: As for tag wikis they are the most difficult reviews. Always look for tag usage guidelines or there's often no reason to approve them. Plagiarism is very common as well. For those who aren't sure how tag wikis should look like, don't hesitate to skip all tag wiki reviews.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just didn't know better and felt like I should ask for the reasons. I will be more careful in the future, especially with tag edits.

Comment: Even if it wasn't plagiarism... it's essentially a sales pitch. "Higher developer productivity"? Not exactly what I would want to read in a tag description. Microsoft would love it though.

Comment: @Gimby True that. I think I learned my lesson here and as I already said, in the future I will be more careful about that :)

Comment: I re-edited the two questions just now, to show what properly concise writing looks like with all the noise and redundancy removed.