# We need to sort out the situation with the "selectors" tags

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process, clean-up

Let's take a look at the messy situation with the tags below.

---

## These two tags are correct, specific, popular, unambiguous, and should remain untouched

#### [jquery-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-selectors) ~6.4k questions tagged, no action needed

> Selectors can be used in jQuery to match a set of elements in a document. Most CSS selectors are implemented, as well as a set of custom ones.

#### [css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors) ~3.6k questions tagged, no action needed

> Selectors are patterns that match against elements in a document tree. In a CSS rule, they are used to define styles for elements that match the pattern.

---

## These two tags are ambiguous and need clean up

#### [selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selectors) ~900 questions tagged, retag all then delete tag

> CSS selectors specify which style rules apply to elements in the document.

This says CSS selectors, but it's used by posts about CSS, jQuery, AND even incorrectly by questions involving Objective-C as the tag below is meant for:

#### [selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selector) ~2.1k questions tagged, retag incorrectly tagged questions

> A selector can be a string identifying a method name in the
> Objective-C or Smalltalk programming language or a special kind of
> switch used in computers to connect multiple lines (I/O) to a single
> line. **Please do not use this tag for jQuery/CSS selectors.**

(Emphasis added)
Even though the tag description says it's not for jQuery/CSS, people still use it for that.

---

It's obvious that we need to get rid of the tag [selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selectors) because it has the fewest uses (less than 1000) and it's also used most incorrectly, partially as a duplicate of [css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors), partially as a duplicate of [jquery-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-selectors), and partially as an incorrect use for Objective-C.

I am proposing the following plan. **We are currently on step 1.**

1. We manually go through each question using [selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selector) and change any incorrect uses of this tag to the respective [css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors) or [jquery-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-selectors). There's just over 2000 questions that use this, but the work on this could be aided with the search bar to look for similar tags such as [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), and [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and the `-` to ignore listings with tags such as `-[objective-c]` and `-[ios]` that **do** use the tag correctly.
2. After this is done, we rename the tag [selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selector) to something which is less confusable. I am not familiar with Objective-C or other languages that use this kind of "selector" so I would like to see some suggested new names.
3. Next, we manually go through each tag in [selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selectors) and rename the tag as either the newly renamed version of the tag [selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selector) for the Objective-C kind of selectors, [css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors) for questions about CSS selectors, and [jquery-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-selectors) for questions about jQuery selectors. There's just under 1000 questions that needs to be sorted through.
4. After removing this tag from all questions, we delete the tag [selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selectors). The cleanup is done at this point, but we may need to watch out for stragglers from step 1.

---

In the last couple days I already retagged a handful (okay, several hundred) questions to get a head start on plan steps 1 and 3. A friend recently informed me of [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253293/review-ban-because-of-approving-burninate-tag-edits) which led me to post about it here first. I had no idea this was bad behavior and I apologize for that. Hopefully I didn't get anyone banned for accepting my edits in the review queue. Anyways, that's what led me to post it on here so we can get a more official movement going to straighten out these messy tags and to improve the sorting of questions on SO.

---

What do you think about this? Is it appropriate for me to continue retagging questions? Is retagging a post really considered "too small of an edit"? Should others join me? What should [selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selector) be renamed to? Another question for discussion: There are ~300 questions tagged with [selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selector)—or—[selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selectors) and [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). Should these tags be removed or should the tag [android-selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-selector) be created? It refers to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html).

Comment: Hi, I've done a bit of editing on your question so that the tags are clickable etc. You might want to proof read what I've done and reprocess it as you see fit.

Comment: Consider this seen by me. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: @BoltClock Hello again! Thanks for prompting me to make this post. I'm wondering when or if I should continue to retag questions.

Comment: You can do it in small bursts (~10 posts or so) over time. I actually found myself retagging like several dozen of them myself in a few minutes the other day, but I have no idea how tag edits from a high-rep user/mod affect the front page for other users.

Comment: Please try to fix all issues when editing a post, don't just change the tag, because editing the post sends it to the front page and your edit requires some work to get approved.

Comment: I mean when you're editing other people posts to remove the tag in question. Like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048086/jquery-given-a-selector-find-only-its-visible-elements) - two additional improvements are removing "jQuery:" from the title and removing "Thanks".

Comment: "selector" is both a type and a keyword in ObjC; there's no other word that can just replace it. The only alternative for tagging would be [tag:objective-c-selector].

Comment: @Josh Caswell: We have [a few other objective-c tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c*) so I suppose it wouldn't hurt to have objective-c-selector. Want dibs?

Comment: @BoltClock and Josh Caswell: The tag wiki says it also exists in other languages, such as Smalltalk. Is this an issue? Should we untag it from those posts not using it with Objective-C?

Comment: @Keavon: If we do end up creating such a tag, then yes, in pretty much the same way we have [jquery-selectors] and [css-selectors] (I like to keep them different because there are major differences between the two even though they are similar in principle and syntax).

Comment: What do we do in this case? I retagged this question about Java using [[tag:selector]] but the edit was reverted http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20475290/5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a moderator, a high-rep user, and [someone who is disproportionately active](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-selectors/topusers) in [css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors), I have been aware of this issue for quite some time but I just haven't been certain on what to do about it, given how heavily-used the selector/selectors tags are and how broad and ambiguous they are by nature (even despite what their wikis say). So, I really appreciate you posting this.

Here are some tips to keep in mind for anyone who wants to chip in:

- From the comments:

  > Please try to fix all issues when editing a post, don't just change the tag, because editing the post sends it to the front page and your edit requires some work to get approved. –  Dukeling
  >
  > I mean when you're editing other people posts to remove the tag in question. Like this one - two additional improvements are removing "jQuery:" from the title and removing "Thanks". –  Dukeling

  This is less important for 10k users who are trusted by the system to make tag edits appropriately, but for users without editing privileges, please remember that your edits are subject to review and may get rejected if they are too minor.
- If you're worried about flooding the front page for other users with edits, do it in small bursts. If you're taking the time to address multiple issues as appropriate, this won't be a problem at all.
- Although it is often said that XPath is used to "select" elements, which it does, questions about XPath are simply tagged [xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath), and either [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) or [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) or whatever the document language tag is. "XPath selector" isn't really an official term.
- Apparently selectors are also a thing of their own in Android. I'm not sure if a tag needs to be created for those things, but I would recommend removing the ambiguous tag if it is there, since it's most likely just being used as a "keyword tag".
- If one of the tags in question is being slated for renaming to an Objective-C-specific tag, it might be a good idea to leave it in so I can then rename it and its wiki updated accordingly. This will update all questions with the old tag name in one fell swoop.

Comment: Why don't you rename the tag now?  That would clue a few people in and maybe even prompt lots of users, who will never see this meta question, to help with the retagging cleanup.  When the tag is renamed to `objective-c-selector`, it should be much more obvious to many more users if the question needs to be retagged.

Comment: I am returning to this task and working on manually going through all 2000+ posts, a few dozen per day. What @BrockAdams said sounds like a very good idea and should be done right now. That will make posts automatically retagged by other people. BoltClock, would you mind renaming it?