# Is simply retagging enough to have an edit approved?

Tags: discussion, edits

I'm aware this is a similar question: [OK to approve edits that only add/remove tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251261/ok-to-approve-edits-that-only-add-remove-tags)

Whilst doing some reviewing I came across a number of edits from a particular user that was doing some serial retagging and nothing more:

[See today's reputation for links to retagged questions by the user in question.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1919627/ringstaff?tab=reputation)

While I agree that the retagging is correctly swapping `bootstrap` to `twitter-bootstrap` it doesn't appear to be a very significant edit.

So is this behaviour acceptable if it's the only thing being edited on numerous questions?

Comment: [This topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253084/is-there-no-limit-to-edits-you-can-make-in-a-day-rep-farming/253105?noredirect=1#comment13895_253105) is basically about the same situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The edit should be looked at in its context:

- If the editor leaves a bunch of spelling or formatting mistakes in the question, reject it as "too minor", or improve the question further and mark the edit as helpful.
- If there are no other issues besides the tag, approve the edit.

Comment: Really mark it as helpful if there's obviously more? He just did the easiest part, which can nearly be automated...

Comment: @Deduplicator "He just did the easiest part" that's still doing something helpful in my eyes. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: "reject it as "too minor"," you might want to review this again, as "too minor" isn't available as reject reason.

Comment: @Braiam thanks for the notice, I'll try to do an update soon with the new edit review flow.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if the edit adds a tag to a **unanswered** question that will get the “correct” people to look at the question it is of great value therefore a significant contribution.  An editor not fixing spelling errors etc. is not a good reason to prevent the question getting an answers.

However if it is an **old** question that has already been answered and the change to the tag will not provide much benefit, e.g. just removing a meaningless tag, then I would say the change was too minor and should be rejected.

My rule is:

> Does the edit provide enough value to justified the time of 3 to 5 people
>   reviewing it?

Answer (score 3):

If you feel that the edits are too minor, and aren't making a significant contribution, then reject the edits as "Too Minor".  That's what that reason is there for.

Comment: I went to reject the first couple but they were already approved, at which point I looked at his history, hence the question

Comment: @Tanner Yeah, you're going to find that happening quite a lot, due to the shear number of bad reviewers in the system.  Its one of the reasons I can't stand using the system anymore; it's just too disheartening.  However, if you are going to continue using the system, I'd hope that you'd strive to review appropriately, rather than reviewing inappropriately just because "everyone else is doing it".