# The King of "hey guys" is reverting my edits

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, signatures

[We agreed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) that questions may be edited to remove words that don't contribute to understanding the problem.

So, I've been removing extraneous words from chatty questions, and a good [search term to start with is "hey guys"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22hey%20guys%22%20is%3aquestion).

One user now has the top 5 questions by votes that includes "hey guys", but he is reverting my edit.  Is there anything that can be done?

[image]

Comment: Not this again... Only on the internet do people get upset over the most stupid and trivial of things.

Comment: Just a tip, don't go on edit sprees especially when it looks like all your edits are targeting a single user. Plus you are bumping old questions that might not actually need attention to remove "Hey Guys". There are far more important things that need to be improved.

Comment: I only checked one edit of yours so far on his post but please make sure you are doing more to make the post better than just taking that out. The one I looked at, I don't know why it was approved. Apart from taking that out, you reworded some of it but it seemed to read fine to me before the edit

Comment: I would suggest not actively looking for things to edit, and instead editing them as you find them organically, while looking for questions to answer.

Comment: codeMagic: My reading of [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) is that *any* edit that reduces the number of words can potentially help users get to the question faster and improves understanding.

Comment: @MichaelCurrie that doesn't mean you shouldn't also fix other obvious issues at the same time...

Comment: @KevinB: I do.  :)

Comment: I would subscribe more to the idea in [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts#comment420305_3021). Though, editing it out is fine **as long as you are making other valuable edits**

Comment: @MichaelCurrie Problem is that you are editing old stuff that doesn't necessarily need to be edited. Don't go searching for these trivial edits, and flood the review queue with them.  If you run across something that needs to be improved, then edit it. Actively searching for things to edit, bumps them unnecessarily.

Comment: @codeMagic: why can't edits be made in very small increments?  For instance, one person comes in and fixes some spelling, another comes in and fixes some grammar, another person removes an extraneous passage or two.  As long as the direction is for improvement, why have a minimum threshold?

Comment: @MichaelCurrie That's usually fine, but, when you're doing it on a large scale by running a search query "Hey guys,", that's where the problem begins. The review queue becomes flooded with these edits that need further attention.

Comment: I see your point about the review queue being a scarce resource though.  I didn't think about that.  Perhaps this needs to wait until I have 2000 rep.

Comment: Partially due to what bluefeet has already mentioned in comments. Instead of asking "why not make a bunch a small edits", I would ask why not make the edit the best you can? But bluefeet's advice of not searching for them is an even better point/suggestions

Comment: @MichaelCurrie Even when you get 2k rep, these are considered trivial edits that don't necessarily need to be made.

Comment: And think about that guy who's posts your editing... he has a red box on his header with a really big number, that's gotta be at least a little bit annoying. I wouldn't be very excited to login one day and see 20 new notifications in my inbox overnight when i'm only used to seeing 1 or 2, just to find out it's someone making minor edits.

Comment: Maybe my problem is that I'm thinking of this site as Wikipedia, where small edits are welcome even on obscure pages, since they improve the overall quality of the site.

I don't just remove "hey guys", I fix ESL grammar, capitalize "I"s, add code formatting, etc.  This stuff might not be the highest priority but it's what I have time to do.  If I'm not harming anything surely there is room for people working on low-priority stuff?

People shouldn't be "annoyed" when their questions are edited; this should be welcomed as long as they are improvements.

Anyway I'll stop since @bluefeet said so.

Comment: @MichaelCurrie I'm not saying stop, I'm saying use good judgment when editing. Edit sprees are not well received and based on your question and what I saw it _appears_ you were targeting a specific user. No one likes that.  Edits are good when they are appropriate, but actively searching for minimal things like "hey guys" isn't really needed.

Comment: The other problem with editing sprees is that questions are automatically bumped to the top of the front page when edited. No one likes refreshing the front page and finding a bunch of multiple-year-old questions. It reduces the signal-to-noise ratio quite a bit.

Comment: @MIchaelCurrie there's also the fact that, while you're <2K rep, all your edits need approval from multiple users. Thus, if you're making trivial edits, it's a trivial edit that needs reviewing (time) by other people. Once you've >2K, it's not as bad... but the bump to front is still a pretty bad effect

Comment: I exterminated all "hey guys" from the posts with score >= 10. [Find scuh posts again](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22hey%20guys%22%20score%3a10..).

Answer (score 17):

> Is there anything that can be done?

Yes, the solution is to not go on targeted editing sprees.  From the current faq-proposed [How do I make a good edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303220/4320665) answer (emphasis mine):

> ## Don't go on editing sprees
>
> Keep in mind that if you have less than 2,000 rep, all of your edits
> need to be approved in the suggested edit review queue. Don't waste
> reviewers' time by searching for and correcting simple errors en
> masse.
>
> Also, editing a post bumps it to the front page, so don't edit too
> many posts in quick succession.
>
> If you feel the need to search out and correct a simple issue on
> several posts, please be sure to correct other issues while you're at
> it.
>
> **If you feel that there is an issue that affects a lot of posts, first
> discuss it here on Meta**. Then the community can decide if mass editing
> is warranted.

Comment: Good point about the reviewers' queue, thanks.  However, the "hey guys" issue was discussed in a Meta post already, so I thought I had a green light: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @MichaelCurrie I suppose that is close enough, but since these are edits to stuff on this site (SO), a three year ole MSE post is not the most relevant discussion.  The idea is that most of the time when people go on editing sprees, they suggest a lot of incomplete edits.  Or edits to posts that are really good and so the suggestions are very marginal/borderline.

Answer (score 12):

First off, thank you for editing. Editing is crucial to the continued functioning of Stack Overflow, and it's always nice to see folks stepping up to fix problems they encounter.

That said... If you're going to edit in any appreciable quantity, *please* read this blog post **first**: [In Defense of Editing](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/).

The three guidelines there are:

> 1. **If you are going to edit a post, make sure you're substantively improving it.** Avoid making isolated, trivial edits, as they are the source of much friction. For example, don't bother changing "its" to "it's" unless you have several other edits to make in the same post. There has to be a legitimate case that your edit made multiple changes transforming the post from good to great -- or at least substantively improving it.
>
>    (Except when you happen to be editing that rare "perfect except for this one misspelled word" post. This is obviously OK to edit. In my experience, the type of posts that really cry out for editing need a lot of editing to be whipped into shape.)
>
>    To be very specific, I would discourage editing a post solely to remove salutations like "hi" and "thanks". That's just adding an unnecessary edit on top of an unnecessary set of salutations. I completely agree that salutations add little to a question or answer, but if you're going to take the time to go in and remove salutations, fix the whole post while you're at it! If there's nothing else to edit, then don't bother.
> 2. **Be diplomatic in your edit-related comments.** If you are going to make edits, you have to be more diplomatic and friendly than "suck it up, the FAQ says I can do this." Explain that the spirit of SO is collaborative editing, and you're only trying to make substantive improvements (see rule #1). More readable questions and answers leads to better information for all future travellers! Above all, be nice. And as mentioned in the blog entry on edit wars, if there's any resistance -- even unwarranted and unjustifiable resistance -- just let go and move on.
> 3. **Every edit is a judgement call.** Do we encourage editing? Yes! Do we demand that every user accept every edit? No. There's no way I can make a blanket statement like that. Do I trust my wife? Sure. Do I agree with every single thing she's ever done? No. It would be irrational to expect any person on the internet to extend more trust than this to me.

These guidelines are essential to achieving a cooperative relationship with the folks whose posts you are editing *and the larger community*. Read them, take them to heart, and put them in action.

Answer (score -2):

Leaving the issues of:

- Clogging the review queue and
- Annoying a single user with edit notifications

aside, I believe [Salvador Dali's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253084/is-there-no-limit-to-edits-you-can-make-in-a-day-rep-farming) speaks to how my edits are, in fact, appropriate:

> I do not see a problem here. As far as I understood the user is
>   removing overused tag run (what is the point of this tag if it can be
>   used for everything?) which is nice. He also removes junk like thank
>   you which is also nice. So the guy is spending his own time trying to
>   improve the site in the way he can.
>
> Yes this is not the best way, but hey, he is doing this for free. He
>   is not spamming, posting random questions and answers. Is he getting
>   "ton of rep"? He can not gain more than 2k during all his 'farming'
>   (as far as I remember after 2k you can not gain rep from edits). There
>   are better ways of gaining ton of rep than just editing posts.
>
> Sorry, but I definitely do not see a problem with what he is doing.

Nevertheless I've had enough pushback here to see it remains controversial, so I'm still going to stop.