# Burninate the [closing] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Along the same lines as [Burninate the [run] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252760/burninate-the-run-tag), the [closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closing) tag probably doesn't serve any useful purpose.  It's used in a small number of questions about closing applications, closing windows, closing I/O streams, closing handles, closing tags, closing database connections, etc., etc.

The only possible legitimate case I could spot is closing as in "closing a branch in a version control system", e.g., [Can you close a Mercurial branch without updating to it first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122183/can-you-close-a-mercurial-branch-without-updating-to-it-first) - but as that's the only question using the tag in that way, it probably isn't necessary.

Comment: Only 122 questions.  You can remove this tag like you remove any other undesired tag: one question at a time.

Comment: The Close tag was burned. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/close/info

Comment: @ckuhn203: Really?  There's still 156 questions with that tag.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Not exactly burned I suppose, but it's out of use.

Comment: Putting "DO NOT USE THIS TAG ANYMORE" in the Tag Wiki doesn't prevent the tag's re-use.

Comment: @ckuhn203: many of the questions with the close tag appear to predate the discussion you link to - so I think the burning was never completed.  I've made a start on getting it finished. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't really be an expert in closing, and the point of tags is so that experts in an area can find questions about that area. Also, this tag does not say *what* you're closing.

Let it burn.