# User attempting to burninate tag without Meta discussion

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, burninate-system

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1107398/chris) has been attempting to burninate the [execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execute) tag, but I haven't seen any discussion on this matter on Meta Stack Overflow. To do so, the user has been suggesting a number of edits removing the tag, sometimes not fixing other issues in the post.

While doing so, the user has removed the tag from questions which were legitimately tagged with it:

- [Is it possible to execute a string in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4711966)
- [TSQL select into Temp table from dynamic sql](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4712029)

(Note that because only the tags were edited, the first post at the time of review was actually [revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/999200/4), not what is currently shown on the suggested edits page.)

Also, reviewers failed to check that the tag removal was appropriate.

What should be done in these circumstances? It's possible that the user thought that "burninate" meant removing tags from incorrectly-tagged posts, but given the number of edits, I'm not sure.

Comment: He still is doing and gets approval. 46 questions untagged and approved within 19 minutes. Plus 10 more yesterday. Ok, some were legitimate referring to what the tag description says, but not all.

Comment: It was suggested in [the discussion on the run tag][1]. I looked at it and noticed that a lot of them were useless, so I started removing them. Some of them may have been relevant with regards to SQL, which was my mistake. My use of the term burninate was probably wrong, and I should have said that it was irrelevant or something. I just recently started trying to be an active/contributing member so I'm not totally sure how things are run. Sorry if it's caused any problems. 


  [1]: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252760/burninate-the-run-tag

Comment: @Chris: sorry, a search makes it hard to find comments. The only thing is that some of these could use some retagging with replacements for the [tag:execute] tag, and to make sure that it's appropriate to remove the tag from the question. Note that burniniate means to remove the tag from all questions, not just some were mistagged (though that is a factor in burnination).

Comment: @Chris - putting for the effort to help make the site better, content more relevant and reduce the noise is **always a good thing**. Even if there are some false positives, correcting a handful of your well intentioned mistakes is trival. Thanks for trying to help nobody is perfect 100% of the time! Don't get discouraged.

Comment: @Chris One recommendation for users without many privileges is to do it in smaller batches.  It's easy to search for a tag and retag 100 questions all at once, but then you slam the review queues and flood the front page/recently active questions list with minor edits (okay, SO has a lot of volume and can probably handle it, but you can see it still makes people unhappy).  You should have less of an issue if you do changes in smaller groups like 10-20 and wait for several hours.

Comment: @Chris Also, specifically when editing posts, it's helpful to clean up _everything_ in the post that you can spot.  That way people will see you're honestly trying to improve the site and not out for a quick way to earn a bunch of reputation, like many other people often seen spamming edits.  I'd suggest doing this even if you're just retagging.

Comment: @Troyen: I'm not unhappy that there was 100 tags being retagged at one, my gripe was that Chris *seemed* to be editing without any sort of community agreement, a few of the edits appeared to be incorrect and that some of the posts still needed fixing (though Chris did fix some of the posts, which is good).

Comment: I was trying to make a general comment based on the guidelines for the old yearly cleanup meta topics in the past (some of which are deleted now, so I can't reference them).  There's nothing stopping him from making a whole bunch of edits all at once, but that also tends to freak people out (isn't this the fourth topic on mass editing in just the past couple of days?).  I guess in this case, it also would have helped to link to the meta topic in the edit comment so reviewers have a reference for the tag burnination.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. @OneKitten, can you provide any examples of things I didn't edit that should have been (other than one that I noted clearly needed it but I had no idea how to reword it)? I'm not disputing you, I'm just wondering so I can do a better job in the future.

Comment: @Chris: mainly it was your first few edits removing the tag, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4711878). I've taken a look at your latest ones and they seem fine to me.

Comment: @OneKitten: "*and that some of the posts still needed fixing*" - that was my impression too. I've come across a number of such edits, minor changes only but the majority of issues left unfixed. To make it clear: That's not specific to this case. There is a certain amount of edit proposals that manage to get approval, but shouldn't. Clearly the approvers are responsible here.

Comment: Viola - [Burninate / retag / disambiguate the \[execute\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253435)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a related FAQ - [How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work/250934#250934)

- There should always be a Meta post.

  > First off, you should not go about burninating a tag without an upvoted Meta discussion about it, because you should first get community approval to make sure what you're planning to do won't be considered a bad thing by most.
  >
  > Even if you deem yourself experienced enough to judge when tags are and aren't appropriate, you should still post on Meta, as what people agree with carries a fair amount of weight (and you can't be sure most will agree with you), even when something can objectively be determined to not be good for the site (in these cases, moderators and/or SE staff can of course override community agreement, but they shouldn't do so lightly - regular users, even high-reputation ones, don't have this right though).

  There is [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252760/burninate-the-run-tag#comment11356_252760), but comments can't be downvoted in case people disagree, don't have a lot of visibility, and that one is only sitting at +2 now, thus only at most 3 or 4 people indicated that they think it's a good idea - considering all those factors, it's definitely not enough to proceed.
- One should absolutely try to fix all issues with a post when removing a tag from that post.

  > Firstly, a list of questions with potential problems (when someone uses a tag that isn't useful and gets burninated eventually, chances are there are a few other problems in their post as well) is useful. If we simply wipe the tag automatically or without looking at each question, we'd be throwing this list away.
  >
  > Sometimes these questions may need to get closed, or the tag to be burninated should be replaced by another tag, not simply removed. While simply fixing other issues while editing posts isn't synonymous to doing either of these, if you're in the habit of giving this added attention to each post, you should notice these issues and deal with them appropriately.
  >
  > Perhaps more importantly, if you edit an old question, it gets sent to the front page. As to prevent posts from constantly being on the front page due to repeated edits fixing minor issues, either accidentally, or on purpose, we should always try to fix all issues with an (older) post when editing it.
  >
  > Additionally, if you have below 2000 reputation, it's especially important to fix all other issues with a post, as there's some work involved in actually getting your edit approved, and it may get rejected if it doesn't fix all issues.
- That tag doesn't seem useful though.

  Execute what exactly? A program? What type of program? A query? A procedure? A function? A script? What type of script? Something else?

  Way too broad.

  I realize the tag wiki talks about executing a stored procedure, but [it definitely isn't just used for that](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexecute%5D+-%5B*sql*%5D+is%3Aquestion).

  Although perhaps we should retag that tag to [sql-execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-execute) and others (rather than just straight-out removing it). Would those be useful? I'm not sure.

### What should be done in response to this?

Post a Meta discussion about it, or just link to this one.

If you think **the tag is or might be considered useful** by the community, you should absolutely **post a separate Meta discussion**.

If the community agrees that removing the tag was **actively harmful**, then the asker's **edits should be reverted**.

**Don't revert edits if they leave the site better off or make no difference.**

If the user didn't happen to find their way here, **@-reply to them** on one of the posts they edited, linking to the Meta discussion.

Hopefully the user will stop doing that, but the system to deal with this isn't ideal. If the scenario is brought to the attention of a moderator (via a flag), unless it is considered really serious, or it's known to be a repeated infraction, I assume they won't do much then leave a comment pointing out the problem to the asker, or possibly even decline your flag if it isn't particularly serious.

Ideally there should be some sort of formal warning if the behaviour has been determined to be bad (a comment by a high-reputation user, or even a moderator, doesn't mean a whole lot to some people). Some period of time later, a reminder should pop up to someone to check up on that user. If the user clearly ignored the warning, this should perhaps be the time we start revoking related privileges (at least for a time). After this, we can escalate appropriately.

If you've found **a user who keeps doing this**, even after being warned about it, **flag a post** that shows the offending behaviour and explain the situation to the moderator - include some links to proof if possible.

Comment: Re: "Don't revert edits if they leave the site better off or make no difference."

Isn't the guideline for edits to be substantial?

Comment: @PeterG. It is, but reverting it would just be adding to the noise. A revert would presumably also result in a question getting sent to the front page, so it should also be substantial.