# Burninate / retag the [execute] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request, clean-up

The [execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execute) tag (x715) seems too broad.

Execute what exactly? A program? What type of program? A query? A procedure? A function? A script? What type of script? A command? Something else?

It definitely doesn't seem specific enough - can we get rid of it?

I realize the tag wiki talks about executing a stored procedure, but [it appears to get misused most of the time](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexecute%5D+-%5B%2asql%2a%5D+is%3Aquestion) (~x571).

Should we perhaps retag [execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execute) to [sql-execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-execute) and others (rather than just straight-out burning [execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execute)) instead? Would those make for useful tags?

Comment: The excerpt says it is limited to sql....so at lest that tag should be removed from questions that are also tagged with javascript...

Comment: I think a good question to ask is: Does the SQL "execute" function really need its own tag in the first place? I don't know anything about that function so I don't know how complicated it is, but if it's anything similar to PHP's "exec" (short for execute) function, it certainly does not need its own tag (hint: do not create a php-execute tag).

Comment: it should be completely eliminated and blacklisted.

Answer (score 20):

Nuke it.  Nuke it, and blacklist it so it won't come back.

I don't think creating an [sql-execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-execute) tag is a good idea, either.  A useful question to ask yourself, when trying to decide whether a tag should exist, is "Are there any experts on this subject?"  That is, could someone reasonably be interested in answering questions *specifically* about this subject, rather than about some more general topic that this subject happens to be a subset of?  In particular, could someone legitimately want to follow this tag, without also following a more generic related tag?

In this case, I fell pretty confident in saying that there's no such thing as "an SQL EXECUTE statement expert".  Sure, there are SQL experts of varying levels, and some will know more about EXECUTE statements than others, but I'm pretty sure that nobody comes to SO wanting to *only* answer questions about EXECUTE statements, and not about any other SQL statements.  So, no, we should not have an [sql-execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-execute) tag.

In any case, even if an [sql-execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-execute) tag *is* created, [execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execute) definitely should *not* be a synonym of it.  Looking at the typical questions using it, a significant fraction appear to be of the kind where the poster just typed some more or less relevant phrase like "[how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/how) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/to) [execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execute) [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code) [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/from) [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)" into the tag field before posting [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174548/how-to-execute-bash-from-within-a-python-file).  Tags like that *will* keep being misused even if they're turned into synonyms, and they *will* keep reappearing even if deleted (because, alas, a few users will keep doing this even after accumulating enough rep to create new tags).

Comment: I think hopelessly too many of our tags would burn if we just look at "Are there any experts on this subject?". I think we should extend that to include something like "Does this have some clearly-defined meaning and it is reasonably scoped?"

Comment: @Dukeling: SO has a ridiculous number of useless tags, because the usual community moderation mechanisms for getting rid of them (that do work on smaller SE sites, and also e.g. here on meta) haven't kept pace with the influx for years. We could probably delete 90% or more of the tags on SO without losing a single actually useful one, if we just had some practical way of doing so.

Comment: @Dukeling I agree with Ilmari - there are quite a lot of tags on Stack Overflow that *do* need to be killed off just like this one. They're crappy tags that probably got created early on and have been garnering questions ever since. Just take a look at the [tag:div] tag. Completely useless. It's just much easier to think about cleaning up the house when you're only looking at one pile of garbage at a time rather than the entire house all at once.