# How to handle the 4/5 different unrelated meanings of the [series] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-wiki

**STATEMENT OF PROBLEM - (REVISED 2014-05-05)**

There is currently one [series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/series) tag. Currently it's like a catch-all, it's getting applied to at least four seriously different concepts/objects, across different families of languages/applications.
Each of these 4+ use-cases merits entirely separate consideration of whether it deserves to exist as a separate tag or not; and thus whether the questions should be split or deleted/untagged.
A brief survey of what [series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/series) is being applied to:

1. [data-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-processing) languages, such as [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)/[python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) /[matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab), where `Series` is a very fundamental and hugely important data-structure. And no, it's not a mathematical series, because the data is commonly categorical, string or logical, and not numeric. Read below, which explains what a Series is in data-processing and why it's hugely important, and also different to 2. It's also infinitely more central to these languages than the use case in 3.
2. [mathematical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematical) series (well-defined, but distinct to data-processing). Unlike use-case 1., this does not in general have a specific data-structure, nor is it central to most languages.
3. Much less important, various data-structures to implement some (vague) concept of 'series' in **general-purpose languages**, e.g. [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c),[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b),[c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23),[vb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb),[java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) etc. I'm not advocating for these to get a separate tag, I don't think they should. However users of those languages will invariably apply the [series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/series) arbitrarily, so just be prepared to intermittently handle confusion. The tag wiki needs to address that.
4. Series in [spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet)
5. Series in [charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/charts), either 5a) the data itself, or 5b) the UI object backing it ([javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highcharts) etc.), or else 5c) the programming language API that backs it. Arguably 5a) should be merged with 4), and 5b) and 5c) with each other - but that's if they need a tag at all - which is a separate subdiscussion, and I'm not massively interested in that.

   ---

**DEFINITION OF 1) THE DISTINCT MEANING OF SERIES AS USED IN DATA-PROCESSING LANGUAGES**

First, many of you don't know that "[data-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-processing) language" is a well-defined term for a set of special-purpose languages/packages: R, Python pandas, Matlab, and more recently Apache PIG and Julia. (These evolved from SQL, SAS, STATA, and as for them, debate continues about whether they are full programming language.) The term *'data-processing language'* is well-established and has been around for about a decade. I did not just make it up yesterday, contrary to what one person insists below. Wikipedia categorizes these as ['Data-centric programming languages'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-centric_programming_language).

Second, within the context of data-processing languages, and more specifically Python pandas and R, the definition of a ***Series*** is a) well-defined b) has a very distinct definition to `Series` in other contexts c) an extremely core data-structure in the language. You can't get anything done in those two languages without Series or DataFrame. Totally different programmatically to C/C++/Java/C#/VB/etc.

Third: so, getting towards what is the (distinct) definition of `Series` in data-processing language, and is it really distinct to the other contexts? (Yes it is. Here's why).
A `Series` represents 'an (indexed) list of values representing the same underlying quantity'.
It has **nothing** to do with the mathematical definition of 'series', and its members aren't (generally) sums of anything, and often they don't even admit ordering or are not numeric.
If you don't believe that, here is an example dataframe with a couple of series, followed by a discussion of key properties, before finally I offer a definition of `Series` (in data-processing languages):

Here is an R snippet:

```
population = data.frame(
  height = c('5"4', '6"2', NA, '5"7',...),
  weight = c(124,203,NA,160,...),
  favorite_color = as.factor(c('green','blue','red','pink'...)),
  isMarried = c(F,NA,F,T...),
  name = as.factor(c('Paul','Terry','Sue','Anita',...))
)
```

Now note these key properties which distinguish a `Series` in data-processing:

- forget the mathematical series, **these series aren't *in general* sums of anything**. Height isn't, weight isn't, favorite_color, isMarried, name aren't even numeric. They are categorical, or logical, or string. These *in general* truly have nothing in general to do with Fibonacci, Maclauren, Taylor, Chebyshev or Riemann (except for 0.01% of the time when the series is numeric and also happens to be representing a numeric summation. But that is pretty rare in these languages: time-series, spatial series).
- **each series has its own type, and all values are homogeneous** (in these languages). This is extremely important: the series represents **one underlying quantity** ("you can't have a weight of 'blue', and your marital status can't be 3.5e+12"). The data structures will generally not allow you insert values of the wrong type. It is not some dumb container class or ultra-general collection class.
- 'ordered list' is a red herring (Dukeling). We're talking here about the VALUES, not the INDICES. The VALUES of the series are in general non-numeric (hence by definition don't admit ordering, and we do not order categoricals by their alphabetical labels), but even those ones that are numeric do not necessarily admit ordering (they could be nominal). If I add the userid for Paul + userid for Terry, the meaning is undefined.
- **NA values are allowed.** Not only that, they get special handling in operations on the Series (exclude/include/fill/impute/...) This is yet another major difference to general-purpose languages.
- the **index** doesn't have to be numeric; in R, Python pandas etc. you can use an arbitrary set of values (see R `row.names`, pandas `set_index()`).
- **operations specific to a series** since the language's type/object knows it's a series, it supports extra builtin operations for tabulating, value_count, fillNA, sum, max, min, mean, median, quantiles...

EDIT: So here's my tentative stab at a definition adapted from the [pandas doc definition of Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series):

> (For general (non-data-processing) languages (C, C++, C#, VB, Java), if that language has a specific Series type/class, can some of you please supply a definition here??)
>
> In data-processing languages (R, Python pandas), Series is a one-dimensional (labeled?) array capable of holding any (homogeneous) data type (integers, strings, floats, Dates, objects, etc.) whose **values** represent a single underlying quantity (e.g. height, weight, name, latitude, color, marital status). The axis labels are collectively referred to as the index. The **index** might represent time, space or some other quantity.

and here's [Matlab doc, specifically on TimeSeries](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/time-series-objects.html)

Before one of us goes ahead and edits the tag, it would be good to reach a consensus on a correct and language-neutral definition, as well as that language-specific links are unwanted.

---

SUGGESTION FOR HOW TO HANDLE THESE 4/5 USE CASES - REDEFINE/SPLIT/DELETE TAGS:

1. There is definitely a use-case for series as used in R, Python Pandas and Matlab (look at the questions tagged series in those languages). This definition is very different to definitions in 2.,3.,4.,5. Do not confuse them.
2. [mathematical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematical) series is a different meaning. Unlike use-case 1., this does not in general have a specific data-structure, nor is it central to most languages (arguments against a specific tag). I don't know whether it deserves a separate tag. I guess for the sake of clarity and preventing confusion, we should consider a [mathematical-series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-series). That's for discussion.
3. Much less important is the (unrelated) application of tag series to various obscure data-structures in general-purpose languages ([c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c),[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b),[c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23),[vb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb),[java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) etc.) I'm not advocating for these to get a separate tag, probably they shouldn't. However justbe prepared for confusion and random misapplication of the tag by users of those languages. The tag wiki needs to address that, i.e. clarify what a series isn't.
4. Series in [spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet). Some are also [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel)
5. Series in [charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/charts), either 5a) the data itself, or 5b) the UI object backing it ([javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highcharts) etc.), or else 5c) the programming language API that backs it.

Arguably 5a) should be merged with 4), and 5b) and 5c) with each other - but that's if they need a tag at all - which is a separate subdiscussion, and I'm not massively interested in that - just as long as you don't call it [series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/series).

---

CONCLUSION:

There are legitimate, very distinct and well-defined use-cases for:

[data-processing-series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-processing-series), [mathematical-series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-series)

As for [spreadsheet-series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet-series), [chart-series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chart-series), the definition is more fuzzy, but still seems legitimate. If you want to keep those two merged, you have the conundrum of what to call them (don't call it plain [series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/series), that's inviting confusion).

Comment: Having a language-agnostic summary doesn't preclude having links to language-specific resources related to the subject. I wouldn't say they're "unwanted. "

Comment: This looks to me like one of those tags that were edited by someone who didn't realize the Excerpt doesn't automatically appear at the top of the full tag wiki.  I believe the excerpt should have been added to top of it, which makes it a bit more sensible: "A Series object represents a data series and is stored in the SeriesCollection class."

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me that the `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Series` class is important enough to have a tag at all, but if it does it should perhaps be more specifically named.

Comment: However, as per http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252954/886887, I don't see any point at all in a language-agnostic "series" tag.  What would the purpose of this tag be?

Comment: @Harry Johnston: are you following this discussion? We're not talking about some obscure crappy VB class, I explicitly said of course that wouldn't deserve a tag. We're talking about **the general concept and implementation of a Series**, which occurs in at least 9 major programming languages (although the implementations differ). In case you don't know it, **`Series` and `DataFrame` are two essential concepts in data-processing languages like R and Python/pandas** - and that's why the tag should be language-agnostic, at least between R/Python/Matlab. Ok?

Comment: @smci: but why does a generic programming concept need a tag in the first place?  What would be the purpose of this redesigned tag?

Comment: @Harry: I've already explained why at least 10 times. Series and DataFrame are also hugely essential **data-structures** in data-processing languages like R and Python/pandas.  They're as core to data-processing language as you can possibly get. This is a fact! Read about it if you don't believe me. Or join me in [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) to chat.

Comment: I'm not asking whether series are useful.  I'm asking whether the tag would be useful.  For example, are there people who are language-agnostic experts in using series, and hence would follow the tag?  (We don't necessarily have to have tags for every important concept in programming.)

Comment: All I'm asking for is an example of how someone would actually make use of the proposed tag.

Comment: @Harry: ok I'm revising this text, distinguishing the 4+ different uses [tag:series] is applied to. But please join me in [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), discussion is better than long comment threads.

Comment: @Harry: one more time, `Series` and `DataFrame` are core data-structures in data-processing languages like R and Python/pandas. Not only are they actual **data-structures**, those data-structures  are **fundamental** to the those languages. I gave you an R code example. Got it? ***In the context of data-processing languages***, `Series` has both a very well-defined meaning and huge importance. ***Outside that context, in the other three contexts I identified***, series means different thing, has much less direct language support, and arugably may not deserve a split tag.

Comment: "In the context of data-processing languages, Series has both a very well-defined meaning and huge importance."  I accept that unconditionally.  But that's not what I asked - I asked why we needed a tag for it.  What advantage is gained by tagging questions about Series with the series tag?

Comment: Note that of the top ten questions tagged [tag:series], seven are using the term mathematically or informally, two are about charting/graphing, and only one is about a data processing package.  In my opinion, none of them benefit in any obvious way from the tag.

Comment: @Harry: Currently there are [55 tagged *series+pandas*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/series+pandas), [17 tagged *series+r*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/series+r), [72 tagged *series+charts*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/series+charts), [18 tagged *series+math*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/series+math) ...

Comment: ... [23 tagged *series+excel*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/series+excel), [50 tagged *series+highcharts*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/series+highcharts) and all from the [391 tagged *series*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/series). These numbers would of course change as tag definitions/retagging/untagging happened.

Comment: If you look at what 'series' means in those subcategories, you will see the separate meanings. 'pandas.Series' is an actual data-structure as well as being a core language concept to Python pandas - this is very different to C++/C#/VB.

Comment: To be clear, the raw tagcounts are not the justification for the separate categories - the justification is given in my analysis above. They do however substantiate my statement that **there are ~4/5 seriously separate definitions of 'series' in very different contexts**. Whether we decide to split, delete or redefine tags, the current situation is a confused mess and needs addressing.

Comment: Agreed; my vote (pending further information) is to delete, but I don't care about it enough to keep arguing. :-)

Answer (score 7):

1. I wouldn't call it a one-dimensional array. I'm pretty sure a series doesn't always need to be an array.
2. Does it need to be homogeneous?
3. I don't think mentioning types are necessary.
4. Is it very different from a [sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sequence) (possible synonym)?
5. It shouldn't contain language-specific things, at the very least not in the excerpt, or they should be clearly separated out.

My first draft: (this might be the excerpt, while the wiki can be longer)

> Series is an ordered list of elements of any type. The index used for the elements in this list can be the position in the list, time, or some other quantity.

Comment: It should probably mention the CS/Math definition of a Series: "the sum of the elements of a Sequence".  Formally, the distinction between a Sequence and a Series is important, but most programmers use them informally to mean the same thing.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: no it shouldn't mention it, here's why. A Series in the general data-processing sense is *not* in general a sum of other quantities e.g. `height = ['5"4', '6"2', NA, '5"7',...], weight = [124,203,NA,160], colors=['green','blue','red',...], isMarried = [F,NA,F,T...]`

Comment: So: Series of string, logical or object type are never sums of anything. Series of **numeric** quantities ***in general still aren't*** sums of other quantities, e.g. weight of a group of people. NA/NaN/Null values are never sums of anything. The possible origin of the data in a Series is not part of the definition of the datatype.

Comment: 1. Since by definition Series do **not** in general have an ordering, Dukeling's definition doesn't work. See those examples. 2.,3. At least for data-processing languages, it's *extremely* important that they are homogeneous. It's also important to note that the Series type could be one of various things. In general Series are not ordered and may not even be numerical, but we can still compare for equality, do value-counts, tabulating, plotting, fill NAs...

Comment: 4. Yes, a Series is a different type/class and a to a sequence, at least in all data-processing languages which support that concept. (and they're ) R's Series is not a sequence. Neither is Python's pandas. In data-processing, they are homogeneous and all of the same type, since they represent the same underlying quantity (e.g. height, weight, color). Since the type/object knows it's a series, they support extra builtin operations for tabulating, value_count, fillNA... see e.g. Series in [Python pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html)

Comment: @smci **1.** They're ordered in the same sense that a sequence is ordered, or an array, as opposed to a set (programmers presumably typically use 'ordered' to mean something similar to 'sorted', but Wikipedia calls a sequence ordered, and I can't think of a better word). **2.** We shouldn't call it homogeneous if it isn't always, even if it is required in some places. **4.** If it means the same everywhere else, we should perhaps disambiguate [tag:series] to [tag:data-processing-series] and retag the rest to [tag:sequence] (just an idea).

Comment: @Dukeling **1.** you're confusing the index with the values. The index is ordered, sure. The values may not be. **2.** In data-processing it **always** is; it doesn't mean "a collection of unrelated arbitrary objects". I'm starting to think we should separately note the definition of Series for data-processing languages. **4.** I strongly dislike that: data-processing people will still reference 'series' by mistake. This isn't arbitrary: you need to actually survey the actual series type/object as used in languages (C, C++, C#, VB, Java, R, Python, Matlab). I'll do a table of tags by language.

Comment: Can you justify the existence of such a tag?  What would be its purpose?  cf. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252954/886887

Comment: @Harry Johnston: In case you don't know it, `Series` and `DataFrame` are two core concepts in data-processing languages like R and Python/pandas - above I've provided copious explanation why. They're as fundamental and essential as 'array' in Java or 'vector' in C++ STL. You can't get much at all done without them in those languages/packages.

Comment: Seems the consensus is: a) for data-processing languages, Series is well-defined and essential b) in other languages, it's neither well-define nor important. Agreed?

Comment: @smci: you can't get much done without running your program, but [that doesn't make run](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252760/burninate-the-run-tag) a useful tag!

Comment: @smci No, most of what you've posted here is incorrect and based on your own preconceptions.  I'm not going to try to list every wrong point in comments, but, in particular, first, trying to redefine "*data-processing*" to mean only the parts of CS and Programming that support your perspective is transparently ulterior and incorrect. And secondly, "*by definition Series do not .. have an ordering*" is so wrong, it beggars description: in fact, *order* is the one thing that *all* generally accepted definitions of a series have in common.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: incorrect. You totally misrepresented what I wrote. I stated that **IN THE CONTEXT OF DATA-PROCESSING LANGUAGES (such as [tag:R] or python [tag:pandas]**, "by definition (the values of) Series do not .. have an ordering". I even gave an example: what is the ordering of ['yellow','red','green']? They are [tag:categorical], represented by factors. They don't have an ordering. (No, not the alphabetical ordering of the levels of the factor.)

Comment: To be clear, we're referring to the **VALUES** of the series, not the **INDEX** of the series. So the index self-evidently has an ordering: `s[1] = 'yellow', s[2]='red', s[3]='green'` ; but categorical VALUES do not have an ordering. **In data-processing languages in general, only numerical values have an ordering.** 'Data-processing language' is a well-defined term, encompassing R, Python, Apache PIG and newer languages big-data. That definition has been around for about 10 years. Got it?

Comment: Read about the definition of the term ***'categorical'*** in statistics. ***'categorical-data'*** is a very well-defined tag with 674 questions over on CrossValidated. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/categorical-data

Comment: @smci: False. The term "data-processing language" has been around for over ***50 years*** and was applied originally to COBOL, but has been used at one time or another on virtually every commercial high-level language. And my degrees are in Mathematics and Computer Science, and I've been an actual Data Processing professional for 40 of those 50+ years, and I can assure you that your use of the term "*data processing*" appears to be drawn from whole cloth, and your parochial concept of Series bears little or no relationship to the way that Math, CS and DP have been using them during that time.

Comment: As a caution: let's avoid making personal attacks and focus on the topic at hand.

Comment: "(indexed) list of values representing the same underlying quantity" -- That IS an array.  Nothing about the word *array* precludes sparsity, even if some language-specific implementations don't support sparse arrays.

Answer (score 7):

First off, I agree with you that as it currently stands the `series` tag as a catch all for these very different meanings for data-processing, mathematics, and other data structures, is not ideal.

However, Personally, this is the first I've heard `series` used in the context of data-processing languages, and I can't recall seeing it used in conjunction with the `r` tag.

This, coupled with the heavy resistance you've encountered in the comments, leads me to think that the best solution is to untag any questions relating to data-processing that are using the `series` tag, and let the other communities work out what the want to do with it.